# SO Close Vote Reviewers

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

### What It's Not

Another thread about close votes (starting with the disclaimer, "Another thread about close votes.") But!

- This thread is *not* about [*why* the queue as large as it is](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/208311/regarding-the-stack-overflow-close-review-queue).
- This thread is *not* about [what's *wrong* with the system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/198288/offtopic-questions-have-to-be-cleared-off-the-way-not-via-closure)
- This thread is *not* about [what we *"should"* do to change the system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/195352/daily-close-votes-queue-limit/195355#195355).

To discuss any the above, kindly comment or post in the linked or related threads :-). If you're feeling especially impassioned, you might even consider [joining the strike](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/208220/close-votes-review-im-going-on-a-strike). Or, [the counter-movement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/208682/close-votes-review-im-not-going-on-a-strike).

### What It Is

This thread's about [a chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) where we'll be hanging out about once a week, reviewing close votes. We'll be there at

- 6:30pm (18:30) UTC, or
- 9:00pm (21:00) UTC / 4:00pm EST / 1:00pm PST

on the following pattern of dates:

[image]
[image]
[image]

That's every 6 days, starting on the 1st Friday of each month, skipping weekends. This means sometimes due to weeks getting split by months, there'll be 4 or 11 days between meetups.

### Why

Many users are [demotivated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/208220/close-votes-review-im-going-on-a-strike#comment664069_208238) by a queue that seems to grow and grow despite individual effort. I get discouraged not being able to *see* the impact of my input—the queue keeps growing, seemingly no matter what I do:

[image]

If there are others who feel as I do, then maybe we'd all feel a lot more motivated if we banded together to attack the queue over a single hour each week—and maybe if we got *enough* of us together, we could put a recurring and *visible* dent on that plot!

I have reason to believe it's possible, because in the first meetup, this happened:

[image]

...and there were only 3 of us.

Comment: [Wow](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXpF2xMlZyQ).

Comment: I like this idea, because you can get some agreements immediately on whether a post should or shouldn't be closed.  Is there any way you could attack "low hanging fruit" (say, votes to close based on off-topic or something that doesn't require a boatload of research) first?  That would allow you to reduce the number quickly, which might take some of the intimidation away that some have complained about.

Comment: @JohnnyBones There is close vote filtering.

Comment: @Undo - Yes, I'm requesting that they actually use that strategy to knock out a bunch of reviews quickly.

Comment: And your goal is to discuss each item in the queue on its merits, reaching a consensus, before deciding to vote to close or leave open, right?

Comment: Feel free to post ideas as answers (and edit additional ideas into your own answer, so we don't end up with pages and pages of ideas). @JohnnyBones - That's a good one. The great thing about this is that we're all gonna be in a chat room together, so you can suggest, "Let's all work on off-topic votes," and maybe everyone will agree.

Comment: @Bart - Haha. Oh, god. That would take forever. (I know you're kidding.) Users can of course discuss ambiguities and debate precedents as they wish, but consensus isn't the goal—just hangin' out and feeling like a team, is.

Comment: I'd be totally down for it, but I don't have 3K rep yet.  However, I think this is an awesome idea and applaud you for putting it in motion.

Comment: Well, keep in mind that the goal of that queue is not to close everything that's in there. It's there to provide easy access to questions which might be candidates for closure, but might just as well be valid questions which should be left open. I have the uncomfortable feeling that such an assembly would end up in a close-vote posse, which might well be brought up on Meta again in some time. So try to avoid that at least.

Comment: @Bart - Ah, indeed, good point. Maybe we could make it a rule for the chat room to refrain from reviewing questions linked in the chat. Something like, _"To avoid turning this chat into a close vote posse, we encourage users to refrain from reviewing/voting on questions mentioned by other users. That is, do use links to discuss and debate questions, but find your own questions to review :-) Thanks."_

Comment: For those who'd prefer meetups at 2:00pm UTC (9:00am EST, 6:00am PST, 7:30pm IST), please upvote this comment.

Comment: I'd rather see the room open and populated at all times, but I like the idea of meetups as well (of course, we can have both)

Comment: @JanDvorak - I was afraid there wouldn't be enough interest to make this a 24/7 active community. (I actually expected to be _alone_ for several weeks, so even this much interest is surprising.) So at least in the beginning, I wanted to concentrate interested users into small windows of time, so we all get to meet each other and feel like an actual group (rather than floating members). Maybe one day though it might grow into what you suggest.

Comment: I can keep the room open in a back tab. I can sit there and respond for as long as I'm online. I never formally leave the javascript chat room either.

Comment: +1 for actually proposing to *do* something about the queue, rather than either whining, or saying "move along, nothing to see here"

Comment: Thought I should throw this out: http://cv-pls.com/ it's what the PHP chat uses to close vote PHP related questions. Source is available on Github and can easily be switched to display tags other than [php], version 1.2 is in the works and will add more features such as multiple tags, column sorting, and more. Unfortunately it can't access the queue as there is no API access to it, but rather accesses new questions in near real-time.

Comment: @crypticツ oh wow that looks cool!

Comment: Why bother? Seriously. The queue is now out of sight, out of mind. Since the top bar came out and hid the extra review links the acceleration of the queue has moved to 7+ times the average. To put it another way, it went from ~180 a day to 1200 per day. The review queue is growing faster than Jon Skeet's reputation.

Comment: @TravisJ - To each their own. Curious though, where did you get those numbers? (I ask because I want those numbers too!)

Comment: @TravisJ - [To chat!](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Comment: It's quite difficult to get in line with you guys but I did do my 40 votes last wed and today earlier than expected

Comment: @mehow - No worries; thanks! Would a different time work better for you? Perhaps the original time of 4:00pm EST?

Comment: @acheong87 I can't guarantee to be on time at any given time... i guess there is no solution to that haha but +1 for the idea and I'd like to see some statistics after it's all done (gone , zeroed)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> This answer is left here for historic reasons but is no longer maintained. For an up to date status say hi in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room or check our [Tour](https://socvr.org/tour) and [FAQ](https://socvr.org/faq).

#### Next Meetup

[3,000,000 close vote reviews celebration](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers?tab=schedule), December 19th, 17:00 -18:00 UTC
*bring your comics, haiku's, comments to celebrate your and our moderation effort*

Keep track of the [CVQ](http://socvr.azurewebsites.net/)

#### Register for regular events [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers?tab=schedule)

#### FAQ

[Visit our extended explanation](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SCVR-RoomInformation)

### Credits

Thanks to many for making these events possible and keeping them going: (in alphabetical order) @bjb568, @codemagic, @crypticツ, @Davidism, @DennisMeng, @Dukeling, @easwee, @Emracool, @GabrielePetronella, @godel9, @gunr2171, @HamZa, @hichris123, @JanDvorak, @JonClements, @joseph-quinsey, @OGHaza, @pnuts, @ProgramFox @Qantas94Heavy, @mehow, @rene, @RichardTingle, @Sam, @TGMCians, @TravisJ, @Undo, @user00000000, @Wayne-Conrad, @WouterJ.

Please don't hesitate to leave a message in chat if I've inadvertently left you out of this list!

---

### Announcements

**May 26th, 2014.** "Life" happened and I've been taking a break from SO. I'm indebted to @rene *et al* for dutifully and cheerily keeping the effort going. This will be my last update on this thread, with an updated plot of the size of the close votes review queue (click for larger resolution):

[image]

**Jan 15, 2014.** The meetup time has been [changed to 21:00 UTC (4:00pm EST)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14036833#14036833) henceforth. Also, some fancy graphs coming up, based on data collected so far—

[image]

**Dec 22, 2013.** Moved cron job to a Linode. Now tracking all 3 numbers found on [the stats page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) (as opposed to just current queue size). Planning to make CSV files available to public in [6-8 weeks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/19514/188984).

---

### Tracking

I've been tracking the size of the close votes review queue with a makeshift cron job.

```sh
#
#   crontab
#
* * * * * /home/andrew/cron/PollCVRQ.sh
```

```sh
#
#   PollCVRQ.sh
#
curl https://stackoverflow.com/review
    | grep dashboard-num
    | head -1
    | sed 's/^.*<div class="dashboard-num" title="\([^"]\+\)".*$/\1/'
    | sed 's/,//g'
    | sed 's/^/'`date +%s`',/'
    >> /home/andrew/cron/cvrq-primary-epoch.csv
```

This outputs:

```
1387381921,100825
1387381981,100830
1387382041,100830
1387382101,100830
1387382161,100826
```

<sup>For details on running this on Windows/Cygwin, see [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/680509/simplest-setup-on-windows-to-send-http-request-get-and-apply-regex-to-response), but for the love of all things holy do not use the code there—I used ISO-8601 thinking it was the international standard of time formats—not realizing what a nightmare it was to convert to and from other formats, especially with timezones involved. The above code uses the good ol' seconds-since-epoch (sample output below).</sup>

And here's the plot as of Dec 18, 2013. The intermittent drops are due to [a weekly task that deletes old, abandoned questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/209567/188984). The crazy drops of late are due to having fixed some [technical difficulties](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1683356#1683356) with the expiration of close votes—which, I hope, might render these chat events obsolete :-)

[image]

For those with *Mathematica* who wish to play with this data themselves, ping me in chat and I'll upload my latest data to [this directory](http://andrewcheong.com/u/so/). (I didn't take data collection too seriously, else I'd have run the script on a server. @Emracool generously supplied me with a ton of missing data—and I was able to fill some other gaps with data collected on my roommate's computer.) The script previously formatted time in ISO-8601 (a huge mistake), but now uses seconds-since-epoch. The following *Mathematica* code includes functions for importing in either time format, and plots all datasets.

```m
CVRQImportISO8601[path_, offset_: 0] := (
   data = Import[path];
   data = {StringReplacePart[#, {" ", ""}, {{11, 11}, {-5, -1}}], #2} & @@@ data;
   data = {DatePlus[#, offset/24], #2} & @@@ data;
   data
);

CVRQImportEpoch[path_] := (
   data = Import[path];
   data = {AbsoluteTime[{1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}] + #, #2} & @@@ data;
   data
);

primaryOld = CVRQImportISO8601["C:\\cygwin\\home\\Andrew\\cron\\cvrq-primary-iso8601.csv"];
primaryNew = CVRQImportEpoch["C:\\cygwin\\home\\Andrew\\cron\\cvrq-primary-epoch.csv"];
secondaryEST = CVRQImportISO8601["C:\\cygwin\\home\\Andrew\\cron\\cvrq-secondary-iso8601.csv", 3]; 
secondaryPST = CVRQImportISO8601["C:\\cygwin\\home\\Andrew\\cron\\cvrq-secondary-iso8601-offset.csv"]; 
emracool = CVRQImportEpoch["C:\\cygwin\\home\\Andrew\\cron\\cvrq-emracool-epoch.csv"]; 

styles = {
   {ColorData[1, 1], PointSize@Tiny},
   {ColorData[1, 8], PointSize@Tiny},
   {ColorData[1, 15], PointSize@Tiny}
};

DateListPlot[
   {emracool, secondaryPST, secondaryEST, primaryNew, primaryOld},
   PlotStyle -> {styles[[2]], styles[[3]], styles[[3]], styles[[1]], styles[[1]]},
   ImageSize -> {GoldenRatio*360, 360}
]
```

Finally, an additional function for zooming in on a segment of the plot:

```m
CVRQZoom[data_, start_, end_, low_, high_] := DateListPlot[
   data,
   PlotRange -> {{start, end}, {low, high}},
   PlotStyle -> {PointSize@Tiny},
   ImageSize -> {GoldenRatio*360, 360},
   Joined -> True
];

CVRQZoom[{primaryOld}, "25 Nov 2013 20:30:00", "25 Nov 2013 22:30:00", 95600, 95700]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you update this answer with the new date(s) and hopefully nice graphs when you have the oppertunity?

Comment: There may not be much to do anymore... :-) but I'll be there. Thanks for keeping these threads updated and the room alive, @rene.

Comment: It just cleared... :-) mission accomplished

Comment: @rene: that's just a illusion -- there's still _tons_ to do!

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Ohh, but...how...the numbers never lie...or do they... :-)

Comment: Has your data been affected by the new close votes display change?

Comment: On the not sharing review of questions, the main problem seems to be the inherent bias that one can vote to close without being able to vote to keep open. I've created a feature-request question that asks to fix that: (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252010/allow-keep-open-voting-outside-review-queue)

Comment: Just out of curiosity: How did the numbers drop from the approximately 100k shown on these graphs to the 10-12k they are now? While I can't join these events (day job...), I've been trying to do my 40 reviews every day.

Comment: @RetoKoradi - That was due to [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252572/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut/252577#252577), and the subsequent increases were due to the restoration of posts with 4, 3, 2, etc. votes.

Comment: @rene do you by chance know if CV Reviewers are aware of recent initiative: [Clean up “looking for \[something\]” questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/282932/839601)?

Comment: @gnat Not specifically but I do notice I get a lot more library requests in any tag we filter on. I did one daily close raid on [tag:free]. I'll put the post on our [starboard](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Comment: thanks @rene - per my observations, this initiative progressed pretty well first few days. Then it somewhat slowed down, making me feel that folks driving it rather lack experience in long term cleanup efforts. Which _naturally_ made me recall of you folks successfully running your gig for over a year now (!)