# Allow "keep open" voting outside review queue

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, vote-to-reopen

The "close votes" queue contains a lot of questions that have some close votes, but not enough to close them.

Maybe some of them could be removed from the queue by adding a "keep open" option to questions with at least one close vote, regardless of how the question is being viewed, if the user has high enough reputation to review close votes. A "keep open" vote would make close votes start ageing out, regardless of views, just as though it had been cast through the "close votes" queue. This could be done by someone working on questions in their favorite tags, without going into a separate review process.

Alternatively, allow preemptive "reopen" voting as soon as there is at least one close vote, without waiting for the question to accumulate 5 close votes.

Comment: I just came to the realization this feature is missing as well.

Comment: +1, pretty please with strawberries and a cherry on top, let us have this. I stopped counting times I've seen a question with one or more incorrect VTCs as a duplicate, or a basic but well-written question with an incorrect VTC as "typographical error."

Comment: I just came across a question that had 2 "unclear what you're asking" votes against it, but it seemed perfectly clear to me.  I would have liked to preemptively vote against one of the close votes - your final suggestion here would make it possible.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Indeed, I also think close votes attract other close votes by other people who don't necessarily know what they're talking about. It's not just for "unclear what you're asking", that happens for "too broad" too (bizarrely quite probably from people who love so-called "canonical" questions, which by definition are bound to be on the broad side). [Here is my latest similar experience](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30809051/372643): a question I had time to answer before it was closed.

Comment: Why doesn't this question have an answer after a whole year, not even an [declined] tag.

Comment: Yeah this is precisely why I came to MSO today to point out.  I find good questions with close votes all of the time as I work through questions and I want to preemptively keep the question open.  I feel sometimes like questions get on the "close bandwagon" improperly.

Answer (score 5):

I think the "keep open" working in the same way as the review queue is the better idea here.

A preemptive "reopen vote" implies that the question is inevitably going to get put on hold - which isn't the case.

Also it doesn't require any new back end functionality to support it - it, as you say, just starts the close vote ageing process as happens from the review queue.

One drawback would be that the OP would see (assuming they had enough rep) the "keep open" link and click it as a matter of course. This could be sorted by either not showing it to the post owner or discounting their vote.

Comment: Well, there is a problem with "keep open" from outside the queue: Those who answered and the asker are quite likely to use that option whether it's justified or not. With reopen, their action is at least a bit ore public, if successful.

Comment: @Deduplicator good point. Though are your own posts hidden from you in the review queues? It makes sense if they are, but I don't remember seeing anything about this elsewhere.

Comment: I thought there was something about that. Anyway, the review-task(s) concerning them aren't that easily found.