# Should Leave Open votes counteract Close votes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

I encountered this question in the close vote queue: [Error messages after creating a new linux user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246946/error-messages-after-creating-a-new-linux-user)

It has 4 close votes from (I assume) people thinking the question was about the unix `chown` command rather than Perl's `chown` method which was clarified in the comments.

Astute reviewers will (hopefully) notice this and vote to Leave Open but it'll only take one reviewer not really paying attention to close it.

If reviewers are voting to leave the question open, would it make sense to move it further away from the close threshold, rather than teetering on 4 until it times out of the queue? Should the number of Leave Open votes be displayed in the review to indicate that perhaps something has been changed/clarified since the close votes were cast?

Comment: I don't think it's a bad suggestion but, if there are comments that would likely keep it from being closed by clarifying the problem, then a user with experience in that field should edit the question and make it more obvious.

Comment: Each user that views the question outside of the review queue who has enough reputation to vote to close but didn't vote to close implicitly left it open.  I don't think that each of those views should cancel out a close vote (maybe they can't judge whether a possible duplicate actually is, or don't know the domain well enough to tell whether something's clear or not).  In principle, those kinds of questions in the queue should probably be skipped, but I bet they're often Left Open.

Comment: Alternatively, if something like this is implemented, then it should probably be implemented outside the queue, too, right?  If a user with enough rep to close vote sees a question with some close votes, should they be able to cancel one out (perhaps using up one of their votes for the day)?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, an option outside the queue similar to the current close option would be a nice addition too, perhaps as a separate count rather than cancelling a close vote (it would still be useful to see the reasons people thought it should be closed). It would have to be a definite action though, not triggered by someone simply viewing the question and not deciding to close.

Comment: @codeMagic Fair point, I've edited the question now so it is more obviously Perl code. Unfortunately, it was already closed!

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252010/allow-keep-open-voting-outside-review-queue

Answer (score 9):

Yes!

**What's the purpose of a do nothing option?**
As currently implemented the <kbd>Leave open</kbd> option is merely a variant of the <kbd>skip</kbd> button.
As such it has no value other than increasing your review counter.
I strongly believe that the UI options should have actual value beyond acquiring gamification points.

If the <kbd>Leave open</kbd> option is too strong a weapon to have in the hands of mere mortals than we can always increase the rep limit for it and leave the <kbd>Do nothing</kbd> option instead.

**The button is mislabeled**
Quite apart from the above issue the <kbd>Leave open</kbd> option is mislabeled. If it does nothing then it should state that it does **nothing** and be changed to read <kbd>My view is clouded, my mind is troubled, yet I'm unsure how to proceed, though I may rue (nay lament) my inaction later, I choose to: **Do Nothing**</kbd>

or maybe

<kbd>while (q.status not in [reopened, closed, deleted]) do begin

**nothing**
end;</kbd>

Comment: I thought we had that button, we just shortened its caption to "Skip"

Comment: @CodyGray, but then `leave open` and `skip` are the same thing. That does not make sense on a UX level.

Comment: @Johan Enough "leave open" votes take the question out of the review queue.

Answer (score 1):

> Should Leave Open votes counteract Close votes?

No. Edits are the best way to counteract close votes. If you see a question that it's being closed, fix the reason why it's being closed instead:

- Unclear what you are asking: edit the post to clarify the question being asked, incorporate the clarifications from comments.
- Too broad: focus the question into a single point, narrow down the scope.
- Duplicated: incorporate or empathize the differences between both questions.
- Off-topic - Resource request: depending on the question.
- Off-topic - unreproducible: incorporate steps to reproduce it, fix whatever could be considered a typo but that doesn't effect the final result.
- Other close reasons are more complex and depend on the situation and context.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that open/close votes operate the same across StackExchange sites:

When casting a close vote, other close votes are shown. At a minimum, the number of leave-open votes should also be shown. Showing only close votes can give a false sense of consensus where there may be none. Showing the number of leave-open votes would at least indicate whether there is dissent in closing, and if so, prompt additional consideration.

Comment: Or we should remove the close vote counts from the close vote dialog in that queue...