# Should a fairly off topic question that would be beneficial for the community be asked?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I have had a question for quite some time now, but have been reluctant to ask as I understand it would be borderline off-topic, and hence I have yet to ask it.

I drafted the question [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/v1wtzkwu/2/), which was asking:

**When is it appropriate to use CSS / SVG in the creation of shapes within the browser?**

I understand such a topic of this nature would be (quite understandably) deemed off topic (too broad, opinion based), but I feel it could add a great deal to the understanding of the [css-shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-shapes) tag, as well as other related tags.

I was also shown another adaptation of the question, shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/v1wtzkwu/3/) from another user.

I have spoken to a few people already on this matter, and whilst they share my views as to question its topicality, they also said they'd have a go answering it.

What would the communities view be of 'knowingly posting an off topic question, but thinking/understanding it would be beneficial for others' be?

---

It comes after the discussions held over [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711203/how-do-i-create-a-teardrop-in-html/30711437#30711437) question that I feel i should to ask this.

---

**update**

In reference to the comments, I understand this may possibly belong on some sort of blog. However, It it was posted in such a way that it 'suited' the Q + A format of SO, would it be beneficial to post this?

Comment: First of all, it's a good thing you asked here first – OTOH, you may already be aware that Meta approval means virtually nothing, and you may still get backslash/DV/VTC. Doesn't the phrase "So, what would the pros and cons of using ..." seem an invitation to a discussion? Can it be removed, so only "Is there a (substantial) difference" remains?

Comment: @Jongware: DW, I'm well aware of that fact :). I just thought I would get a 'official view' as to whether or not such questions should be left for blogs or other sites, and not for SO.

Comment: Seems like a mix of "too broad" and "how to paint my bike shed". And while you might get interesting answers, I doubt those would universally qualify as _useful_, as it's not a specific problem with a clear-cut solution. The answers will probably all say "it depends" in one form or another, and lead to debate or at best establish what is considered "best practice". It seems more appropriate for a discussion or an opinion piece on a blog somewhere. SO should be a resource of factual knowledge, and while answers might contain useful factoids, the question feels inappropriate for such a resource.

Comment: @l4mpi: Thank you for your comment. I understand your viewpoint, but there is always a counter-side. Whilst my draft isn't exactly a 'clear question', I do think it could be narrowed down into a 'better question' ;)

Comment: You would IMO have to narrow it down extremely. You're currently asking about many facets (browser support, number of requests, performance) which are part of the picture; but even focussing on just one of those could still be too broad if it isn't accomplished by a specific use case. E.g. performance - maybe a CSS hack to create a shape is orders of magnitude slower than a SVG solution in one case, but it's reversed in another case. Browser support is similar, if you're asking how all shape-related CSS / SVG features are supported in all current browsers, that's not very specific.

Comment: @l4mpi its pretty common to get comments like: "There is little support for SVG" . On a lot of my SVG answers. While I find that IE8 support should matter very little in today.

Comment: To be honest, I'd replace _"fairly"_ with _"very"_, in this question's title. The question as written here is basically asking _"Should I use X or Y?"_, which can only invite opinion-based answers.

Comment: There are so many questions like this, and the people best qualified to answer are usually on this site. People inevitably see that and come here for answers, and they will not stop. There needs to be a way to handle questions like this, perhaps a additional Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Cerbrus: Cheers for your comment. If you wanted to alter the question, or offer up an alternative, please feel free. As I said, I only mocked that up as a possiblility  :)

Comment: @MikeWise: Thanks for your comment. However, an additional SE I believe would be overkill IMHO. However, maybe the fact that the 'skills' are here, with people I know are happy enough to answer such question (I've already had confimation from one such individual who's happy to add a detailed answer). I guessed that such question would be beneficial for users, and yet I know of its topicality.

Comment: Personally, I have found (what I consider) useful information in off-topic posts.  Perhaps I _should_ have found this information in a blog somewhere.  But I googled stuff, and when I saw SO had some info...  it was my first choice.  That being said, I don't think this is the place for off-topic posts.

Comment: (Looking at your title...) Benefit or usefulness to the community is not a reason to extend the scope of what's allowed on SO. As you say, blogs have uses; product support forums have uses; MOOCs have uses, etc. and SO supports none of these.

Comment: That question might be a better fit for Programmers, where more conceptual questions are welcome. I would still try to narrow it down some and make it less opinion based, but I think you'd have a much easier time getting it to be on topic on Programmers than you ever would on SO.

Comment: This could be a good candidate for the [new documentation project](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303865/warlords-of-documentation-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 32):

Note I'm not saying whether your drafted question is or isn't on topic, but with regards to your broader question:

**No**; an off topic question is off topic, regardless of intent.  With the growth of the Stack Exchange network, we can afford to be a bit more critical of what's acceptable, as there are other sites, such as Programmers, where certain questions may now be a better fit.

Comment: Cheers for your answer. I understand where you are coming from, and yet there are always 'special cases' for such questions that are yes, off topic, but hold significant information on its topic. I feel such a question, whilst off topic, *would* benefit the community - especially in this tag.

Comment: @jbutler483 There's a certain amount of leeway for old questions that are now off-topic, but weren't at the time of posting, which have proven to be useful (or at least popular). However, I'm not aware of there being any "special cases" for new questions, regardless of intent.

Comment: no problem @AnthonyGrist. From the feedback I've received here suggests that asking/answering such a question would  be a bad idea. Especially as you pointed out that such a question would not be helpful to the community.

Comment: Disagree: the question asks for pros and cons of both approaches, which is a request for facts. Whether the pros outweigh the cons would be a matter of opinion, but the question does not ask that. (The question may still be off-topic for other reasons mentioned, I make no claims one way or the other about that.)

Comment: I couldn't disagree with this more.  This is not an opinionated question.  There are very clear guidelines for when you might want to use the various techniques asked about.  I would downvote this meta reply 100 times if I could, as this attitude is damaging to Stack Overflow.  The post would not violate the guidelines, and even if it did some common sense should be applied.  Just because we're programmers doesn't mean we have to be robots. Let's think a bit before nuking everything that may technically have crossed a line because of some minor wording. Read the *intent* of the post and rules.

Comment: @Brad: Are they really that clear-cut? And does everyone agree on them?

Comment: @Deduplicator Everyone with significant knowledge who has considered them would agree.

Comment: @Brad I think the problem here is that there are essentially two questions in the OP. Firstly, "is this question that I've drafted off topic?".  It may or may not be.  But secondly, and the main question in my eyes is "should I ask an off topic question if it would benefit the community?".  This is what my answer is aimed at, and the answer of course is no, off topic questions don't benefit the community by definition.  This is even more true now we have the wide range of SE sites that we have, as mentioned elsewhere here, this particular one may be better on Programmers or even Webmasters.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Your post actually only attempts to answer the first question. You say it's off topic, and you say why you think it's off topic. You don't say anything more in your answer. If you meant to answer that second question, I recommend you rewrite your answer.

Comment: @hvd point taken - now edited

Comment: "*an off topic question is off topic, regardless of intent*". I don't really agree with this, I think it depends on the kind of off-topic. I think "off topic" itself is "too broad": typographical errors, book recommendations, debugging help are all different from question for which the subject is only partly about programming. This is typically the case for ["devops" type of questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295094/372643) (or other similar questions where the developer has to know a bit about the sysadmin side of what they're doing, without it being a suitable question for SF).

Answer (score 11):

Honestly I like your question, I've found myself wondering about the subject on more than one project.

The problem I see with it is that it isn't specific enough. You mention a tear drop shape, which may be a good starting point though. With a very specific shape in mind the question becomes answerable, but then it more or less boils down to a "Benchmark it" question.

"Benchmark it" questions, in my opinion, are kind of lame though. They're usually solved by simply building both versions and running them and checking them for whatever you're looking for (speed, browser/device support, and so on...)

Asking others to benchmark for you is a little lazy. Not to mention that the results of benchmark testing are pretty likely to change over time and from one machine to the next, so the answers may not age well or be terribly helpful to the next reader.

---

To answer the title question:

> Should a fairly off topic question that would be beneficial for the
>   community be asked?

When in doubt do exactly what you did and ask about it here on Meta.

Comment: `When in doubt do exactly what you did and ask about it here on Meta.` this will become an issue when every on-the-fence question is asked first on meta. Meta is about the workings of the site, not really so much about whether each question you have is ok to ask on this site.

Comment: @humble.rumble Questions about the scope of the site have always been welcome on Meta. Better to ask if a question is on-topic before it is posted than after... I understand that you're pointing to a "slippery slope" issue, but it hasn't been a problem so far.

Comment: He's not only looking for a benchmark of a specific shape with existing versions, but for a general rule. Yes, that might include benchmarks, but a good answer would show a) which benchmarks to take (execution time is not the only one) and b) which results can generally be expected for which technology.

Comment: @Bergi Wouldn't a general rule fall afoul of being primarily opinion based? Depending on the specific shape you're shooting for, some would probably be better in svg while others in css, so perhaps also too broad?

Comment: @apaul34208: Asking for a general rule is not asking for opinion on a specific example. Yes, a good answer would need to explain *how* the results depend on the shape. Yes, this does require a broad answer, but if it actually *is* answered then it is no more *too* broad.

Answer (score 6):

I think the question as-written is pretty close on the "good subjective"/"bad subjective" line.

It would be good if it can be written in a way that encourages factual, data-based answers and discourages answers that are purely opinion based.

I also feel that it might be more appropriate on [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) or [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), but again it needs to focus on the facts with a narrow scope.

Comment: I'd wondered whether Programmers might be a better fit for it, but it's not a site I use.

Comment: cheers for your input. Seems like such a question would just lead to controversies, and so there's no point adding such a question, whether it be useful or not to SO. I think I'll leave it be as, whilst it may be helpful, it might not exactly bring with it much 'desired' attention.

Comment: It might also be good if it can serve as a canonical for future dupe-closure. Actually phrasing such a post is a little more challenging.

Comment: @JamesThorpe you might want to take a look at **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat Thanks - that's useful.  I've seen a quote a couple of times here (not sure by whom, sorry) that is something along the lines of "if the problem is on the whiteboard, it belongs on Programmers.  If the problem is in your IDE, it belongs on SO" - would you say that's broadly true?

Comment: @JamesThorpe I think this is best stated in [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/165773)

Comment: @gnat Thanks again - another great post :)

Answer (score 2):

I like questions that help alleviate a major problem that many of us face, which boils down to decision anxiety. You're presented with three (seemingly) similar paths to take, each with potential gains and pitfalls, and you need to pick one.

***When the cost of resources required to simply try them all and see what happens practically precludes doing so, I'm all for asking folks that have already done it.***

In other words, it's something you can't just 'benchmark' (as [apaul mentions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1947286/apaul34208)) and make an informed decision based on data and how it relates to your use-case. We're talking about *critical* design paths that are difficult to test, and can result in *enormous* amounts of wasted time if you get them wrong.

If the answer you expect is "[Yes/no], and here's the data I got from my experience doing that" - then Stack Overflow is probably the right place to be. If you think good answers would start out with *it depends ...* - then you *might* still be okay to ask on Stack Overflow, but make sure you've stated your problem and expectations as an objective framework for folks to write an answer.

If it feels too theoretical, or you feel like you have a limited grasp of the size and nature of the problems you want to avoid, Programmers might be a better bet.

If you can get your answer with a short amount of time and effort in a lab, just hit the lab. If you turn up something unexpected and can't figure out why in the process, you've probably got a good question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'm not too sure how this answer should be interpreted with regard to the question. Are you suggesting OP should or should not ask their question? IMO your second-to-last paragraph seems the most applicable here as the proposed question feels rather theoretical (due to its brevity and lack of a specific use case), and OP seems to "have a limited grasp" of the involved concepts (e.g. asking if inline CSS or SVG cause additional http requests). So, do you recommend OP should ask the question on programmers.SE?

Comment: He's saying it depends on the nature of the question, and implying that this is a judgement only OP can make.

Comment: @BoltClock The problem is that it's not only the OP that makes that judgement, it's also the first 5 close-voters who come across it and feel it's not quite right (even though there may be other people with the ability to vote for closure who think it's an acceptable question: they don't get to cancel close votes, at best they can vote to re-open).

Comment: @Bruno [Here's a related feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252010/allow-keep-open-voting-outside-review-queue#comment153498_252010) where you could pre-emptively vote against close-voters.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

because I do not consider it off-topic. It's not really opinion-based (like "*Is SVG better than CSS?*" would be) but asking for rational arguments, and in which situations each technology is appropriate.

You are basically looking for a **canonical question**. Indeed, these tend to be a bit broad, but canonical answers need to be broad. If you are certain that the question will be answered with extensive and high-quality answers, either because you plan to self-answer or know that other users will take care, then go for it. You should be able to ensure that the answer is backed by the community and there are efforts to maintain it. If you want to team up for that, post a community-wiki answer.

Answer (score -7):

I think it depends on which [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) you ask the question. If you ask the question on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/), it may be okay.

It all depends on *where* you intend to post the question. But I think with so many StackExchange sites to choose from, any question has an appropriate place somewhere.

Comment: We're on MetaStackOverflow, so he intends to post it to SO.