# Why are questions about how to shape divs getting closed for being too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, needs-more-focus

Here's an example:

[Parallelogram with an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526008/is-it-possible-to-get-a-div-to-be-this-shape)

[Different shaped divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474634/different-shaped-divs)

It's true there may be more than one way to do it, as there often is with programming (and I admit, neither question is well titled), but the actual question here is really quite specific and the image itself shows a precise shape.

It's easy to answer this question with two or three clear, succinct ways to do it, having looked at the options, picked the best and answered with a section for the cutting edge and a section for legacy browsers. In each case the picture tells the answerer everything they need to know.

This would be no different from an answer that lists a JavaScript way, a jQuery way and CSS way.

EDIT:

[Should a fairly off topic question that would be beneficial for the community be asked?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296748/should-a-fairly-off-topic-question-that-would-be-beneficial-for-the-community-be)

this has been suggested as a duplicate, but I don't feel the answers there cover my question for these reasons:

- the question suggested is very subjective / broad, even though there are several answers to the questions I link, the actual questions ask about very specific shapes
- the 'too broad' tag in my seems to be being used to apply to a 'not enough research' question, rather than a borderline subjective question
- the answers refer to 'off-topic' type of question, such as one that would be better on Programming.SE or Quora - these questions definitely belong on SO because they are 'how do I do *X* with programming language *Y*'
- the css shapes element is a co-incidence

Comment: lol, sorry for initially linking to my answer on one of the questions, that was unintended!

Comment: Too broad is also used to mean "no research shown", that the user didn't appear to try himself first.

Comment: @GabeSechan: ...and I vote to reopen every time I see that.  The actual wording of the reason bears no relation to such questions, since it's both clear what's being asked and the answers are typically quite short.  Downvoting works [just fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) to get rid of such questions.

Comment: @Kevin I'm going to disagree there.  Downvoting doesn't work, too many people answer anyway.  And if people answer anyway, the asker never learns.  I wish they would bring back the no effort close reason, but people will continue to use too broad until then.  Including me.  Although that doesn't mean that all no-code questions should be closed, I'd probably have been ok with these.

Comment: I think with some css questions, especially for a newbie, it's hard to even know what to try and css shapes fall into this category, the answers are either cutting edge stuff most people don't know about or something counter intuitive like use .pngs - is it OK for a user to say 'I've read about this and I have no idea what to even try'?

Comment: 2nd question still should be closed.No research effort.Just only an image and online text.That question seems like asking how can I solve 5*3

Comment: @ShaifulIslam - if you've never done Maths before, 5*3 is a difficult question and you might not know where to start looking

Comment: So I would first learn math and then I would solve it.I would not ask how to calculate 5*3 without learning basic.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam and what happens if you try to learn and get stuck on something simple, do you give up, or do you ask for help?

Comment: I would ask question if I don't find any solution.But that question demands us to solve the problem.Did not tell where he got stuck.answer of this post will make you clear.

Comment: @GabeSechan - Doesn't a sufficient number of down votes trigger the "Low Quality" close reason or am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: _is it OK for a user to say 'I've read about this and I have no idea what to even try'?_ @ToniLeigh - It would need to be more specific like, "I've been searching for [search term 1],  [search term 2], ...  [search term n] and reading resulting articles on [topic 1], ... [topic n] but don't seem relevant in solving my problem." That would at least help other users see why you haven't found the info you need and someone could comment, "You should be searching for [search term X] instead."

Comment: @ToniLeigh - Even then you should provide some sort of "the closest I could get is this" type of code or even "this is where in the code I want to do this" code. That's also useful in being able to tell why someone's getting stuck. Don't make people start from scratch and don't hide other potential issues/bugs by not showing what you're doing.

Answer (score 29):

This isn't really about [css-shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-shapes), it's about users making no attempt to solve their own problem, not demonstrating any research, and not really giving any starting point.

"But, those are reasons to downvote, not vote to close…" I know…

**That said…**

I would have voted to close [Different shaped divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31474634/different-shaped-divs), and honestly too-broad fits well enough. There really isn't any meat to the question, the user couldn't even offer a reasonable use case, so there isn't really any context.

I probably wouldn't have voted to close [Parallelogram with an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526008/is-it-possible-to-get-a-div-to-be-this-shape). It's not much better, but at least the user mentioned what they're trying to accomplish. I probably would have posted a comment requesting more info and the relevant markup.

These tend to get closed because many people just get tired of the "Do it for me…" type questions.

**We're generally happy to help you do it, but we're less happy to do it for you.**