# Enough fuzzying: let's let everything into the close queue and age out questions that don't reach a threshold

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review-queues, vote-to-close

We've just about hit equilibrium here: [Fuzzy the number of questions in the close review queue, a dopamine for the shutterers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252572/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut)

The number of questions in the queue is falling slowly, but I don't think we're going to clear it out any time soon. And even if we did, that would just mean re-introducing a gigantic backlog of questions with only 1 vote or flag on them - thus bringing us back to where we started.

This was intended to be a temporary solution, to catch what fell through the cracks - I think it's safe to say we've done that, but continuing this way long-term is actively harmful to the goal of getting bad questions closed quickly.

So let's try a more focused approach...

Once upon a time, *all* close votes aged away after 4 days. This was great for not having a backlog - but terrible for folks active in obscure topics where the number of close voters was small. [The current vote-aging system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away/166124#166124) was put into place to address this, at the cost of a perpetual backlog.

I think we can have the best of both worlds. Here's what I propose:

- Two parameters:

  1. **FlagsAgeDaysThreshold**: the number of days old the newest vote or flag must be for a question to remain under review. Default value: 4
  2. **FlagsThreshold**: the number of votes or flags required for a question to remain under review once FlagsAgeDaysThreshold has been exceeded. Default value: 3.
- A single vote or flag on a question will send it into /review.
- After FlagsAgeDaysThreshold has been exceeded, the question will be removed from review *if FlagsThreshold has not been met*.
- [Existing aging rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away/166124#166124) will still apply - votes will not be discarded until they are met.
- If a question aged out of review and later attracts another vote or flag, it will re-enter review until either FlagsAgeDaysThreshold or FlagsThreshold are no longer met.

If this were implemented today, the queue length would immediately drop to 7,531, and *I suspect* remain fairly stable at that level - we would want to adjust FlagsThreshold as necessary to keep a reasonable backlog however (1-2 thousand at minimum), so as to encourage filtering and discourage [review-racing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip/252267#252267).

This would allow egregiously-bad questions to be closed more quickly, while preventing borderline questions from hanging around in limbo waiting for votes.

Unlike the current system, I believe this could be operated indefinitely (with proper adjustments to the parameters) without negatively impacting the community's ability to quickly close poor questions.

Comment: In addition, can we reset close votes on questions to be removed; e.g. if I VtCed it, can I please re-vote on such a post if I were to come across it again? Just the one reset.

Comment: This sounds good to me.

Comment: As I said, this should not affect *vote* aging at all: if it drops out of the queue because no one saw it or cared about it, your vote should remain until enough people do see it / care about it, @martijn

Comment: Wouldn't this still more or less continuously drop questions from obscure topics from /review?

Comment: Some of them, but some of that is unavoidable @Anna. If we can't get enough reviewers in to address the number of *questions* coming in, there will be things falling through cracks no matter what we do - some of the work you're doing should help with that though. Right now, they're not even getting *into* review, which is a bigger problem than a few of them getting overlooked.

Comment: @Shog9 Reasonable.

Comment: @AnnaLear: It seems to me that a bad question will be a bad question regardless of topic.  The obscure topics' bad questions get their close votes aged away because the questions *never get seen*.  This sounds like it'd fix that problem.

Comment: @cHao Seems like a net no-op to me unless/until, as Shog also mentioned, we can get more people to do reviews. Having an obscure bad question dropped into review only to have it age out of it (and then subsequently age the votes... eventually) doesn't seem like it's gonna do much for that particular set of bad questions.

Comment: @Shog9: Right, which means I'd have to bring attention to it in a chat room or something, same way I do now. Sounds good.

Comment: Are all days equal? Or do some days get significantly more review traffic? (4 seems low enough to have weird patterns emerge).

Comment: @AnnaLear: Having better relevance for questions in the Close Queue (rather than chipping away at questions that nobody cares about anyway) would certainly improve *my* motivation.

Comment: This sounds like a really good idea. I like how a compromise was made to both keep old close votes while removing the old votes from the queue.

Comment: For now we keep the [SO close vote reviewers chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) alive with its weekly events... It doesn't sound unreasonable though...

Comment: What this still doesn't address is that sometimes the fastest way for a question to be closed would be for certain users to have increased close vote weight. For example, if there were some sort of deputy mod that had the power to cast 4 close votes or have an increased weight to their close vote.

Comment: Four gets you through the weekend, @Flexo. There are patterns to review, but then again there are also patterns to question asking, and I'm not sure it's worth it to try and find a formula that keeps them in sync. I'm asking that this be made configurable so that we can adjust it if necessary to deal with unintended consequences if they do emerge though.

Comment: @Shog9 well done. thank you for all efforts on this issue.

Comment: What would the number of questions in the queue be if FlagsAgeDaysThreshold were increased to 7?

Comment: As of this moment, 10543 - compared to 7901 for 4 days. @Ben

Comment: @Shog9 Would it be possible to do something like this, but still leave a way for someone who's using a filtered view of the queue to get at the full list when they finish the filter, to help people who *are* willing to help in those less-frequented tags?

Comment: Not easily, although you can get a full list for any tag from the Stack Exchange Data Explorer if you're interested, @Billy.

Comment: @Shog9 Not enough rep on SO to pitch in much here, sadly. Hmm, maybe a link to a relevant DE query could be added to the empty queue message if filtering only on tag? I'm in favour of this idea in general, but it just feels like there's gotta be a way to keep it from affecting low-activity tags too strongly, given that it's only the review task that would be aging away, not the votes.

Comment: We need privilege to close question in one click. I'm really suffering of many questions remain open with my vote standing alone. This is an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23290133/1771795), I can't re-vote even.

Comment: @Omar, or a better close vote ageing system.

Comment: IMO, if your close vote expires, there's no reason you should not be able to vote it again in the future. If they're worried that someone will perpetually keep a question in the close vote queue, then introduce a cooldown period if it is absolutely necessary. The "no re-voting" thing appears to attempt to address a problem which does not actually exist.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Implemented and going live in build rev `2014.5.7.2223` on meta and `2014.5.7.1592` on sites. Expect the number of items in the close queue to drop a bit.

Comment: Just an aclaration, will this be active for *all* the sites?

Comment: it's the same as with fuzzying; it'll be active on SO only, but can be turned on anywhere if the need arises

Comment: Now that this is changed, are there any new statistics on the close votes queue? What percentage drop out of review? And what is the distribution of time in queue for items which complete review respectively drop out of review?

Comment: I notice the close review queue is currently a bit over 13K. Did this not happen, or has FlagsThreshold not been adjusted, or was there later reconsideration...?

Answer (score 48):

I think the community at large is getting very tired of spending more time reviewing poor content than providing answers to good content.

Lower the threshold to close questions or increase the voting weight of a specific set of users either through election or automation. Something! Help us, help you.

5 experienced users reviewing a really crappy post with their time, 40 times a day, is ridiculous.

> "the problem is that there's more crap than there are folks who can close it." -**[Shog9♦](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow#comment8344_252547)**

Comment: The point of that statement is that closing is fundamentally the wrong tool for the job when it comes to dealing with mediocre (vs. off-topic / unclear) questions. Making it work for this would require more than  a few users with extra voting power.

Comment: I agree with Travis. I think experienced users should have more power to say it is not good, close it asap IMHO. What is wrong about 3 cvs to close a question?

Answer (score 18):

> If a question aged out of review and later attracted enough votes or
>   flags to meet FlagsThreshold, it would be re-introduced.

I think any new close votes or close flag should reintroduce the item to the review queue.

Also I don’t think the current close vote ageing system works well at all on SO,  I have seen too many duplicates when the close votes has aged way.    These take effort to review so often get skipped, hence we can’t depend on the review system acting on duplicate close votes.

Firstly don’t count views by people that are not users.   (Have 2 view count on each question)

Maybe even don’t count views from any users that have not casted at least some close votes/flags.

At least in the case of duplicates it should be the number of views AFTER the last close vote has been casted.   I have seen duplicates when the number of views is now low, so in 4 days no one may view the question, but it had lots of views before the duplicate was found.

Comment: Hmm... You identified a pretty major error in my description above - I'm assuming "age of newest vote" at the start and "age of oldest" at the end, which doesn't actually make any sense. Correcting...

Comment: Yes, Ian, it takes time and effort to correctly flag a post as a duplicate, and now it seems like my effort to CV can just vaporise.