# Probationary period for Questions to be Answered to encourage better questions with more effective Moderation?

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions, low-quality-posts, new-users

### An idea that was formed from some discussion:

[More effective closing / downvoting of junk questions to help with the signal-noise ratio?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-down-voting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal)

### How about a waiting period for Questions to be Answered:

You have to wait a certain period of time before you can **Accept** an answer in order to give time for better answers to appear. **This is no different.**

*There is no special queue, or special set of people that approve and nothing is invisible.*

#### Why not do the inverse:

Low Reputation users or Users with lots of Closed/DownVoted/ZeroVoted questions can submit questions, but they can't be **Answered** until some time has passed to give the community time to enhance the question or curate it to **allow for a better question** to be submitted or be moderated appropriately before the reputation whores get to it.

#### There are lots of tuning opportunities here:

1. Once you get a certain rep your **Questions** no longer are subjected to the probationary period.
2. Having a low accept ratio would extend the probationary period.
3. Having a majority of Closed/DownVoted questions would extend the probationary period.
4. Having a high accept ratio would reduce the probationary period.
5. Having a majority of Accepted/UpVoted questions would reduce the probationary period.
6. CloseVotes / DownVotes / UpVotes could increase or decrease the probationary period.
7. Moderators could remove the probationary period immediately if flagged.
8. Maybe you could spend Reputation to get your question published quicker, similar to the *Bounty* concept.

#### Immediately increase the quality of answers if nothing else:

This would would be a huge dis-incentive for those posting terse, half-baked or naive answers immediately and would give those that take the time to actually respond with a **good** answer time to be on equal footing.

#### Doesn't have to be a long wait to have a huge impact:

This could potentially solve lots of the problems with the drive by/vampire/anonymous/one time users that are just shot gunning the internet for an immediate *quick fix*.

Comment: But in summary: delaying answers or hiding answers won't stop people from posting *anyway* (in a separate editor until they can post or hidden) in the hopes of being first with their answer to an obvious question.

Comment: @Mysticial - you mis-understand that suggestion, it would not give high-rep an advantage in Answering but in not having their Questions subject to the waiting period. Much like you can't comment, edit, moderate or other things without a certain rep score. I re-worded it to be more specific and clear hopefully. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Related: [Place answers into demilitarized zone instead of 5 minute grace period](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/230709)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson You're right, I did misread.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - bully for them, but it would be a majority wasted effort of the terrible questions never make it to active state. They won't spend time on questions that reasonably aren't going to become active. I don't think that your scenario is a concern.

Comment: How long do you think it'd take for a stackapp to be built that automatically submits a given answer when a post emerges from this lock?

Comment: This was already more or less proposed [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214813/novice-questions-approval-queue) (closed as duplicate of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185530/should-questions-by-new-users-have-to-be-approved-before-becoming-generally-visi))

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I think the differentiating factor is there is no special queue for the questions and the questions aren't invisible. I think this suggestion is fundamentally different and more inline with the way the site works already. Delayed Acceptance is the model and explained in the very first justification. **The idea is there is a period where the question can be improved or closed that will eliminate the reward for drive by answers and rep-whoring**

Comment: @Servy - I don't think that is a concern if the questions never make it to an `active` state there is nothing for the `bot` to post to.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson But it would mean that anything that does ever become active would be immediately flooded with tons of answers in a matter of seconds.

Comment: @Servy how is that any different than the current situation? I see crap duplicate Questions with 10+ equally crappy answers and a dozen up votes before it can be closed as a duplicate. I don't think that there are that many people that would be willing to waste time queuing up answers in another program just on the likelihood that something **might** open up. Also, the time would give the **good** answers time to be written and formatted nicely and be submitted at the same time as the crap answers, **it would actually level the playing field** while being punitive to the lazy rep-whores.

Comment: Related at least in spirit, from Meta.SE: [Should questions by new users have to be approved before becoming generally visible?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185530). Also [Require a net +1 for questions in high-volume tags to become answerable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108822)

Comment: @JoshCaswell - this isn't related to that, there is no queue and nothing is invisible. This is fundamentally different and more inline with the normal operation of the site. Accepts have a waiting period for example and lots of stuff requires rep to do.

Comment: I am sceptical that that askers would improve their questions in the probationary period or that other users would go the extra mile to edit them. But I do think this would make many people **think twice** about asking questions that could be solved more quickly in other ways.

Answer (score 24):

I strongly support that idea.

**Benefits**:

1. Main one: People who post bad questions in search of quick gratification would be at least partially **dis-incentivized** from doing so (assuming the warning about the delay is prominent).

   This means "do my homework for me", "debug this code dump so I don't have to", "lmgtfy", and other such instant gratification questions would be reduced in volume.
2. As a corollary to #1, it would reduce the strain on the moderating users (closers/downvoters).

   This has two effects: first, it would directly improve the amount of bad stuff being moderated - since they would have less crap to moderate.

   Second, it would encourage people to re-start moderating who simply gave up when they saw crap multiplying and no effort on SE's part to help stem it, leaving aside the OPPOSITE signal sent by the "Summer of Love".
3. Helps address "Fastest Gun in the West" issue.

   Having the questions stew without answers for a probation period would let people who post GREAT content compete on even footing with TFGITW posters. If you have to wait before posting an answer; you are thereby dis-intentivized from posting quick bad answer, as the speed of writing it won't bring the benefit of getting in on the question early.

---

Admittedly, this approach would have some drawbacks, but IMHO those would be easy to address and ameliorate:

1. *Problem:* It may disincentivize good users who like the concept of "fast service" yet would have posted a good question otherwise.

   *Solution:* Transparency. Explain WHY you have the delay. If you are truly a serious potential user; you would be GLAD to be made aware that you pay the cost of a couple of hours waiting for the future benefit of better visibility for your good future questions that no longer have to compete for attention with seas of crap.
2. *Problem:* People wouldn't bother answering an "old" question once it becomes answerable

   *Solution*: Bump the question when it becomes eligible for being answered; as if it was edited. This will bring it back on top of the "active" queue.

   *Solution #2*: More drastic - reset the question ask time the moment it becomes eligible for answering to be current time, pretending that the question was JUST asked. This 100% eliminates the problem; but presents a minor downside that some people would see the question twice (once when it was first posted, second, when it becomes eligible for editing). Frankly, too minor of a downside to offset the other benefits.

Comment: "It may disincentivize good users who like the concept of "fast service" yet would have posted a good question otherwise" Good question, quick answer? Not possible.

Comment: @bjb568 - sure it is **possible** (whether likely or not is different story). "My code generates this weird error XYZ" "Yeah, I saw that error 2 years ago, you need to twiddle config setting BLU to value 42 to fix that".

Comment: Yes, I should have said unlikely.

Comment: I agree as a general rule, good questions do not have fasted gun in the west quick answers

Comment: Some other ideas to alleviate problems: 1. Scale the delay by reputation, or make delay-less questions a rep-based privilege. 2. Allow *posting* of answers immediately, but hide them from everyone except the answerer until the delay ends.

Answer (score 12):

Implicit in the question you've asked is the notion that we should be somehow concerned about *anything except for the present moment.*

This problem was brought into sharp relief for me when Shog9 posted this: [Enough fuzzying: let's let everything into the close queue and age out questions that don't reach a threshold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions), which states the premise that, if close votes are languishing in the close queue, then by definition they aren't all that important, because *nobody is paying any attention to those questions anyway.*

The close system is constantly hampered by this notion of time. Should we help users improve their question in the comments?  Why don't we give them a probationary period?  They are new users, after all; shouldn't we give them a break?  What about bad tags or questions that never got closed; aren't we sending the wrong signal?

The real question you should be asking yourself is this:  **What can I do about this post right now?**  If the question is vague, incomplete, off-topic or otherwise unanswerable, by far the best thing you can do for the site as a whole is to **vote to put the question on hold,** and move on to the next question.

**On hold is the probationary period.**  Putting the question on hold gives the OP time to improve their question so that it can get [reopened](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen).

The reason you don't see more people voting to close questions is because they don't understand the purpose of closing, or they think they have to follow-up on the post, or that we're somehow being unfair to people.  It's too much work, in other words; too much cognitive dissonance.

You don't have to follow-up, leave snarky comments, bookmark the question so that you can check on it later, or hand-hold the OP in any way.  Just vote to close the question, and find a new question that is answerable.

Comment: I see this as another side of that coin, if the question is closed before it can garner *"answers"* then it is better than the current situation. The limited pool of people that **do** vote to close is actually about 25% - 30% of those that **can**. [See my link with my research on these numbers.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-down-voting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal) I think this suggestion gives those limited resources more time to respond to the crap before rather than after the fact. This suggestion is about **before** as much as **now**

Comment: I think there are a dearth of engaged people that can actually vote to close. The ratio of them vs the incoming horde is much greater than most people think.

Comment: There are currently 21,420 users on Stack Overflow who have vote to close privileges (give or take a few).  I don't think we lack the resources; I think we lack the will.  Anyway, if I'm prevented from answering someone's question for 10 minutes (or whatever the time period is), what incentive do I have to come back later?

Comment: I ran numbers on the 30K+ users the percentage that vote period is disheartening. I already quit frequenting the site as much as I used to, I moderate much less and if something isn't done or at least attempted I am going to *retire* from moderating completely like a lot of other people have. **I like to help those that show the effort to deserve the help, that number is mighty small now and getting smaller and they are being drowned out by the noise.**

Comment: You only need 3K to vote to close.  Like I said, the problem is not available people, it's convincing them that voting to close is the right thing to do.

Comment: I know but you would think the 30K+ users would be good examples, apparently they aren't. I can't expect *new* 3K+ people to know any better from the poor examples being set! **There was the "Summer of Love", which seems to have been a bad idea in the long run; maybe we need a "Summer of Vote to Close"**.

Comment: I suspect that many of the old timers decided that the contention involved in closing posts (and the ensuing meta drama) was simply not worth it (the Summer of Love was part of that drama).  People don't have to explain their close votes; it still takes four other people to agree before a question gets closed.  And the situation is much better now; the close reasons are clearer, more self-explanatory, and far less ambiguous than they used to be.  It's been said before, but it's worth repeating: *voting to close is not being mean; it's the right thing to do.*

Comment: I still think we need **"Close: You are a lazy mooch that should never be allowed to be behind a keyboard ever again!"** That would be *clearer, more self-explanatory and far less ambiguous* and any options we have now! :-)

Comment: Shog9 seems to think that you can make one of the existing close reasons stick, most of the time.  "Code dump, how fix" questions can be closed as "insufficient information."  `icanhazcodez` questions can be closed as Too Broad, although I am far less bothered by those (which can be useful to others) than I am by the "troubleshoot my code for me" questions (which are only useful to the OP, never for anyone else).

Comment: [See my original post about making it easier to close for those that do, and see where the onus from this idea came from.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-down-voting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal)

Comment: I've already seen it.  The algorithms are not the problem; the soul being sucked out of close voters is the problem.  Close voters have nothing to apologize for; they should feel free to exercise their privilege without being constantly harangued about being too mean.

Comment: Then we need a **2014 Summer of Close Voting** campaign!

Comment: @robert - I'm sorry, but I think you may be misunderstanding the main gist of the proposal based on your answer. The **main** benefit of the probationary period is not so much in allowing people to improve their now-bad questions - it is to **dis-incentivise** help vampires who seek immediate gratification (homework, gimmezecodez, lmgtfy)....

Comment: @RobertHarvey - ... If you have to wait for a certain period before you can get answers to your question, **and are warned about it upfront before posting**, you won't be as likely to post those kinds of questions. There are other side benefits which aren't resolved by closing process (This is free and not taxing closers who are already stretched thin; leaving them with less bad question to handle).

Comment: While a question on-hold could be considered to be in a state of "probation", it's too-late by that point as it has already consumed moderation resources. The "probation" is on the wrong side of the fence; it should be on the question being **asked**, not answered. If moderators are overburdened, the solution/s are to lessen that burden. This can be done by either increasing moderation supply (via engaging more moderators, increasing moderator power, etc.) and/or decreasing moderation demand (via "asking probation", show/hide queue, new question limit, etc.).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think this answer completely misses the point. Beside discouraging help vampires who seek fast&cheap solutions another advantage of OP's idea would be no FGITW unnecessary answers to duplicates and bad questions. Such answers do encourage unwanted behaviour and duplicate information on the site.

Comment: "the best thing you can do for the site as a whole is to vote to put the question on hold" Ok. Crap question posted. CV, -1, VLQ. Answer posted. Answer posted. Answer accepted. Answers up voted to +1, +2. An hour latter, the post is +2/-4, closed, your VLQ flag is disputed, and since it's answered Community won't delete it. 10kers don't delete 5% of what deserves immediate deletion because they reportedly don't have enough votes, there aren't may 10kers, most 10kers don't bother with it, and the question has to be closed first.

Comment: @bjb568: Downvotes help too.  If people are going to use the site this way, make them pay for it, at least a little.  Now, not later.  The whole point of my answer is *don't wait.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey The whole point of my comment is *I don't wait*. Waiting or not, the crap is there. This proposal is to deter it and give time to CV before the crap storm of answers come in.

Comment: @bjb568: I don't see how you can interpret this proposal as anything but yet another delay tactic.  Are you saying that you can close vote, but not allow people to answer during the probationary period?  That hardly seems fair.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hmm? Bad questions should not get answers, ever, and answerers should be penalized for posting their answers. Ok questions will have a rush of bad answers, giving a wait period will allow the good answerers time to finish writing their answer without rush. Good questions will not be affected since answers shouldn't be posted in the wait period. Seems like a win-win-nothing.

Comment: @bjb568: I'm here, right now, with an answer to the question.  Why are you making me wait 10 minutes to post it?

Comment: @RobertHarvey A) If it's a bad question it needs time to be closed (closing is a slow process, I think 5 people is too much), B) You can improve your answer in the 10 minutes, don't just post a link to the docs, C) In the first 5 minutes, the question may be edited substantially, D) Making the question asker wait discourages help vamping (and shuts off answers if it manages to be closed fast enough so help vampires and rep whores will both be taken care of) E) If you do have an answer in 10 minutes, is it a good question? Maybe you should downvote it.

Comment: @bjb568: In the vast majority of cases, when I've written an answer that has been well received, it is an answer that *I already knew.*  It didn't take me 10 minutes to figure out what the answer was.  That's the whole point of expert knowledge.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Worst case, you get there in the beginning, the question is excellent (no clarifying or editing needed), you know the answer. Well, the 10 minute wait forces you to like... proof-read your answer. I don't see a problem with that.

Comment: @bjb568: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24894618, posted two minutes after question was asked.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How often are perfect questions that are easy enough to answer fast posted?

Comment: @bjb568: About as often as good questions are posted.  Which isn't very often.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Are you saying good questions can't come from editing an ok question? Good questions aren't hard?

Comment: @bjb568: I'm saying that they're seldom asked.  Y'know, this delay tactic might actually work, if there is some basis for actually delaying the question, like the automated quality filter score was too low.  Or, you could only allow users above 150 rep to answer for the first 5 minutes.   Of course, that would seriously handicap the 1 rep folks, desperately looking for any way to earn some reputation so that they can gain some ghetto-free privileges.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hm... using the quality algorithm to determine how long of a wait period is a good idea. But no, definitely not answerer rep-cutoff. There are rep whores with 50k.

Comment: that [strawman](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24894618) should have been marked as a duplicate, not answered.

Answer (score 7):

Good idea would be to utilize **First Posts Queue** for that.

I'm not sue how many people must review the post before it leaves the queue, but judging how quickly that queue is processed, it wouldn't hurt if it was at least 5.

Simply add the feature, that the question is **not visible** on the site until it leaves the First Posts queue.

This will prevent, at least initially, very low effort questions to be quickly answered, therefore strenghtening the **spoonfeeding-request** behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

I want to offer an amendment to the proposed idea that I think covers some of the expressed concerns, plus may help resolve some other issues.

New questions by users in probation (by some criteria) are put in a "waiting" hold.  However, this hold merely prevents answers from appearing on the question.  Users can still post answers, however answer will not appear until the question is out of the holding period.  This has two benefits: users who need to be on probation (because they're new, have a very low accept ratio, have too many negatively voted questions, have too many closed questions, etc) don't get the quick answer.  Existing users who might post an answer are encouraged to instead take the appropriate action of close-voting bad questions (duplicates).  Answers posted during this waiting period on questions that end up on hold before the waiting period is over will simply never be posted and become visible for upvotes or accept votes.  Comments can still be posted and appear as normal.

The wait period is purely time-based (by some formula based on the criteria), *however* downvotes can extend the wait period, and upvotes can decrease the wait period.  If a new user posts an excellent question that immediately receives several upvotes, there will be no wait.

The immediate impact would be disencitivizing existing users from answering bad questions.  Their answer will stop appearing, and they'll stop getting rep.  The long-term impact is that there should be fewer repeat offenders of bad questions.  As soon as existing users learn they'll get no benefit out of answering questions that should be closed, they'll stop wasting time answering low-effort questions.  With fewer low-effort questions receiving answers, fewer low-effort questions will be asked.

Answer (score -1):

The feature you are asking for already exists. A question that is **on hold** cannot be answered. After it has been cleaned up and edited, it can be re-opened (taken off hold) and then answers can be added. We have review queues for first questions, and we have users who regularly look at particular tags, and a mechanism that enables 5 users to put a question on hold if it can't be answered as it is written. (Sometimes, those users choose to improve the question instead.)

Therefore what you're really asking for is that questions from low rep users be "born on hold" - that someone will need to review or edit them in order for anyone to answer them. This seems extreme to me. While most crappy questions are from new users, it doesn't follow that most questions from new users are crappy. Let's continue to put questions on hold **based on their content and the way they are written**, not based on who wrote them.

Comment: *Therefore what you're really asking for is that questions from low rep users be "born on hold" - that someone will need to review or edit them in order for anyone to answer them.* This **is not an accurate characterization**. You didn't read the entire question, I never mention mandatory review. I specifically state give some time to be voted on or edited before it becomes answerable. **Read for comprehension, Completely different things!**

Comment: "reviewing" and "voting on" are not different. "editing" and "editing" are not different. Try to stay polite, please.

Comment: No where do I propose that question will be should locked until **approved** in some way. No where do I propose that anyone must do anything to before it becomes available to answer. I just propose a waiting period to give people time to take appropriate action, like marking it closed or down voting **if needed** based on the content. I stand by my comment, yours is not an accurate characterization of my proposal in any way, and arguing that it is just further demonstrates a lack of comprehension or willful ignorance.

Comment: "it doesn't follow that most questions from new users are crappy" It does.

Answer (score -3):

As a new user, I mostly benefit from other's Q&A, but even I have noticed the increased low quality question flow, lately.

So I will make a humble suggestion, hoping that it has not been already made 1000X:

**SO rewards us more for quantity, than for quality.** Rewarding for quantity is in my opinion essential if this site wants to keep a large user base. But on the other hand, this encourages junk content. So why not **introduce a parallel rewarding system based on quality, and segregate privileges (and community) a bit on this base?** The catch would be to make it **discreet**, i.e invisible to very new users/incapable rep whores, to discourage new low-quality posters and would-be rep whores to whine about it unless they posted enough high quality content to gain access to the privileges attached to such content...

**A few ideas for practical implementation:**

- implement a quality score for each Q&A judged only by recognized high quality users
- leave present rep system in place to satisfy rep whores/low quality posters
- only high quality users can see the Q&A/user quality score to avoid making rep whores remember too much they are subordinates
- questions with no example code or error code cannot be high quality
- close meta sites to users whose content quality is too low (such as me)
- specific moderator/editor privileges to high quality posters that overcome those of rep whores
- ability for high quality users to filter questions based on quality score
- and many more...

**Basically, it would boil down to define what makes a good question/answer, and define an attached parallel privilege system.** But I think that **if you do not want to see this site die, it is essential to leave low quality users and rep whores a certain amount of freedom, since low quality posters are often beginner programmers looking to improve, so why not leave your army of rep whores deal with those easy questions/rep points?** Stratifying the reward system for quality would definitely allow high quality users to stay in control, and low quality users to stay on the site. Everyone wins: increasing website traffic, but high quality users recover the site they lost some time ago: good questions asked by good coders, answered by the same, just by using a simple filter.

Just my 2 cents...

Comment: The issue with this is that it would split SO. Yes, that would insulate the high-rep users from the garbage posters but it would also exclude them from new users altogether. The problem with that is, the genuine new users might be the reason some mods continue contributing to SO; it might be more about satisfaction from helping (or novelty) as opposed to gaining rep.

Comment: @dilbert Of course. That is why I was suggesting to 1.hide it a little 2.allow a permeability as high as possible between the segregated groups to encourage high quality content posting. At the same time, this might decrease the whining due to "closed as not constructive" issues. How much segregation is necessary is debatable and adjustable.

Comment: how are you suggesting the 'parallel' system works ? Another Rep count ? Two sets of upvote/downvote arrows (for quality and quantity) ?

Comment: @dilbert I would suggest leaving a single set of arrows, but adding to a separate rep stack depending on wether the voter is high quality. This would partially fuse the 2 rep stacks, in hope that users that persist posting would be educated enough not to post LQ questions by the time they gain access to high quality privileges. But I'm sure there are very good ways of devising such a system that I am not aware of.

Comment: the issue is, at what Rep count does a user become high quality ? Indeed, some Repwhores have quite a high count and might qualify.

Comment: @dilbert Yes, indeed. This is a problem because I see only 2 ways of dealing with it: 1.reboot community rep counts, which defies the "discreet" argument, 2.elect a "SO king" (bootstrap user) that would start quality rep propagation, which defies the "discreet" argument, and creates a temporary oligarchy. I hope somebody has a better idea to solve that...

Comment: Perhaps it could work as a tiered trust system. The 'high-quality' users group starts as all users above a certain Rep count. Over time, this group grows when a group member 'endorses' a lower rep user as 'high-quality'. Given Repwhores are selfish, they won't 'endorse' other Repwhores and so the group should remain relatively Repwhore free.

Comment: @dilbert yes, it would also be a way to do it. Anyway, I hope the SO establishment will try something along that line, because this site is extremely useful to me, and I don't want to see it die!