# If we want to tackle the problem of question quality, really simple questions need some legitimate avenue

Tags: discussion, feature-request

There's obviously a lot of talk on here about question quality lately, and a lot of suggestions for how to kill perceived bad content, which I think is misguided.

The fact is that there are people out there that really just don't know where to get started, and down votes and close votes don't really help them understand anything about their problem, or about how they should interact in this community, nor should they necessarily know where else to ask their more basic questions.  Searching for answers is a skill like any other, and requires practice and, in some cases, guidance.

Perhaps there could be a special "needs guidance" tag or flag that can be applied, which removes the question from the normal queue and sends it to an area just for this sort of thing.  If you want to go and help, go do it, otherwise ignore it.  Perhaps disable voting and answers for these questions to take rep out of the equation (if necessary), and just provide suggestions for these people to help themselves a little bit.  Handling it this way would allow for a quicker response (it wouldn't require 5 people marking it to get something done) since the result would be far less dramatic (the question would still be there and you could still interact on it without any negative feedback scaring the user off).

I know this sort of remedial education is not the primary goal of SO, but when you cultivate a reputation for a place to get answers, where else do you expect people to go?

Comment: I think there is a disconnect between the "really simple" of your title and the "needs guidance" in your question. There's a big difference between "These new users need help asking a good question, let's provide it without judgment" and "these new users need a simple typo to be fixed, let's answer them without judgment." Which do you mean?

Comment: Or... we just need to get better at closing as a duplicate quickly. Very quickly.

Comment: @DavidRobinson, I mean some variation of "these new users need help providing enough detail for a legitimate question" or "these new users just need to know a term they can search on" or the like.

Comment: @Ben, I don't think we could possibly ever be quick enough, at least not always.

Comment: Perhaps we simply have to more strongly and clearly move away from the notion that has crept in over the years that Stack Overflow is for everybody. If you can't formulate a good question and haven't a clue where to even start, perhaps it's just not the site for you.

Comment: Good luck with that.  The only way to get involved with the site as a new user is to post a question or post an answer.  You can't even comment without rep.

Comment: If that barrier comes with a loss of some new users, I'm not so sure that's too big of a drama @Jason. If that in turn somewhat increases the quality. I'm not saying SO needs to be "expert level". But you're talking about "people out there that really just don't know where to get started". Why should Stack Overflow cater to them?

Comment: What barrier?  My point is that you're encouraging people to jump into the deep waters right away by adding the kind of content that we want to be canonical before they can get involved with the site in any other way. And why should SO cater to them? Because they're coming here whether we want them or not.

Comment: You're effectively talking about creating a form of ghetto where all the "undesirable" questions would be directed. Who would even bother to go to this area? Who would watch over it? What if a good question ended up there by mistake, or one was edited into better shape?

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much the shape of what I'm suggesting. I think there's a fair number of teachers around about the place that would go in there to set some troubled souls straight, but perhaps I'm wrong, and if I am then it would likely turn out badly.  Editing could produce much the same action that it does for a closed question now, goes into a review queue (right?)

Comment: @Jason: Do you go into Yahoo Answers to help coders there? There's no shortage of "troubled souls" out there; there's a shortage of interesting and well-asked questions.

Comment: Maybe the rep-whores would hang out in there..

Comment: I read special "needs guidance" as "special needs" guidance :P

Answer (score 13):

To be clear, we don't discourage really simple questions.  They have just as much a right to be on Stack Overflow as the more "interesting" ones.  But question still need to be clear, answerable, and on-topic.

Unfortunately, the user who asks a simple question also tends to be the same person who won't understand your answer, because they have insufficient background knowledge.  They are the same folks who can't write a coherent question because their lack of fundamental skills underpins their confusion.  What these folks really need to do is curl up with an IDE and a good programming book, and learn some more fundamentals.

They're not going to get those fundamentals from Stack Overflow.  We're not set up to do that.

Comment: All I'm suggesting is that if these questions are handled in a less dramatic way (much in the way "closed" changed to "on hold"), that perhaps only one person might need to flag it to shunt it off to the side.  The people SO isn't set up to handle will continue to come, regardless

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252782

Answer (score 6):

Close votes do help because they give a reason for the close so that users **can** learn how to provide a better question. I agree that excessive downvoting new users is not helpful which is why I won't usually downvote if there already are a couple of them.

> Perhaps disable voting and answers for these questions to take rep out of the equation (if necessary),

This would allow for a slew of bad questions because people could just use the "need help" tag or whatever it may be and not be in fear of being closed.

The best thing we can do is comment and use the tools provided to help new users understand how to form a good question. I have seen some terrible questions **and** answers of which I have downvoted, voted to close, and or leave comments. Some users take the advice, reformat their q/a, and go on to help others. Some do not. It is ultimately up to the user.

Don't get me wrong, I love helping new users so I am in favor of anything that can help those that *really* want to create better posts and learn. I just don't think this way is really going to help. And, as I stated above, those that want to get better and are capable of doing so will get better by listening to the comments and suggestions of more experienced users.

Comment: "slew of bad questions" so what? If they are removed from the normal question queue, then what negative impact are they having?  Perhaps they could expire and be removed automatically with no action in a few days to a week?

Comment: So it seems we are going backwards by almost encouraging bad questions.

Comment: The site encourages bad questions by existing: it's a place to go and ask questions.  How do you expect someone who has a bad question to find someplace else to go with it?

Comment: Bad questions exist, yes, and that's not so bad. It's if they learn how to edit and make it better by listening to what is suggested that matters.

Comment: @Jason: Not every question deserves to be answered.  Everyone here has limited time to devote to this philanthropic endeavor; we need to reserve that time for those folks who express a willingness to help us help them.

Comment: There's a major difference between "do your homework" and "search for `term`", see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373086/show-something-to-a-first-time-site-viewer-for-only-an-hour)

Comment: @Jason I agree but that shows absolutely **no effort**. [See here](https://www.google.com/search?q=make+a+div+show+only+for+specific+time+php&oq=make+a+div+show+only+for+specific+time+php&aqs=chrome..69i57.3246j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). I don't know if any of that answers the OP's questions since I'm not concerned with that at the moment. But all I did was take a few words the OP used and put them into the Google. I'm sure something there could get the OP started and would allow to show some effort.

Comment: Absolutely you are correct, but instead of looking like someone who is unwilling to make effort, it looks to me like someone who doesn't know how.  I think the distinction is worthwhile

Comment: @Jason I see your point. However, I hate to sound harsh but if that person doesn't know how to do a simple Google search then they have a very tough road ahead in development. The way to handle that is, again, add a comment and possibly a link like what I posted in a comment showing them how easy a search is.

Comment: That's all I'm advocating, as well.  I'm just suggesting a way to flag a question to indicate that it's looking for that caliber of response even if you don't care to do it yourself, remove it from the normal question queue as a result, and allow all of that by the action of a single user (or maybe 2) in order to make it more responsive than the current system of close votes.

Comment: @Jason Luckily, I just [ran into something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23374823/common-string-using-in-activitites). Now, this question was pretty much unreadable before I attempted to clean it up but with two close votes. I'm not sure how what you are proposing would be any more beneficial than me editing and commenting. Now, hopefully the user will learn from what I have done but if not then nothing is going to help them. Or maybe this isn't quite what you have in mind...

Answer (score -2):

I completely agree with the reasoning behind the topic at hand. I would like some other kind of related forum sort of like proposed here: [The fourth place: Polling, Recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/the-fourth-place-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-stuff)

Where sub-par questions could be moved. This would allow the questions to be answered while also moving them away from the main queue. If somebody chose to answer these questions they could, but if you didn't want to you wouldn't. This would replace simply CLOSING the question which helps nobody.

People talk about needing to meet certain standards and increasing the quality? But what is the purpose of a question and answer site if not to help people? If more people can be helped at no detriment to others then I fail to see how that's a bad thing. I also don't see how one person is more worthy of help than another because he's more "expert."

I think that Stack Overflow is the clear place to go for questions, and is almost always the first on google search, and I just think it should find a way to try to be more welcoming while still maintaining the quality that is desired