# Should I try to have questions moved from Stack Overflow to Code Review?

Tags: discussion, questions, migration, code-review-se

All too often, I see posts (generally by new users) who have a syntax error or are having trouble with learning how to use a specific data structure in their code.  I feel like this type of question doesn't really contribute much to Stack Overflow.

Should these kinds of posts be moved to Code Review?  I'm not an expert on the intended purposes of either site, but I feel like users asking for other users to debug their code isn't relevant to what Stack Overflow is meant for.

I also hope that if this happens enough, then new users (and Google) will make Code Review more prominent in search results, and hopefully in all users' minds, so that these questions will appear less often on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Code Review is not for debugging. It's for suggesting improvements to *working* code.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Which site(s) would make more sense if I replaced "Code Review" with them in my question?

Comment: Why would we move our crap somewhere else?

Comment: SO is the best match for helping people with syntax errors. They don't really help future readers very much, but there's no better place for the OP to get the kind of help they need. So I usually answer them and then vote to close because of typo.

Comment: What we really need is a separate site for new programmers to get help with the basics. Kind of like the distinction between english.stackexchange.com and ell.stackexchange.com. That's where the second type of question you described would go (e.g. the hundreds of questions from people trying to implement linked lists or binary trees in C).

Comment: @Barmar: Would the experts ever go there?  See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252788/if-we-want-to-tackle-the-problem-of-question-quality-really-simple-questions-ne#comment9946_252788

Comment: If those hundreds of questions would be valid on this new site, that would pretty much violate the principle behind all Q&A's in the network. I'm not sure such a site would work within the guidelines for our sites.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's a good question. I kind of hope that there are some people who like to tutor beginners, and would volunteer at that site. As things currently are on SO, about once a week I randomly blow up at a novice and say "you really need to learn to program" because they don't understand when I tell them "Do that with a simple for loop".

Comment: @Bart How does English Language Learners fit into the guidelines? It seems to be targeted at basic questions that probably wouldn't be helpful to many future readers. But after a quick look, it seems like there's quite a bit of overlap with English Language and Usage.

Comment: If they indeed tolerate hundreds of questions on the exact same topic, they might have a problem.

Comment: So I understand the points you're all giving, but I don't see why this question should be downvoted.  Is it because someone thinks I'm not showing any research effort?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No; see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from the Code Review Help Center. Specifically, this seems pertinent to the examples you mentioned:

> However, if your question is not about a particular piece of code and instead is a generally applicable question about …
>
> - Best practices in general (that is, it's okay to ask "Does this code follow common best practices?", but not "What is the best practice regarding X?")
> - Tools, improving, or conducting code reviews
> - How to add a feature to or solve a problem with your code
> - Trouble-shooting, debugging, or understanding code snippets
> - Higher-level architecture and design of software systems
>
> then your question is off-topic for this site.