# Add 'related' forums for questions that don't belong here

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Someone else has already asked [Should Stack Overflow have a forum where users can talk about anything they want?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254466/should-stack-overflow-have-a-forum-where-users-can-talk-about-anything-they-want), but I think that forums for programming questions that, for whatever reason, don't belong here would be better than a completely open-ended but somehow related forum.

[*Edited* – I admit that this only seems workable in so far as it mitigates low-quality questions if it doesn't require the same kinds of moderation that are already being done to little avail.]

Part of the idea would be that 'too broad', open-ended, and 'too subjective' questions *would start* in the forums. Noobs and others with questions that aren't good enough to be part of The Canon could still find a receptive audience (or not).New users, or users with insufficient rep, would only be able to *ask questions in the forums*.

If a question is Good Enough, then it could be migrated to SO-proper.

But the reason why I'm proposing this as a feature request is that SO seems to be in *dire* need of some way to stem the tide of low-quality questions. The site, possibly even the network, *needs* some kind of at-least-semi-formal – and official – means of diverting The Deluge of questions Elsewhere. And if there was an Official Forum, then it could be integrated with SO more closely than otherwise, e.g. share tags, users, rep, etc. I think it would be interesting to consider how those now branded as Rep-whores might continue to serve their Fellows in a more suitable venue than SO.

Related questions:

- [If we want to tackle the problem of question quality, really simple questions need some legitimate avenue - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252788/if-we-want-to-tackle-the-problem-of-question-quality-really-simple-questions-ne)
- [Ability to Ignore Questions from low rep users - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252607/ability-to-ignore-questions-from-low-rep-users)
- [Thwart publishing duplicate and low quality questions - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253305/thwart-publishing-duplicate-and-low-quality-questions)

[Of course the forums should be hosted via [Discourse](http://www.discourse.org/)!]

Comment: Assuming that a "related" forum is a good idea, how would you shunt the "don't belong here" questions there?  Wouldn't you still have to see them first?  If you still see them, how does it stem the tide?

Comment: So we can spend time voting to migrate questions to another awful site instead of just closing them here? That... doesn't sound better.

Comment: To truly stem the tide, you'd want to force all questions (meeting some criteria, such as user age or user rep perhaps) to *start* in the forums.

Comment: Who's going to read them to decide which ones to promote to the real site? And why would they want to?

Comment: @Wooble, all the people reading – and answering – those questions already on this site. Give them some fraction of the rep they currently gain and they'll gladly do it.

Comment: I edited the 'question' as I now agree completely that requiring yet another form of moderation does nothing to really help improve question quality.

Comment: But people come to this site because they like a Q&A form. If they wanted a forum, they'd already be at one instead of here.

Comment: @Wooble, I disagree; people come here because other people help them with their (home)work. Does it seem like they respect the intent, the spirit, or the *form* in which they're made to request help? I've been unable to *find* an actual new 'question' of late; all of them have been 'I want to do X' or 'Why isn't this code working'? I mean, sure, if you squint real hard, there's a question (or a dozen) in those posts, but bleh.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the people who care enough that they'd want to triage posts to a forum to promote the ones that good enough to be Q&As are here because the format keeps out the awful forum posts. The help vampires, of course, will go wherever they get an answer. And eventually, that will be some other site because the crap forum will be unusable and people will stop answering.

Comment: @Shog9, I disagree that this is a duplicate. The two answers on the other question just list other SE sites. There's no answer as to where users can ask *programming* questions that don't fit the intended format of SO. Hence my suggestion to provide such a place and *explicitly* promote to alleviate low-quality question pollution.

Comment: Read the second answer more carefully, @Kenny.

Comment: @Shog9, sorry; I saw the links. Can I, and everyone else, assume that you closing this as a duplicate implies that there will *never* be an SO forum?

Comment: We have chat; I don't see us going further in that direction though. See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254466/should-stack-overflow-have-a-forum-where-users-can-talk-about-anything-they-want

Comment: @Shog9, I think I can reasonably write that *you* should have read my question more carefully. I linked to that meta-SO question *in the first sentence in my question*.

Comment: Again, please read the *answers*.

Comment: @Shog9, like my own answer? And the comments there? Are you trying to close my comments as duplicates?

Comment: This is why I hate comments. I'll just answer.

Answer (score 10):

[Stack Overflow was created with one goal in mind](http://blog.codinghorror.com/introducing-stackoverflow-com/):

> There's far too much great programming information **trapped in forums**, buried in online help, or hidden away in books that nobody buys any more. We'd like to unlock all that. Let's create something that makes it easy to participate, and put it online in a form that is trivially easy to find.

Obviously, creating a *new* system to trap information doesn't do much to further that goal - this was [pointed out by several people in the discussion you linked to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254466/should-stack-overflow-have-a-forum-where-users-can-talk-about-anything-they-want). Therefore, for the past 5+ years we've strenuously worked to avoid this trap by focusing on a strict Q&A model. For questions that *don't fit* this model, we've maintained [a helpful list of other places where folks can and should participate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254567/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow/254568#254568):

> #### Other/General
>
> - [Yahoo! Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/)
> - [Google Search](http://www.google.com)
> - [AskMeFi](http://ask.metafilter.com/)
> - [Quora](https://www.quora.com/)

If you find someone asking a question that is wholly inappropriate for Stack Overflow, don't hesitate to direct them to one of these.

Comment: I *understand* what you implied that *I didn't understand* by your comments like "please read the *answers*". And I understand that I must be frustrating to you; you're frustrating to me! I just happen to disagree that it's *obvious* that "a *new* system to trap information doesn't do much to further that goal" because I think a suitable new system might make it easier to cleanup *this* site. I fully understand that you disagree!

Comment: This is why I think you need to be a bit patient with [this discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254466/should-stack-overflow-have-a-forum-where-users-can-talk-about-anything-they-want) before you proceed with proposing alternatives. There's an awful lot of talk about the "quality problem", but a tremendous amount of disagreement as to what that actually *means* - so it's easy to throw out solutions that don't actually address the root of the problem, or that would actually make it *worse*.

Comment: What result could I reasonably anticipate about that discussion? Apparently the meta-SO community thinks more highly of the idea of a Stack Overflow forum that is *not* restricted to programming topics than one that is!

Comment: More highly? I'm not following your logic, @Kenny: if you're looking to clean up the site, why would you want to dump the refuse on a site you think highly of...

Comment: I'm not interested in a SO-theme forum that's not intended for programming topics, or not intended to be restricted to programming topics, so *I* don't think highly of Cupcake's suggestion; I'm indifferent. I also don't think low-quality questions are "refuse" to be *dumped* on some other, unfortunate site. I *do agree* that they're not appropriate here. But because they *are* here and they will continue to be *added* here, I think that it *might* be helpful for these questions to be 'gently' migrated elsewhere, if it was easy to do so.

Comment: *"... we've maintained a helpful list of other places where folks can and should participate..."*. That answer has been deleted (about 11 days after this answer...)

Comment: About half of the links in that answer were outside the Stack Exchange Network (25).

Comment: Thanks, @Peter; looks like this has perhaps outlived its usefulness.

Answer (score 2):

I find it telling the number of people here who are commenting on this solely considering the answerer's time and the annoyance of having to see "low-quality" questions.

What about thinking about being able to help a subset of people that are not able to be helped on this forum with its current restrictions?

Stack Overflow is absolutely ubiquitous on google. When looking for problems it almost always gives the best results. Unfortunately it also gives these results when it isn't actually being helpful at all. I've had questions I've desperately wanted answered, or problems I've had, and Stack Overflow results have turned up with my exact question. I eagerly click it, only to find that the question was closed. So here is my problem, right before my eyes, the only place that I could find it - but it was just closed and no answer was provided.

What would be very helpful would be if this question was moved to some subforum of some sort, where it could actually be answered. By redirecting me there (and hopefully posting in the original topic a message saying it was moved because it did not meet the standards, and then providing the link) I then realize that this type of question is not appropriate for the main site, BUT I am given a place to have it answered.

Who does it help when I find my problem but then just have a big "CLOSED" message waiting for me? I guess it helps the answerers because this question will not be re-asked, but it doesn't do much for me who needs help.

In my opinion, this is a great idea, because the Stack Overflow userbase is very intelligent and thus helpful and reliable. And the upvote/downvote system is very good at finding nice answers. It would be nice to be able to ask this set of people questions that don't specifically fit the restrictions of the site! This would certainly make the stream of bad questions no worse, since they would be moved, and probably people would find these questions through searches and be directed to the subforum - in addition, at least SOME People will catch on that this is the correct place to ask their questions.

It's true that it won't make the stream of bad questions that much BETTER. But what it WILL do is help a lot of people who needed help, and isn't that something we want to provide?

Answer (score -3):

One reason why it would be helpful to have a *sister site* for off-topic questions, discussion, and requests for help that are still related to programming is that there's no acceptable way to point users to a more suitable venue. See [my aborted attempt to simply list some alternate resources to which I could then point users that ask low-quality questions on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254704/173497).

Comment: `it would be helpful to have a sister site for off-topic questions, discussion, and requests`.... if I am following you correctly, this is what Programmers.SE was intended to be, but it failed miserable and was reborn as what it is today.

Comment: Nobody wants low-quality questions, because the only useful thing to do with them is shoot them on sight, and there is already an abundant supply at hand just about everywhere, to satisfy the most avid hunter.