# Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, faq, questions, site-recommendation

**Thank you for your confidence in our abilities!** But have you looked at the [Stack Overflow Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)?

Even though we get a lot of IT/network/computer/technical questions here, Stack Overflow is meant to be first and foremost a programmer's resource.

Other avenues more focused to your topic can give you a much better answer than a munching bunch of programmers.  It's also likely that your non-programming question may be downvoted and closed.

It's not that we *hate* you, it's just that we're programmers and [we like to keep our corn pops separate from our cocoa puffs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290806/do-you-try-to-make-your-code-look-pretty).

In that vein, where can you turn to? What forums can people go to to ask the questions that are off topic here?

[Return to FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225)

Comment: possibly related: ["Meta Stackexchange: Stack Exchange clones"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones).

Comment: see also: [What kind of questions belong on Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275082/what-kind-of-questions-belong-on-stack-exchange-and-stack-overflow)

Comment: The answer linked in the 4th paragraph was "removed from Stack Overflow for reasons of moderation". Remove the joke or put a screenshot for users who can't see deleted posts?

Comment: @Samathingamajig It's been undeleted

Comment: @wjandrea Neat. I've searched through the current version of the page (including all comments) and the edit history of the question and a few of the answers, and I'm unable to find anything involving the string "corn". Does anyone know if it was a comment, or if not, anyone care to explain "corn pops separate from our cocoa puffs"? My assumption is "we like to keep our [off-topic posts] separate from our [on-topic posts]" but even then I don't get what it's going for.

Answer (score 38):

Visit the [List of All Stack Exchange Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites). Here, you will find every site that exists on the Stack Exchange network along with a short description of each one and some stats.

**Warning:** While some of the site names may appear to be self-explanatory, you should *always* read the help center to find out what questions are considered on- and off-topic for that site. Never dive in and expect your question to be answered.

Other site names may not be self-explanatory, notably:

- **Super User**: personal computing software and hardware: Windows, home networking, etc.

  - Note that there are also some more specific sites like Ask Ubuntu, Unix & Linux, and Ask Different (Apple)
- **Server Fault**: professional system administration
- **Ask Different**: Apple products: macOS, iOS, iPhone, etc.
- **Cross Validated**: statistics, machine learning, data analysis, data mining, and data visualization
- **Computer Science Educators**: teaching computer science, including self-teaching / self-learning, i.e. what topics to include in a self-guided study plan.

Comment: +1 for "read the help center to find out what questions are considered on- and off-topic for that site". It really helps a lot.

Answer (score 21):

If you don't have the energy to go through the contents of every help centre on Stack Exchange sites to determine where to post your question, try [Quora](http://www.quora.com).

Pros:

- No off-topic rules. Anything could be asked.
- Good for opinion-based discussions and general suggestions.
- Rarely are questions closed, unless they're blatant trolls.
- Registration as well as real name is required to post both questions and answers. Considering the responsibility people generally associate with their real identity, this adds credibility to the answers.

Cons:

- Pure technical questions might not get answered quickly
- Lengthy registration process required prior to viewing content, nevermind asking or answering any questions
- Difficult to tag your question in a way that it will be seen by those who can answer it
- Primarily opinion and personal experience based, rather than objectively provable solutions
- Due to registration requirements little of the content is searchable via popular search engines
- Content is under a [variety of licenses](http://www.quora.com/about/tos), and there's no easy way to point others to content without also forcing them through a registration process

Comment: Consider adding your first "pro" as a "con".

Comment: I personally find that Quora sends quite a bit of spam, so I advise you add them to your spam blacklist..

Comment: @zyboxinternational you could control what mails they send you you know.

Comment: Additional sites worth considering: reddit.com and freecodecamp.org/forum

Comment: Another con is that question details were removed (comments can be used instead but it is not a good fit), so only the (one-line) question is left.

Comment: Reddit is good for removing some of the cons like technical problems. As long as you find the right Reddit community, you can probably answer anything. Should I add this as an answer?