# Doubt on closing (or not) a question related to programming but that does not fit a specific topic

Tags: support, close-reasons, questions

I'm asking here beacause in a previous answer ([Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254567/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow)) I cannot find a specific reponse for it.

The following SO question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809369/does-switching-an-iphone-app-from-paid-to-free-reset-ratings-reviews

is related to iOS and App Store but based on my opinion does not fit the *What topics can I ask about here?* section that can be found at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

So, where should the OP ask a similar question?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I definitely agree with your assessment of the question. As for where to ask it, I would have looked someplace dedicated to support for that sort of topic. The user pretty much got their answer already, though. hehe. One tiny note: Your comment could have been a tiny bit more diplomatic, correct though it was.

Comment: @AndrewBarber Thanks. Yeah I agree. I wasn't diplomatic. The next time I'll try to act as so. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks! To be clear for others (I deleted the comment), I wouldn't call the comment "rude"; just abrupt. And since most of my activity on the site these days involves mod stuff, I definitely know how easy it is to be abrupt with things!