# When someone asks for a recommendation instead of a question, where should I tell them to post their question? Yahoo answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, scope, needs-more-focus, recommendation-questions

Many times I have seen questions that are more like

> "Which language should I use for ..." and "Can anyone recommend..."

than

> "I am having a problem this this chunk of code in my file and I need some help..."

I flag these questions, but is there a place where I can direct them to ask these chatty questions? My first thought is Yahoo answers or some kind of blog. Where should I tell them to post these types of questions that are not appropriate for stack overflow?

Comment: You can tell them to look for other resources than Stack Exchange (modulo [softwarerecs.se] if applicable). I would personally refrain from recommending Yahoo Answers, as it may look like you're mocking the questioner instead of helping them.

Comment: I always recommend Yahoo! Answers, along with Quora and specially 4Chan's /b/ channel. You can literally ask **ANYTHING** in those sites and no one will ever give you trouble for being off-topic! (just kidding... I agree with Servy's answer).

Comment: @Renan Wait... comparing Quora and `/b/`...?! Quora does moderate to some extent (I *guess*).

Comment: @CamiloMartin: Quora's just a creepier version of /b/.  Why not?

Comment: @Renan Amazon Askville?

Comment: @tmyklebu What? To me Quora looks much more family-oriented than `/b/`. And a little bit more polished. `/b/` is where you go to see clever sociopathic misantropes at work and leisure.

Comment: I think a lot of people who ask these sorts of questions would be well-received on /r/learnprogramming.

Comment: [Yahoo Answers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Answers) closed down in 2021.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you would like to recommend another site for questions that are off topic you're certainly welcome to.  You are not *obligated* to suggest another site when informing someone that their question is off topic for the site that it *is* on.

You should of course only recommend site that you personally feel comfortable directing the user to; you should be confident both that the site you are suggesting is capable of helping the user and that the question would be welcome on that site.

Comment: This. Sometimes a person seems to think, "Well; if they are saying my question's not on-topic here, they are responsible to tell me where it is on-topic."

Comment: Thank you @Servy for clarifying that for me.

Comment: @Andrew Barber I agree with you, the off topic user should learn to research on their own. I will post a link if I know that some great piece of documentation exists. I just wasn't clear of the too broad/off topic etiquette besides flagging. Thank you for clarifying that for me!

Comment: @AndrewBarber So you're saying we use the "you don't have to go home, but you can't stay here" philosophy?

Comment: @corsiKa You're *welcome* to do so, if you wish, just as you're welcome to suggest an alternative.  All we're saying is that you are not *obligated* to tell them where they can go, not that you *cannot*.

Comment: @corsiKa What Servy said. I was meaning just to emphasize the (false) belief of obligation. One is still welcome to do so if they wish.

Comment: I like Servy's emphasis. It certainly is nicer if you can provide an off-topic questioner with an on-target pointer. It's like the difference Santa Clause in Miracle on 34th street brought to Macy's. You don't *have* to. But it's nice if you do. I'll assert that it creates value in terms of good-will for StackExchange.

Answer (score 14):

I couldn't agree more with Servy and Andrew Barber. It is not your responsibility to direct people who ask off-topic questions elsewhere. Just because we turn away a question does not mean that we are obligated to find it a new home.

But if you want to provide them with a helpful hint, my suggestion is to refer to them to the following question, from our community-curated [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) here on Meta: [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254567/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow)

Not only will this provide them with *a lot* more information than you can ever fit in a comment, it also saves you a lot of typing. Oh, and it frees you from the burden of *personally* recommending a particular place. It takes a considerable amount of effort to research and decide on an appropriate place to ask a question, as evidenced by the people who persist in asking off-topic questions here without reading through our explicit guidelines in the Help Center and the new user Tour.

(Also, feel free to update the information in the linked FAQ entry with additional resources, if/as you discover them.)

Comment: Much prefer this answer to Servy's.  Yes, these questions don't belong on SO, but if the goal of SO is to improve programming everywhere, and if the questions exist, getting them answered (whether on SO or not) serves that goal.

Comment: Our goal is not to "improve programming everywhere", nor is it to educate programers. Our goal is to build a comprehensive resources of answers to specific programming problems. This goal is clearly presented in the [new user Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). As I tried to make clear in my answer, you are **not** obligated to find a place for people to ask questions that are off-topic here. This is not a self-help site, it is a Q&A site. We have a very specific, targeted goal.

Comment: It isn't to educate programmers? Why do people ask questions if not to learn? The goal is to create a compete set of questions and answers. Is that not motivated by the idea that things are generally better when more people know more things? Yes, that is not explicitly said, but that's why I use SO. Why do you answer questions? Internet points?

Comment: The goal of individuals is not the same as the goal of the site. If our goal was simply to educate, we would be teaching programming. We can't do that with our format. Our goal is more nuanced than that.