# How do we handle ethical/legal questions?

Tags: support, flags

Today I came across a (now deleted- will link it here if I can find the link) question which asked about the legality of using distributing Microsoft libraries (DLLs) with their programs.

This type of question is asked a couple of times a week (so not a *major* problem), and perhaps should be flagged using the `Primarily Opinion Based` flag:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

..as opinions differ quite widely on ethical questions.

For ethical/legal questions, is flagging as `Primarily Opinion Based` the correct flag? If not, what flag should be used?

I thought there was a dedicated flag for this type of thing, but obviously not.

Comment: Questions about software *licensing* (the legal part of this) are off-topic here. Ethics is opinion based, as you say.

Comment: The example at the start of this question is not a good example of an *ethical* question. It is asking about the *legality* of distributing DLLs.

Comment: Well, the [legal] tag on SO says "Questions about licensing should be asked on Programmers.SE. If you’re using this tag here, your question is probably not appropriate for Stack Overflow."  Don't know how accurate that is or not, since it only takes three people to approve the tag, but there you have it.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables According to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic software licensing is explicitly on-topic at Programmers. Not sure if that includes using *other* people's licensing, but you'ld have a shot.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET -- good to know!

Comment: @gnat Not a duplicate as that question asks *where do we go* when mine asks simply *how do we flag*.

Comment: Should be a dupe of https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254567/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-dont-fit-or-are-off-topic-for-stack-overflow, not the current one. The current one is a dupe of those and has no answer, so is a useless dupe target. I can't change the targets myself as I only have a gold badge in discussion, not support.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Questions about legal, and ethical, concerns should be closed as off-topic (or, perhaps, 'opinion-based'), they're not relevant to Stack Overflow since they are about the application of an ethical, or legal, framework: neither of which is a programming question.

Questions related to ethics within the community of Stack Overflow could be on-topic here at Meta, or on [Meta.se] depending on the scope of the problem/question, but that would be unique to those questions about this site. Similarly, I could imagine that asking questions, here on Meta, about the legality of use of Stack Overflow, could be on-topic, depending on the precise question.

Otherwise, given that we are (I imagine, mostly) not lawyers, it would seem presumptive, and foolish, of us to advise anyone as regards the law, and the application of the law, for any jurisdiction for which we are not qualified to practice law.