# Not really sure what made my question to be closed automatically

Tags: support, specific-question, scope, closed-questions

For my recent question,

*[Linux search for a string in a given set of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65265265/linux-search-for-a-string-in-a-given-set-of-files)*

It was automatically closed with the comment 'don’t allow questions about general computing hardware and software on Stack Overflow'. I don't quite get what exactly in my question is linked to 'general computing hardware and software'. Could you please elaborate? My question is more on Linux commands [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)) and [grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep).

Also, it says "This question does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines. It is not currently accepting answers". I am not sure again what it meant by 'not accepting answers'. I've accepted answers to all my previous questions. I just received one answer and it is not really giving the desired output, so I've added a comment asking accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If your question was not well received, read this before you post your next question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254262/if-your-question-was-not-well-received-read-this-before-you-post-your-next-ques)

Comment: Relevant: [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254567/11682469)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No question is ever closed "automatically". There are always actual humans behind it, who have reviewed your question and determined that it does not meet [our site requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Such questions are closed, which means that they do not accept answers. We don't want people answering off-topic or unsuitable questions.

Stack Overflow only accepts questions about programming.  Basic usage of Linux user-mode commands, like "find" and "grep", is not programming.

You can look into asking such questions on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: noted that Stack Overflow only accepts questions about programming. Will post my question in other communities.

Comment: @Lokesh When you first visited the site and signed in, you should have been presented with information about our scope. How could you not have known that the site was for programming questions? Can you tell us how we might have made this more obvious, to prevent others from being confused in the future?

Comment: I might have overlooked it (if too much content about the scope) or never gave it a thought on that there are multiple sites depending on the type of questions i.e. programming oriented or others. May be if possible, just before allowing to post the question, depending on the keywords in title (for instance linux or unix) or body (for instance find, grep or standard shell commands in code blocks), a pop-up can be thrown suggesting if the question should be targeted to most relevant site and then link back to "scope" page should give an opportunity to the OP to think before posting.

Comment: @Lokesh but you overlooked the *first* popup, you said it yourself...... Why would a second one be less ignored than the first?

Comment: @Patrice, when I clicked on 'Ask Question', it straight away shows the 'Ask a public question' page with 'Title', 'Body' and 'Tags'. The right side of this page contains few details like 'Draft your question' and 'Have a non-programming question?' which is probably the one that I missed. Once the details of the question are entered, 'Review your question' and then Posting it. If posting questions on sfo is new to me, then there is nothing stopping me to post a question if I missed out to read those details on right hand side of the page. Hence a pop-up would help is what I thought.