# Is it OK to recommend new users to ask their question elsewhere?

Tags: discussion, scope

Sometimes when I leave a comment along with a *needs more focus* CV on a (more or less) homework question like

> There are many ways you can do this. What's your attempt? Where are you unsatisfied / stuck with it? Show your code please! Otherwise we cannot help in improving / fixing it.

OP answers in a comment that they haven't made any attempt, and they need basic help in how to approach the problem.
I am answering in another comment that Stack Overflow isn't the site to ask for such general help, and also provided a link to [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

OP almost always complains, and then asks in comments:

> > Where can I ask such question here?

And I tell them they might try at reddit, quora, geeksforgeeks, whatever.
But wait, I am not even sure if these sites might be a place to ask such question successfully. The only thing I almost certainly know is, that there's no Stack Exchange site I know, which is suitable for those kind of general questions.

Or am I wrong with the latter? Was my recommendation OK?

---

<sub>For those who are interested in the concrete case, here's a link to [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66623517/how-to-replace-different-strings-with-the-same-string-in-several-files-using-not), but mine here is about the general case, which can be found frequently with all language tags.</sub>

Comment: I think if you change the wording ever so slightly you'll probably be "fine". Instead of "try" you could say "You might be able to ask on... but check the site's own policies first." Just like *we* get annoyed/frustrated with people being referred to [so] for off topic questions (I saw a LTT video suggest SO (in passing) for Windows trouble shooting yesterday >_< ), I am sure those communities do too.

Comment: @Larnu Would you be so kind, and write your proposal for a better (more conservative) wording in an answer? There's also a parallel I see, when recommending other Stack Exchange sites (e.g. SE Code Review), and I believe it would be nice to have a community backed policy about doing so.

Comment: When I'm not on my phone, sure. Writing more than an answer on a small screen is often not a great experience. :)

Comment: did you consider replying with a link to this meta FAQ: [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254567/839601)

Comment: @gnat THX. That's more or less of what I am looking for. Maybe, even a dupe for my question here (which isn't really surprising, as you proposed it ;-) )

Comment: "they barely need" means "they almost don't need" but you don't seem to mean that. "basically"? (Or just, need help with basics of how to"?) PS Don't suggest another site unless you say, read the help at the other site & make sure their post is on-topic there, or they will not check, and probably won't check even if you do.