# "I am new to X, therefore I don't need to try anything"

Tags: discussion, new-users

I don't use Stack Overflow very much. Every so often I will come on and try to answer some of the questions. Something that annoys me is the statement,

> I am new to X (language, technique, or field).

I have been seeing this a fair amount and it usually is followed by something along the lines of,

- "I can't do this",
- "This doesn't work", or
- "How do I do this?"

with no real proof of prior effort.

I usually try to point people towards Matt Gemmell's brilliant article [WhatHaveYouTried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

**Are there other things that users can do to try and teach new people to come to Stack Oveflow with a little more prior work?**

Down voting usually doesn't work in this case because they are often a 1 rep user. On top of this, we don't necessarily want to discourage people from using the website to ask their questions.

Comment: There exist questions that we absolutely do want to discourage from being asked on SO.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I find this sort of thing mildly annoying too. Also, keep in mind that [main] is very much **not a forum**. It's a Question and Answer site that was very much designed to be the exact opposite of a forum, an "**Anti-Forum**". See [Shog's answer here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254696/456814).

Comment: What have you tried to sort the problem out?  :D

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Very good :) , Well what I have so far is answering there question and also pointing them to some resources they could have used and also to that WhatHaveYouTried site.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg as a result of [the current culture here on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251487/456814), I think we're already doing a pretty good job of discouraging a great many type of question from being asked around here. Not to agree or disagree with any point, just adding an anecdotal observation, from my point of view.

Comment: About the "WhatHaveYouTried site", I was reading somewhere around here that leaving comments saying to go read that on questions was considered not appropriate anymore. I don't remember where that discussion was though...

Comment: Yes, I was mostly teasing, as I think you recognized — but you did set yourself up with "I'm new to SO" (sort of).  I not infrequently simply remove the apologia from the question if I'm editing it anyway for something else (like 'i ⟶ I', etc).  If the question can't stand on its own without it, it wasn't a very good question in the first place.  There's a limit to what you can or should do.  If the question interests you, work to improve it.  If not, leave it; you're not obliged to do anything with it.  If you think it needs downvoting, do so; there are those FGITW who think that is crucial.

Comment: The instructions are given to every new user who first posts a question. I haven't seen any correlation between being new to something and some self-entitled notion that they don't need to have tried anything, except when the asker themselves snaps back to that effect. In fact, if anything, if I haven't tried anything it's because I'm completely lost and have no idea what I'm supposed to try (although I'd probably mention that in that case).

Comment: @Cupcake That is interesting, I sort of get that though, I like to post it because its a really good article for them to read but it obviously doesn't contribute to the question itself. I guess i will stop doing so now.

Comment: `Down voting usually doesn't work in this case because they are often a 1 rep user.` On the contrary - getting such users question-banned is sometimes the correct course of action, and downvotes are the mechanism to accomplish that.

Comment: Also, people get *really* uptight about seeing the post score go down, even if (especially if) their rep doesn't.

Comment: @roippi, I agree, but also I know that if I was a new user and got bombarded with down-votes I probably wouldn't come back. I didn't write awful first questions but they also were not amazing. I was pointed to the Matt Gammell thing and my questions instantly got better (in combination with reading site rules). I guess this is why the editing of users questions is a good thing.

Comment: Related?: [What is the proper way to approach SO as someone totally new to programming?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/456814).

Comment: @Cupcake: What you've probably heard about "what have you tried" is me complaining that the phrase has turned Stack Overflow from a programming resource into a troubleshooting site.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Your comment made me think about the difference between programming resource and troubleshooting site. Basically questions can not only be too broad, they can also be too specific (and uninteresting). This isn't however a reason to close them currently, isn't it?

Comment: @roippi, and yet they keep coming. We need new [mechanisms](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no).

Comment: @Trilarion: Troubleshooting questions don't bother me all that much, if they contain [all of these things](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/102937).

Comment: I often attempt to guide such people to find the answer.  Unfortunately, very often someone will come along and post an answer which does their homework for them.  (I always downvote such answers, but it seems to do little good, even when I've warned that I will in the comments.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*contra* Tim Post, almost every time I see the phrase "I am new to *X*" in a question,  the question is poor quality, worthy of down votes and closure.

Examining your "where is the coffee analogue" a little more closely illuminates why. In the social situations where we would excuse ourselves like that, are we not say "this is a trivial question, but there is no way to know its answer without troubling you"? But we don't want trivial questions here, and there are no questions here that *only* the SO community can answer. Trivial questions are *not useful* (to others, what used to be closed as *too localised*, but worthy of a down-vote) or have easy to find answers (and thus indicate a *lack of research*, also a reason to down-vote).

Almost every time I see this kind of excuse on SO, it is clear that the poster is actually new to programming in general. They do not know what features of code are important for understanding why it might not work, so their problem description focuses on irrelevant details (such as what their entire program is meant to achieve), and the question is typically a code dump rather than a small self-contained snippet. They do not know how to debug programs or read a stack trace,  so there is rarely any indication of useful debugging having been done, or what it uncovered ("I've been working on this for hours" is a common and useless statement). They do not know how to specify a program, so there is rarely a clear description of what the program is meant to do.  So there is often a reason to close the question as *off topic* for not providing adequate debugging information. In some cases, answering the question properly would require explaining so much about basic concepts about which the asker is confused that the question is *too broad*.

Answer (score 11):

It's human nature to excuse one's self in advance of asking others for their time - especially for something one feels they should be able to do themselves. Have you ever started a job and asked someone:

> I'm sorry, I'm new here - where do we keep the extra coffee?

... or something similar? It's a natural expression and doesn't always mean everything else that follows is going to be awful. It's a way of saying *"I'm sorry for taking what seems an unnecessary three seconds from your life because I feel like I should know this but I'm stuck"* without the added drama.

In the programming world, this is often indicative of simply not knowing what they should have searched for. They needed to be searching for 'string method' but went looking for 'word function' instead.

Where this breaks down is where folks use it as a *repeated* excuse.

***I don't mind the occasional question that really only asks for a nudge in the right direction as long as the pattern of asking them doesn't become pathological.***

I've been at Stack Exchange for over a year and a half. If I ask Joel where the coffee is at this point, things are going to get real very quickly. Just remember, knowing what to try often means knowing *what to search for* - so try and give folks a chance or two before classifying them as lazy.

Answer (score 7):

The term `I am new to X` is in my mind nothing but unnecessary fluff and should not matter when asking a question. Therefore, it should either be removed or ignored.

If the user presents a clear answerable problem, the askers level of competence should be assumed to be in line with the question. I.e. :

> "I'm trying to implement FizzBuzz, but I keep getting a Division by Zero error. [code sample 1]. I tried [code sample 2] but that doesn't even compile. How can I solve this?"

EDIT: Example stolen from [S.L Barth's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/812149/s-l-barth) [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254922/i-am-new-to-x-therefore-i-dont-need-to-try-anything/267461?noredirect=1#comment71077_267461).

Should be answered with an answer on an extremely basic level, but this does not mean that all easy questions have easy answers. One should try to explain clearly and to the askers level (to an extent).

Comment: I'd like to see a different example. This example is a question that shows zero effort and deserves a downvote. A better beginner's question would show some effort ("I looked in 'C# for beginners' but...").

Comment: @S.L.Barth Perhaps a question regarding a certain example in a tutorial, book or some basic tasks that can be hard to wrap your head around at first?

Comment: If I see a question like that in the example, I wish I could downvote it more than once.

Comment: A question regarding a book or tutorial, or some basic task, would be great. A possible example of a basic task: "I'm trying to implement FizzBuzz, but I keep getting a Division by Zero error. [code sample 1]. I tried [code sample 2] but that doesn't even compile. How can I solve this?"

Comment: @S.L.Barth Edited answer with your provided example.