# Delay Display of Low-Quality questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, questions, low-quality-posts

As I've [just learned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253351/allow-users-to-optionally-filter-out-low-quality-questions) we have a machine score questions by their quality.

We could use this to delay display of questions, lower quality leading to a longer wait.

The idea behind this is to make it "cheaper" (in terms of time until the questioner has an answer) to do your own research than to dump the question here.

This should discourage users to just dump their no-thought questions here while still allowing everybody to ask any question they can ask today and have them seem by all the experts.

So if you have a serious question on which you have done your research and you post a good question -> great, you'll get a quick (instant) display and quick answers.

But if you ask a low quality question it gets delayed so the personal reward system gets broken.

Of course after an edit this has to be recalculated to encourage enhancement of quality.

#### Who is going to be hit by this

1. Beginners that just don't know how to ask properly yet.
   They will get their answer (a bit delayed though) and be able to learn from the experience and improve so the next question they ask gets an earlier answer.
2. "Gimme Code" or otherwise lazy people who think we are here to use Google for them
   They want their answer quickly and if they get it quicker somewhere else (e.G. Google) they won't come back.

#### Comparable approaches

[This request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252769/probationary-period-for-questions-to-be-answered-to-encourage-better-questions-w) is somewhat similar to this one but aims at improving the questions that are already there. My Request aims at reducing the number of low-quality questions asked in the first place.

The existing "On Hold" concept isn't going to solve this problem, as it kicks in too late. When the question gets closed it often already has an answer thus for the "Gimme Code" part of questioners (especially the anonymous posters) it doesn't matter at all.

Comment: This might have been suggested somewhere else on Meta already, for example, maybe in [More effective closing / downvoting of junk questions to help with the signal-noise ratio?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no).

Comment: @Cupcake thats possible. After reading through the linked question I found this one: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252769/probationary-period-for-questions-to-be-answered-to-encourage-better-questions-w which is close to my request but aims at a different goal. Robert there wants the questions that are already there to improve, I want to reduce the incentive of asking bad questions in the first place.

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer, I've [suggested](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253489/2507539) both Machine Learning and question delays (a form of probation) in the question Cupcake has already linked to.

Comment: Seems a bit like hellbanning, which the SE folks have said they don't want to do.

Comment: @3524344 It shouldn't seem like that at all! Hellbanning causes you to be inable to do anything at all (for a period of time). Which this doesn't aim to! You CAN still ask questions (and of course can still answer anything instantly) its just that this "post question, let other people think" mentality stops being catered to.

Comment: @Angelo: That's not what hellbanning is. Hellbanning is hiding a user's content from everyone except themselves. More here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93857

Comment: @3524344 Ah, thanks! But still this is not like it as Hellbanning is transparent to the asker (he doesn't notice being hellbanned) while this system is meant as being obvious. When the question gets posted there should be a line beneath it (like the "on hold" box) saying "This question will appear on the main site in 24 hours" or something.

Comment: Delaying display of poor-quality questions of impatient an lazy users might lead to the problem that they are asking their crap question multiple times (with different titles maybe);

Comment: @aschipfl Which just causes them to wait ever longer before they receive an answer. The goal here is to annoy such people away or educate them enough that they can improve.

Comment: I agree, @AngeloFuchs, but I fear the amount of poor questions might not be reduced but even increased by introducing a delay;

Comment: @aschipfl I can see that. My experience with other such situations on regular forums on the Internet is different. Such people go wherever its easiest, so making it inconvenient is helping in such cases (they then bother other people unfortunately).