# This is why not answering duplicates is more helpful than spoon feeding!

Tags: discussion, feature-request

### This is the desired outcome of marking things as duplicates.<sup>1</sup>

[This feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252769/probationary-period-for-questions-to-be-answered-to-encourage-better-questions-w) needs to be reconsidered, because there are extremely few questions that have not been asked at this point, especially about extremely common `Exception` messages.

[image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37125028/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-dependencies-between-two-eclipse-projects]

> Spoon feeding is bad for the person you are feeding, it is bad for you
> and it is bad for everyone in the entire industry. No other
> professional field would tolerate spoon feeding peers because it
> dilutes the talent/knowledge pool and drives the quality of peers down
> and the quality of the entire industry suffers.

1 <sub>I omitted the post to avoid the meta effect on the question.</sub>

Comment: Yes, yes it is. Shame this attitude by posters is so vanishingly rare.

Comment: Thank god the site doesn't reward people for just spoon feeding others instead of actually helping them.

Comment: > [The biggest outstanding issue with preventing answers to duplicate questions is finding the right target.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564/remove-the-incentive-for-fgitw-to-answer-well-known-dupes/316682#316682)

Comment: @Shog9 - that is why [I proposed a grace period for submitting answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252769/probationary-period-for-questions-to-be-answered-to-encourage-better-questions-w) so that we can have time to find the duplicate, this needs to be reconsidered!

Comment: Wouldn't the feature request you are referring to encourage people to ask questions more quickly so that they can get past the delay to get an answer faster? I am not sure about you but if I am looking for an answer and know there is a built in delay that won't cause me to be less likely to ask that question while I continue my research.

Comment: I sympathize with the sentiment, but this seems like kind of a lost battle - against the phenomenon, and/or against the SE powers that be that won't do anything despite generations of Meta people rambling about it. For peace of mind, I recommend the libertarian view - if stupid people ask obvious dupes on SO, and other people are stupid enough to answer them, let them. It is not our place to interfere and impose artificial restrictions. And to be fair, the place is still remarkably bearable despite it

Comment: it dilutes the work of previous contributors and those answering the dupes as well as creating a workforce that nobody that can find the answers themselves and figure things out wants to work with. If you want *coding* to be a minimum wage job, then keep answering these people, I will be retired by the time the dilution hits maximum entropy hopefully.

Comment: I agree (well, partly. I don't think it's going to dilute the field as a whole - the industry is always going to need bright people.) But as said, it seems like people in charge are happy about the way it currently is. Talking about it on Meta has had no measurable effect for the past five years.

Comment: well it is **not** making the internet a better place in the long run, that is for sure. It is harming the internet in the long run.

Comment: I don't understand why your question has four "unclear what you're asking" close votes. We may or may not agree with you, but it's pretty clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Fréd because meta has a robo-reviewer problem. It was close-voted  even after the clarifying text was added, and the reviewers didn't read the updated question, and that is not the first time today.

Comment: @CodeCaster I invite you to look at the first revision of this question. That's what it looked like when I voted to close it. If you see a question in there maybe you can enlighten me as to what it was exactly. I noticed the edits that turned what was originally nothing more than a rant into an actual question but the edits also made it a duplicate of the original feature request, *so still worthy of being closed.* As a general rule, I don't retract close votes because an edit changed the reason for closure.

Comment: @Louis I still need to learn how to read the [timeline](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/322908/timeline). However, all reviews seem to have taken place _after_ the edit that added the "question".

Answer (score 9):

> there are extremely few questions that have not been asked at this point

And most answers that are posted to such questions are ["try this"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298804/what-should-a-minimal-answer-contain) or other utter garbage, often incorrect, incomplete and/or insecure, and even more often copied from Googling the question title and copy-pasting some code together from the first resulting Stack Overflow post, omitting the explanation provided there as to not be accused of plagiarism.

The askers of such questions just want help, and that's understandable. The posters of answers as described above also often don't mean any harm, they just want to help the OP to their best knowledge - and gain some imaginary Internet points in the meantime.

What those users simply don't understand, is that they're not helping the site and the web as a whole, and just so often neither the OP as well, as the code they post is of questionable quality. All active, knowledgeable users together don't have the manpower to review every question and answer, and so incorrect information and insecure answers stay on the site without being moderated.

I fully agree with putting "potentially risky" questions on hold by default, as to prevent "guess-answers" and help the askers *find*, not *give*, the answer they so desperately need, by fleshing out using comments what they actually are asking for.

Comment: that quote is taken out of context, *`, especially about extremely common Exception messages"*, just to make sure people do not vote against that quote, it is not the issue.

Comment: @Jarrod yeah it's quoted a bit selectively on purpose. Do you want me to add the condition from the question?

Comment: No I just wanted to make sure people did not down vote based on that quote alone.