# Tell the financial controllers of Stack Exchange to put money into keeping the current user base happy

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete, moderator-abilities

### We're Unhappy

This question has brought out many issues on the site that have been discussed and just are not being addressed.

[Declaring a Review strike until efficiency improvements are implemented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385023/declaring-a-review-strike-until-efficiency-improvements-are-implemented)

In [one answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385168/3956566) the questioner is referred to as throwing a tantrum.

The fact someone is suggesting a review strike and the post is upvoted is indicative that people are burnt out. They face a close queue that they do not have the tools to clear. They do not have the tools to curate the site. To remove low quality content.

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385154/3956566) echoes the futility of even coordinated efforts to reduce the queue.

In some comments under [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385141/3956566), people are voicing thoughts that the network somehow plays with the number of posts in the queues to make them look smaller.

These are symptoms of a ailing community. This type of suspicion is borne from people feeling disenfranchised within the site. Feeling fobbed off.  It's a real problem that needs to be addressed.

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/385143/3956566) goes into the statistics of the number of requests there's been to alleviate review queues. We feel ignored.

The success of the network rides on the success of ***this*** site. The people bank rolling this network need to realise they may well be stuffing up their investment. The internet changes rapidly and it will not take too many more iterations for the site to die. I haven't got statistics, but we have lost a lot of high rep, regular users. Without people providing quality content, the site will die. Too much is resting on the past success of Stack Overflow.

There was fear about user attrition rates, but we need to retain our long term contributors as well.

Reinventing the UX to assist people asking questions or posting for the first time will improve (to a degree) the quality of the site's posts. However, there's limitations to how foolproof any website or application can be. In the meantime we still need to clean up the site and be able to keep it clean.

### Tell the executives what we want. TLDR

Every time we ask for help we are given a stock answer. "We are focusing on a, b, c... then we will get to x, y, z". This is why the employees are being met with hostility on the site. The long term user base feels like they're the lowest priority. Read the writing on the wall. ***Take this (the answers) to the executives.***

Tell the financial controllers of Stack Exchange to put money into keeping the current user base happy. Not with contests and swag, with the tools to curate the site.

***We don't want much, some back end work to make reviewing, closing and deleting easier.***

Comment: possibly related: [Why we initiated the latest round of design changes and the role of meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/314923/165773), "... talking about concerns related to content quality (which naturally appears to be primary focus of the site "core group"). This may sound a bit paradoxical but I think the best way here would be to figure _why_ you would need to address these concerns and serve this group..."

Answer (score 21):

#### Reality:

The problem is the people that can provide the support for *closing and deleting easier* have decided that *closing and deleting* is bad for business. They do **not** want questions closed or deleted. Closed questions piss people off and pissed off people do not come back to look at more ads. Deleted questions can not be monetized. They want people engaged asking questions, period. Fullstop. You will never get *help* with anything that reduces eyeballs.

Of course this is never *directly* stated, but is implicitly implied with the deletion of that *tongue in cheek* answer about *How much effort is expected?* being deleted with the comment *this is not what we want to be telling people* from the moderator that deleted it.

Which was then switched up and spun to, well it was just too much *hyperbole*, which was then switched up to undeleting it and neutering the language to the point of irrelevance.

Face it, they are not interested in *quality* or *moderation* like we ***were*** doing, they want people posting as much as possible as quickly as possible. If you need official proof it is right there on the *Tour* page!

> With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed
>   answers ***to every question*** about programming.

***Every question***, means **every question**; just let that sink in before you read any further or make any comments about *community standards/quality*.

#### Contempt:

The deafening **silence** on any kind of minor nod to the people that have been around for 10 years feeding and grooming the site after the Hanlon blog post is just too loud to ignore anymore. Instead, they just double down on all the attacks on the *veteran* community not being *welcoming* enough instead of doing anything to support us. Adding that *New Contributor* tag/badge was just a poke in the eye to everyone that moderated actively.

I mean how is volunteering and providing hundreds if not thousands of man hours of free work to total strangers not ultimate sign of being **welcoming**?

That free volunteer work is ultimately benefiting a **for profit** organization that flogs you with scorpions because a handful of people tweet that their feelings are hurt when they are asked to meet some basic minimal community guidelines.

**To be clear:** I am part of a *protected minority* commonly discriminated against as well, that the Hanlon blog post accused all the community contributors of being implicitly biased against. The fact that they doubled and tripled down on that blog post instead of retracting or at least posting something equally as strong language supporting the community and what it has done is and should be extremely insulting to anyone that has ever taken the time to answer a question, vote on a question or answer, edit a question or answer or comment asking for more information to provide free help.

> That is it in a nutshell, you can see [what I have to say about a very
>   simple fix to the site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252769/probationary-period-for-questions-to-be-answered-to-encourage-better-questions-w) in the past as the user formally known as
>   `user177800` from over 5 years ago!

If they had done something like this even 3 years ago, there would be plenty of people willing to keep moderating the site and you would not have had this flood of posts about people quitting. Even if they did this today, it would be too late. Instead they did [Documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334638/documentation-is-on-its-way-to-becoming-the-next-w3schools) and that was time well spent, not, ended just like my Cassandra prediction.

I predict that the flood of crap on the site generates more income than the long tail views of the quality content.

#### Thought Experiment:

In the short term a view on a off-topic crap question pays them the exact same money as a view on a quality question/answer, even if the question never gets answered!

What about the long term, long tail revenue? Well that is easy to calculate this many years into the site's existence.

Most likely the calculation shows that a constant flood of off-topic *give me teh codez* questions that people click on and might or might not answer, make more income **right now** than a few good questions that **might** make some long tail income in the future.

I can imagine some meeting that went like:

> Old questions generate `X$` on average over `T amount of time` and
>   that content is kind of static now as every *good*/on topic question
>   that could be asked is probably been asked so our income is fixed per
>   time period, but, our data shows that a flood of crap questions
>   generates more income right now. Bring on the unwelcoming campaign to
>   get people to welcome as much new posts as possible, quality be
>   damned. Profit!

<sub>This account will be deleted in near future, when that happens I have nothing more to say on the self inflicted entropy of the site anymore.</sub>

Comment: Pretty much sums it up. We can only draw these conclusions based on the fact it is continually ignored. I also suspected they just wanted the traffic. Imagine what the site would look like if we could clear the garbage off it quickly and decent questions were visible to the horizon? What, wouldn't there be enough advertising revenue if 90% of the new posts were continually removed?

Comment: Speaking as a pretty quality-focused, tooling-focused user, I find the conclusion drawn here from the deletion/editing of the research answer to be very tenuous. You see, I thought that answer was awful, and I was glad when the old hyperbole got the axe. That doesn't prove anything about SE's innermost motivations, of course, except that they aren't *necessarily* nefarious at all: the stated rationale may well be the real rationale.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - which rational? the justification/reason for just deleting it changed multiple times? The only one that is probably true is the first one. Which is, we do not want to be telling people that there is anything expected of them before asking a question.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson either that, or they thought (i'm inclined to agree) that the hyperbolic wording did not contribute to people actually listening and using the site better as a result.