# Close-votes review queue should have expiration

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, closed-questions

The review queue shows 9.9k questions dating back 20 months. Now, on other sites that review queue is fully managed, but on StackOverflow.com the volume is too great so there are way too many questions suggested to be closed there.

If something doesn't get reviewed for over 1-3 months, it needs to come off the review queue, to help improve the possibility of 'accomplishment feedback'.

I think that 1 month would be a good limit.

[image]

Comment: Agreeing on the huge queue (I just went through 20-or so posts but it didn't make a visible dent), but which direction would you like to see these posts moved? "Automatically closed", or leaving them open? Both seem ... less *tidy* ideas.

Comment: 72 hours is a pretty good limit.  It will have been buried under *25,000* questions by then.

Comment: @Jongware, Leaving them open, Automatic closure would be risky, because only 1 close vote would close the question. Leaving them open is status quo, and an appropriate one at that, because it is not worth your time or mine to review anything that hasn't had close votes since 2012. :)

Comment: @Hans, Other sites don't need this limit at all. I'm certainly open to limiting to 72 hours. I just suggested limit of 1 month because that's obviously not going to have any 'unintended consequences'.

Comment: Closed questions are automatically purged after a while. Are open, unanswered questions too? (I think they are not.) So basically, what you are suggesting is shortening the *visible* list of open questions.

Comment: This is the meta site for SO, can't worry about other sites.

Comment: @Jongware, Yes. Because we will never review 10k questions, but the time may come when we are on top of close votes, but we'll never know how well we are doing so long as 2012 data is in the counter.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the real problem..  HOW did it get this way?  It seems there is an abundance of two types of questions; [poorly worded, vague or minimal content questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825268/how-to-make-the-blue-border-on-the-image-disappears-in-ie) and [looking for reference material questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217760/where-can-i-get-mix-09-slides-from).  I'm not sure how to solve the abundance of these questions, but trying to fix the current close voted questions seems like we'd be solving a symptom.

Comment: @Erik, Yes, this does not solve the problem. However, lets assume we eventually get the incoming close votes to a manageable level. This counter will still say 9-10k, forever. BUT, if they accept my feature request, then once we solve the problem, the counter will show it. (within a month) Besides, it just 'makes sense' to have a 1 month time limit (at most), system-wide, and I think it has a low chance of unwanted side-effects.

Comment: @ErikPhilips: Close voting such questions is only one part of solving the symptom: they should also get down voted, so as to get their authors question banned.

Comment: I think the problem is the number of people who have access to the moderator tools is not correctly proportional to the number of either users or questions (i'm not sure which really).

Comment: @Denis, Erik, Discussing how we got 10k is off subject, in fact discussing how to resolve the problem is also off subject. This thread should be about whether it is appropriate to archive or hide all the stuff over 1 month old. I believe this is a legit request because it very well compliments the solution to that problem. I don't mind a little bit of that, but lets keep it limited. (that's my opinion)

Comment: Ahh, but sometimes discusing the source of the problem can produce a better solution which can sometimes fix the symptom as well.  That is what comments are for!

Comment: Hah, complaining about the close vote queue being 10k questions deep? It's not that long ago that this was 95k: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208220/close-votes-review-im-going-on-a-strike . Have you seen Shog9's proposals for what they're working on regarding this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions ?