# Make SO a better place for good!

Tags: discussion

I saw one of the top users of SO, BalusC's [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc). It read:

> I'm not that active here anymore as I'd like to be. I'll answer
>   OmniFaces-related questions though and likely also a really
>   interesting JSF-related question which is not been answered before.
>   The remainder only if it has a bounty. Yes, for that YOU need to earn
>   reputation first. You deserve what you give.
>
> But remember: if the question in question needs severe editing, or got
>   a bad (suggested) edit, I am not going to fix and answer it anymore.
>   Both Stack Exchange as company and Stack Overflow as community namely
>   doesn't seem to bother about the quality of the posts anymore lately.
>   I was mentally absent for a couple of months and came back in JSF tag
>   only to find a huge mess of low quality questions with a doubled up
>   unanswered rate. "You deserve what you give" also applies to the
>   company and community here.
>
> If you want to give yourself (and Stack Overflow) a chance, here are
>   some hints:
>
> - [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)
> - [Information to provide when asking JSF questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info)
>
> Things which scare me are:
>
> - Bad titles (don't use tags and subjective-/argumentativeness in titles)
> - Irrelevant tags (is it a Java or JSF or JPA or CSS or JS problem?)
> - Disrespectful punctuation and spelling (I don't care about grammar tho)
> - Formatting non-code as code ("JSF" and "PrimeFaces" are NOT code)
> - Irrelevant code in snippets (is that style attribute absolutely relevant?)
> - Unreadable code (use English variable names and love indentation)
>
> **Note:** I have a full time job as co-founder and main frontend developer and therefore I am not available for off-site consultancy,
>   so please don't try to contact me directly about that as well.
>   Everything will end up as junk. Just use Stack Overflow the way it
>   deserves and you'll eventually deserve it.

It shows in what direction SO is heading to.

We, should really take some steps to improve the SO and bring back it to its glorious past.

After reading that, I myself felt, whether am I doing it right to contribute to SO?

Really we should take time to fix this issue. Stack Overflow as a company with large number of users (*many of them just under 100 reps*) and boastful statistics (*of which only some questions and answers are really genuine and helpful*) can bring profit, but it is definitely bad for the community.

One, user has almost stopped contributing, then another will and so on..

So, as said in the title,

> Do something to save SO for good!!!

### My Suggestions:

- "Questions that may already have your answer", algorithm must be made strong and if that list contains at least 5 answered and/or accepted questions, then the question shouldn't be allowed to be posted.
- Users must be made to answer a few questions which every programmer should know to answer. It must be general. And if he passes that, only then he/she should be allowed to have an account of SO.
- Weightage of the close votes must be increased based on reps of a user. Vote of less than 5000 rep user has to be taken as 1 vote, greater than 10000 reps must be taken as 2 votes. **Trusted users** are trusted and their vote should be counted as 3 votes. The total votes to close the question must remain same however.

Comment: So ... what does this post add to any of the several "we're going down the drain" posts of the last few weeks? Where are your ideas? What do you propose?

Comment: @Bart, wait... I'm writing it ;)

Comment: Sadly, this is is a place where a lot of us who have donated a lot of our time and knowledge are rapidly speeding toward. It's interesting that a *concrete* example of the current problems is not open for discussion, as evidenced by the rapid downvotes.

Comment: You mean, not open for discussion besides all the other (ongoing) discussions that are already being had on the exact same topic @BrianRoach? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions

Comment: the fastest, easiest, and most helpful method to improve the quality of the site, is to decrease the number of close votes needed to put a question on hold from 5 cv's to 3. After that is implemented, it would be nice to see a harsher algorithm implemented in banning users from asking questions, as well as a harsher algorithm for SO deleting questions from the site, so more questions are deleted and not clogging up the site with the trash.

Comment: @Bart Oh, It's a duplicate? I must have missed those close votes on my screen. Or is it something you just dislike? Perhaps editing it to "Why are top contributors editing their profiles to show they are leaving SO" would be better? ... Oh, hey, I can do that ...

Comment: I have already stated my problems with this question in an earlier comment. To state that such problems are not open for discussion is however nonsense @BrianRoach.

Comment: @Bart, the duplicate which you are pointing to is not about what I'm proposing. make sure that you've read my edit

Comment: the dowvnotes, it is getting is the example of how bad the system is running :(

Comment: @AmitJoki [Downvotes are an example of disagreement](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) and are an appropriate way to put your opinion across on Meta.

Comment: @AsheeshR, thanks for telling. I had not known that ;)

Comment: However downvotes drive contributors away.  Every downvote should be accounted for with an explanation and should be reversible via a voting system.

Comment: I bow down to this system. Will delete this question soon :(

Comment: @AmitJoki: There is no need to delete this. You didn't lose reputation, either. We are having discussions here, but to delete is to disengage from the discussion and retreat.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yeah, I thought of it, but was somewhat depressed when the community didn't agree to my thoughts ;)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, even if I don't delete it, it has already recieved 4 close votes

Comment: So? I didn't cast a close vote myself; I assumed most were from before you edited you question to add remedies. I downvoted instead because I disagree those remedies would work.  But if it *is* closed we at least have a record of the discussion.

Comment: @Amit: the first version of this question was fine (though a duplicate). But as a high-rep user, the edits you have made lack context, and are confusing. The first sentence is "This discussion is entirely different from what's going on. They just asked opinions etc.". This forces the reader to ask: what is 'going on' here? Who is 'they'? Of course, it can be worked out (I did eventually) but please: if you make an edit to any question (on the whole internet) consider future readers, not just the small group who read the first version.

Comment: @halfer, I've re-edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

While it's always sad to see a long-time user decide to pull back on their contributions to the site, you have to realize that this has been happening since the start of the site. In the nearly six years I've been around this place, I've seen many higher-rep (read: long time) users of the site become less active for various reasons. Maintaining an interest in a site for years is a rare thing, and personally I'm surprised to see as many people hang on for as long as they do.

Honestly, many of the recent "sky is falling" Meta posts all seem to lack a sense of historical perspective. People forget how bad things were before the question ban was put into place, or before a decent (and audited) review system was instituted. I have confidence that some of the [question ban changes in the works](https://twitter.com/tinkertim/status/459211148441550848) and proposed [modifications to the close vote review system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions) will help with this.

However, I'm not so sure about your suggested fixes. To your points:

> "Questions that may already have your answer", algorithm must be made strong and if that list contains at least 5 answered and/or accepted questions, then the question shouldn't be allowed to be posted.

No, I don't think this would work well. The "related questions" queries are fairly simple, and do not have a very good hit rate. Far too many false positives would result from this. Good questions would be blocked left and right. We already have problems with [too-aggressive word filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192515/how-to-ask-about-the-halting-problem-on-stackoverflow-regarding-the-title-fil).

> Users must be made to answer a few questions which every programmer should know to answer. It must be general. And if he passes that, only then he/she should be allowed to have an account of SO.

Who decides these questions? How in the world can we make them apply to the incredibly broad audience of developers here? Not every developer knows the same fundamentals, because they don't apply everywhere. Even if you made this domain specific, who will curate these questions?

Every time I hear someone propose making some kind of programming test before someone can use Stack Overflow, I think of the [Jim Crow laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Crow_laws).

> Weightage of the close votes must be increased based on reps of a user. Vote of less than 5000 rep user has to be taken as 1 vote, greater than 10000 reps must be taken as 2 votes. Trusted users are trusted and their vote should be counted as 3 votes. The total votes to close the question must remain same however.

After dealing with a few 10K+ users who have been banned from review over 10 times for failing dozens of obvious audits (some of whom have been banned over 30 times), it becomes pretty clear that having a high reputation does not always mean that you make good moderation-related choices. There are many high-rep users who vote to close everything they see, including really good questions, simply because it doesn't meet some ivory tower standard of theirs. Frankly, I think many of us here are becoming too harsh in the way that we are judging many well-asked questions while missing the steaming trash pile in the corner.

Reducing the number of votes to close for certain classes of users will lead to good questions being closed. If something is truly terrible, it is not hard to get five people to agree on that.

Are there things that should be done to reduce the number of terrible questions coming in to the site? Yes, but I don't think these suggestions are the right way to do that. As I said, I look forward to the proposed improvements to the question ban and better ways of presenting the worst questions to reviewers to get them dealt with sooner.

Comment: Totally agree.  As someone who has been around for a long time I can confirm the testimony that these "sky is falling posts" aren't new.  There's a lot of history in this community, and it has evolved in myriad ways - and it's really pretty remarkable that it is still vibrant and effective.

P.S.: But....Jim Crow?  Ayayay.