# Tracking the close votes review queue: The latest plot, and whether I should stop

Tags: discussion, review-queues, vote-to-close

Unfortunately in recent months I've been busy with "life" and haven't been kept up with meta. Seems I've missed out on a lot of exciting stuff regarding the close votes review queue.

Back in January I kicked off a simple `cron` job on my Linode that would `curl` SO every minute to record the three numbers at https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats:

[image]

```
* * * * * data=`curl https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats | grep 'review-stats-count' | sed 's/[^0-9]//g'` && echo "`date +\%s`,`echo $data | tr ' ', ','`" >> /home/acheong87/cvrq/`date +\%Y-\%m.csv`
```

Finally got around to running the data through Mathematica, so I thought I'd share (click for larger view):

[image]

<sup>I doubt anyone cares for the raw data, but I can provide a link if requested. The Mathematica code too.</sup>

The tiny, periodic steps down between January and March are due to a weekly cleanup job. IIRC, the drop in mid-December was due to bug-fix in said cleanup job. The drop at the end of February was of course due to the beginning of @Shog9's initiatives, but that's about when I disappeared from SO, so I'll let others comment on the events in detail, if they wish.

Personally, I'm curious why the weekly cleanup job doesn't seem to have as much of an effect as before, and what happened earlier in May that caused the queue to move more erratically and begin to grow.

Also, I'm wondering if SO already tracks these stats. If so, and the moderators would like me to stop requesting that page every 60 seconds forever and ever and ever, please let me know.

Comment: Early May changes: [Enough fuzzying: let's let everything into the close queue and age out questions that don't reach a threshold](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252584) and  [When did I get close-vote superpowers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254589); this latter would affect the number of dupe close votes making it into the queue.

Comment: "need review" is likely going to be useless because of changes mentioned in above comment. Tracking "reviews today" and "reviews all-time" probably makes even better sense now than it was before - it's likely the only way to study trends that's hard-to-impossible to fake/fuzzy

Comment: [The CV reviewers chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) may be causing the weekly fluctuations.

Comment: Voting my own question as a duplicate of another because the plots were updated and explained there, not here.