# Does casting the first close vote, also raise a review flag?

Tags: support, review-queues, vote-to-close

After emptying the close votes queue for a particular tag I see recent questions with close votes on them which didn't appear for review. This makes me wonder if older questions I've voted to close will appear in the review queue for other people.

If I vote to close something, do I need to also flag it for others to review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single close flag or close vote will send a post to the review queue, assuming that is does not get closed before it gets there. The vote/flag has to exist on the question for at least 15 minutes before it is actually eligible to enter the queue.

Also, there are some [new rules](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions?lq=1) on how questions age out of that queue automatically:

> - Two parameters:
>
>   1. **FlagsAgeDaysThreshold**: the number of days old the newest vote or flag must be for a question to remain under review. Default value: 4
>   2. **FlagsThreshold**: the number of votes or flags required for a question to remain under review once FlagsAgeDaysThreshold has been exceeded. Default value: 3.
> - A single vote or flag on a question will send it into /review.
> - After FlagsAgeDaysThreshold has been exceeded, the question will be removed from review *if FlagsThreshold has not been met*.
> - [Existing aging rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away/166124#166124) will still apply - votes will not be discarded until they are met.
> - If a question aged out of review and later attracts another vote or flag, it will re-enter review until either FlagsAgeDaysThreshold or FlagsThreshold are no longer met.

Keep in mind that it's rather hard to figure out it already went through review for 10k users, and virtually impossible for non-10k users (easy as pie for moderators).

Answer (score 0):

Both voting to close a question and flagging to close it sends the question to the close review queue (after a short delay). You do not need to flag it if you can vote.

Comment: Does the same apply for answer which have been voted to close, or should they be flagged in addition?

Comment: @bummi: you cannot vote to close *answers*, only *questions*.

Comment: @ok, I was about flagging as VLQ or NAA if I already voted to delete, would it be noise?, ok?, are the already in the VLQ Pipe or is the only place the can be found http://stackoverflow.com/tools , sorry for being unclear.

Comment: @bummi: I've seen posts go into the LQ queue that have been downvoted only, but it wouldn't hurt to flag a post as NAA or VLQ if it applies.