# Could we get the reason for closing at the top of the Reopen Queue?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I was just going through the Reopen queue, and was getting frustrated with trying to figure out if the changes helped the most in a meaningful way. I would have to go over to the Original Question with every item, and scroll down to the bottom to find out WHY it was closed to begin with.

Is that a deliberate omission to get us to at least look at the original question? If so, I totally agree with that reasoning. I was doing that as well once I found out why it was closed.

If that wasn't the reasoning behind this, and other people don't feel that rereading the original question is a good idea, could we please get that information at the top of the item page? Perhaps above the "Original Question" and "Revised Question" tabs?

**Addendum**

[This item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/7237056) in the Reopen Queue is a good example of this. On its own, the edit seems trivial, and wouldn't normally trigger a Reopen vote. However, with the context that it was closed because of "Why isn't this working?" and "How is it currently 'not working'?", you can see that this minor edit does warrant a reopen (in my mind).

Comment: The question you have to ask is not "Does the close-reason (still) apply?" but "Should the question be re-opened?".

Comment: Don't reopen a question closed as unclear because it was clarified to make it be an opinion poll.

Comment: OK, I do concede that point, @Deduplicator. I would take that as another reason to not have it on the page.

Comment: @Deduplicator, But sometimes the first answer to that question is, "Well why was it closed in the first place?"

Comment: @ouflak while this curiosity is understandable (and I frankly often am curious about this), you better keep in mind that it is generally dangerous, as it is known to sometimes result in [bandwagoning](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773). Forcing self to consider "clean room" view of the question you review is safer (as if there were no votes down and close at all). Somewhat related: [The “I Get It” Reputation Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/552/165773)

Comment: @gnat So with that in mind, shouldn't we get rid of notifying us why other people voted to close in the first place? We're allowing bandwagoning to close, but make it more difficult to view why it was closed to reopen.

Comment: @krillgar maybe. If memory serves this was discussed and there was even a feature request for this at MSE. Per my recollection, it was considered not sufficiently much of an issue for _closing_ (yet) to be implemented. In that sense, it's rather not that "we're allowed to" but more like "it's tolerated until there's not enough evidence of substantial abuse"

Comment: ...it also could be an intentional compromise. With 100+ thousands questions waiting for close review (you know, few thousands in the queue are [only tip of the iceberg](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252584/839601)), they would better do their best in making close decisions as simple as possible, even at the expense of higher error rate. With reopen review, there's no contention at all. I just checked, reopen queue shows 3 (that's _three_) items total - with load like that, they sure need not concern about reviewer spending extra few minutes to study the post without external hints

Comment: In the queue I just see the question/answer, to get context (e.g. have the comments been adressed, what do answers say, ...) would be useful.

Answer (score 20):

There are many reasons a question could be closed.  Many times in the close queue there will be a disagreement as to which reason is most appropriate (ie. 2 votes for unclear, one vote for off-topic -> debugging questions need code, etc).  Regardless, if the question receives 5 close votes it is closed.  The one with the most votes is the one that is displayed even though there could be many things wrong with the post.

What you really should be doing is looking at the question and asking: "Is this question good enough *as it stands* to be on the site?"  If it is, great, reopen it.  If it made improvements but is still bad, leave it closed.  Don't reopen crap just because they made *some* effort.  They need to get to at least the minimum quality threshold for a question before it gets reopened.

Comment: Agreed. I do see that a lot when I close stuff where there are multiple reasons. I guess it's just a matter of me getting used to that new queue. I wouldn't just blindly reopen a post because it was moderately better than it was before, I'd want it to conform to the guidelines. I'm just saying that having a clue as to why other people thought it was worthy of being closed could help with determining if it is better.

Comment: To kind of clarify my point on my approach, I don't go through the main list of questions assuming that everything should be closed. That's not why I'm there. It's when I read the question and get the impression that the question is way off base that I'll vote to close it. I think it is just a matter of finding the correct way to approach that queue.

Comment: close reason shown may even be one cast by a single voter: ["In the case of five different reasons chosen, the first selected will be the one that triumphs."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/32701/165773)

Comment: Then there's little reason to show the diff - since it doesn't really matter, only the end result does.

Comment: @gnat, giving the (up to 5?) top reasons, or allowing to look at them, would cure that.

Comment: @vonbrand there are many feature requests to address that and many suggestions on how it can be done. My personal favorite is [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234894/165773), "breakdown of the votes can go in the revision history". Quite a pity that Stack Exchange team doesn't give a sh!t