# Does flagging an already-flagged question for closure affect its status in the Close Vote queue?

Tags: discussion, support, flags, vote-to-close

I've read through a couple posts on CVs and flags, but couldn't find quite what I'm looking for.

[Shog already detailed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194515/sort-order-on-close-vote-queue) how the CV Queue is *sorta* sorted already, in that questions in the queue with more votes either way will appear more frequently, and preference is *also* given to recently-queued items.

When a question is initially flagged by a user who can't yet Vote-To-Close, that counts as a CV in that it sends the question to the CV Queue.

My question is whether *additional* closure **flags** will count as "more votes" or even as a "recent queuing" for questions that are already flagged, thus giving them a higher priority for being shown in the CV Queue.

E.g. a 1,500 rep user flags for closure > Question sent to CV Queue > A second 1,500 rep user flags for closure. *Does the question in the queue now consider itself to have two flags/votes or just one?*

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The system does recognize that there are multiple flags. However, this *doesn't* affect the question's priority in the queue; flags carry no weight when it comes to closure - no number of close flags will directly cause a post to be closed, nor will new flags "bump" a question in the queue.

Additional flags aren't completely meaningless however:

1. New flags will prevent old flags from [aging away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting), and multiple flags can slow the rate at which *votes* age away (only [one vote or flag per question is aged each day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136989/how-do-close-votes-age-away/166124#166124), so older flags will age before newer votes).
2. New flags will prevent the question from [dropping out of the close queue due to inactivity](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions).

Note that it takes only one matching close *vote* to mark close flags as helpful, so questions which hang around with flags for long periods of time are relatively rare.

Comment: @Deduplicator In that scenario, the flags are probably dismissed already, per the last sentence of the post.

Comment: The subtlety here involves close flags followed by votes that *don't* match (unclear flag + too broad vote, for instance)... The aging logic is quite complex, and has been a rich source of bugs in the past; adding more nuance is not something to be done casually.

Comment: Note that the statement "flags carry no weight when it comes to closure"  is only applicable to close flags. "Offensive" and "spam" flags can actually result in posts being deleted automatically http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/192171