# Should I flag comments if they indicate the question should be closed?

Tags: support, flags, comments, comment-flags

Sometimes there are unanswered questions that look ok until you read all the way into the comments:

> Oops it was caused by a mistake elsewhere in my code  -OP

In this case, the question should certainly be closed/deleted as a typo, or not reproducible.

What should I flag (question or comment)? The comment should definitely not be deleted on its own, but if I flag the question, it may not be obvious. Should I use a specific flag type?

I'm asking this because one of my flags was marked as disputed. I was flagging [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379865/java-arraylist-and-other-variables-not-saving) It should be closed, right? (Edit: it's closed now.  `:)`)

Comment: Don't flag it. Vote to close with the "*a problem that can no longer be reproduced*" reason.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Do you mean: don't flag it, earn enough rep to VTC, then VTC?

Answer (score 6):

You should flag the question as: Should be Closed -> Off Topic -> the problem was caused by a simple typographical error.

When over 3k rep you can do a close vote for that reason instead of flagging.

Comment: Is this the most helpful way? My flag for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36379865/java-arraylist-and-other-variables-not-saving) was disputed.

Comment: @Laurel:  "Disputed" means that someone else (not anyone necessarily reviewing the flag) disagreed that there was an issue that warranted the flag.  It's not an indication of you misflagging anything.

Comment: @Laurel - I would have flagged it as you did. A disputed flag does not mean it was wrong. Some people agreed with you and some did not.

Comment: Can they see the all comments? Do people look in the comments for this stuff?

Comment: @Laurel - Yes, those doing the close votes can see the comments when handing the flag.

Comment: Why do you think it was disputed?

Comment: @Laurel It got disputed because the [flag aging script](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252584/578411) picked it up. After your flag no-one casted another flag or close vote in 4 days hence the review task got removed and pending flags get disputed in that process (as they can't be helpful or declined).

Comment: @rene So it will be marked as "disputed" if it aged away after someone voted "not sure"?

Comment: @Laurel No-one voted "Not Sure", this is just what the SEDE query returns where there was no outcome (review was invalidated). Actually, no-one voted on the close vote review and that was the problem here: because of that, the flag aged away and was automatically disputed.

Comment: @Tunaki Why isn't it marked as "aged away"?

Comment: @Laurel - It was disputed as a result of this review in triage: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11871612 . Can't comment on the validity of that review.

Comment: @BradLarson sorry to be persistent but I don't understand the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36379865/timeline) in that case. Did the unsalvagable vote in the triage review by [necreaux](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4564945/necreaux) (< 2K rep) create the close reviewtask? Then what event caused the close review task to be invalidated? Does that mean that necreaux also has a disputed flag in their history?