# When flagging a question, does it matter which flag I use?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderation

There have been [quite](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-down-voting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal?cb=1) [a few](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252009/should-there-be-a-deterrent-for-answering-obvious-duplicate-questions) [questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow) on meta recently about the decreasing quality/influx of duplicate posts on SO.  As a relatively new user, I want to help, but there are frequently many things wrong with the question and I can't figure out exactly how I should flag.  My common sense tells me "flag it anyway" to bring it to the attention of users who can VTC.

This question was primarily prompted by looking at my flag count and realizing that 15-20% of my older flags are just chilling.  Not declined, I don't think, because they say "active".

How important is the accuracy of my flag choice when flagging a question?  Obviously, I do my best to describe a problem with the flag that fits it most accurately, but are there moderation issues if I mis-categorize or otherwise screw up?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, yes it does.

The main thing is, *someone* has to deal with that flag later. If a post is flagged incorrectly, we can't reasonably expect whoever is reviewing the flag to then sit down and comb through the post and look at it from every possible angle, trying to figure out what's *actually* wrong with it (if anything). The ratio of flagger-to-reviewer is way too high for that to be effective. However, if a post is flagged correctly, then it's much easier to deal with; it's much easier to verify a large number of flags if you know you're looking for a specific thing.

All that is also ignoring the fact that all flags aren't handled the same way (for example, flagging as off topic doesn't do the same thing as flagging as low quality, and neither do the same as flagging as spam)

As for the last bit:

> but are there moderation issues if I mis-categorize or otherwise screw up?

I'm not 100% sure, but I wouldn't be surprised if flagging suspensions (for example, being unable to flag for 7 days) get doled out for poor flagging quality.

Comment: There is a mechanism to block/warn users with a high percentage of recently declined flags.

Comment: I think that the user was referring implictly to duplicate/close flags, not very low quality/spam/offensive flags ("bring it to the attention of users who can VTC"), and which of the flag reasons would be appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

> How important is the accuracy of my flag choice when flagging a question?

I'll show you a practical example, when I erroneously picked the incorrect flag the first time, and when it got declined, I reflagged it correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> How important is the accuracy of my flag choice when flagging a question? Obviously, I do my best to describe a problem with the flag that fits it most accurately, but are there moderation issues if I mis-categorize or otherwise screw up?

It's important.

The type of flag you raise feeds into a number of other systems.  Close flags go to the close votes queue.  Not an answer and very low quality flags go into the low quality queue.

In fact, accurate flagging is important for [generating good review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/160551):

> #### How does the audit work?
>
> First Posts, Late Answers and Low Quality - The test presents a reviewer with a post that was previously removed by a moderator and known to be of extremely poor quality (**flagged as spam, not an answer or very low quality**) or high quality (many up-votes, no down-votes, etc).

As nKn noted, the moderators can [decline your flag if you flag incorrectly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190424/160551).

If you're unsure what to flag, you could try flagging as Other and include a detailed explanation on what you think the problem is or what you would like the moderator to do.

> This question was primarily prompted by looking at my flag count and realizing that 15-20% of my older flags are just chilling. Not declined, I don't think, because they say "active".

I will venture a guess and say these were flags about closing questions.  Moderators don't handle those anymore, they just go into the close vote queue.

With the current setup of the Stack Overflow close vote queues (and Stack Overflow only), if you flagged a question and nobody else has flagged or voted to close that question, it is [currently hidden from close-vote reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252577/538247) and languishing in no-man's land.  A number of us have flags like these that will be stuck in suspension until the review queues start showing everything again or just [discarding really old flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252584/enough-fuzzying-lets-let-everything-into-the-close-queue-and-age-out-questions) on the assumption that if there was a problem, someone else would have chimed in by now.