# What happens when giving the wrong flag?

Tags: discussion, flags

What happens when a user flags a post (which must be flagged) but they gave the wrong flag (couldn't evaluate the proper flag must be given).

For example, if a post must be flagged `too broad`, but the user flagged it as `unclear what you're asking`, is the flag accepted or not?

Comment: Open to interpretation by the moderator I guess. It's possible he/she will decline it however it is also possible he/she will mark it as "helpful" because you are flagging it for a reason (even though you may have selected the wrong one). Not posting as an answer because I'm not a mod but I've had both cases happen to me.

Comment: @aug interesting point, I think it may be like this.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253215/when-flagging-a-question-does-it-matter-which-flag-i-use)

Comment: I flagged a post with a wrong flag, it was declined. I flagged the same post with the correct flag, it was marked helpful, and the question closed eventually.

Comment: in my experience, wrong flags just get rejected - lots of posts on meta saying how mods are not expected to spend time trying to understand the flags cos they have so many to process

Comment: I think there is also another possibility, it may depends on how close the flag is.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Flags to close don't go to moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187008/165773), these feed to close review queue where 3K users review the question and [vote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/vote-to-close/info) to close or leave it open.

These flags are resolved as helpful if the question gets closed, even if your close reason differs from final one.

I [could not find](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/209640/165773) authoritative reference on what happens if review decision is to leave it open; some kinds of flags are known to resolve to [disputed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95275/what-is-a-disputed-flag) if they fail review of regular (non-diamond) users, but [this recent example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288082/declined-unclear-flag-later-post-put-on-hold-as-offtopic#comment165758_288082) suggests that failing close review may result in [declined flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/141292/165773).

It may also happen that moderator occasionally stumbles upon your flag to close and decides to decline. If you get too many flags declined by moderator, you will be [first warned and then temporarily suspended from flagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/165773).

Comment: If the users vote to leave it open the flag is declined I believe.

Comment: Yes - moderators can never handle close flags directly, and the ones that get declined by review also count against you in flag bans.

Comment: I think disputed comes when the review queue votes are split.  For a flag to be declined the voting would have to be unanimous to leave the question open.  (Or nearly unanimous?)

Comment: @BenVoigt in review [referred in my example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7351337) there is a split, but flagger still got decline

Answer (score -1):

You can retract the flag and add the one you meant to add.