# duplicate flag but not marked as duplicate Why

Tags: discussion, flags, duplicate-questions

I have raised many flags as duplicate on "Stackoverflow" and reviewed as help full but it not marked as duplicate, due to I have not access to caste votes so I flagged. for example

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26526602/field-navigation-with-tab-key-in-kivy

[image]

In above picture it is showing is helpful, so why this question is not marked as "Duplicate".

It is just a example it happen many times. If Duplicate flag not marked as duplicate so what is the use of this flag??

Update : ok above question was delete but what about this

[Difference between two dates and .NET function DaysInMonth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207671/difference-between-two-dates-and-net-function-daysinmonth)

Comment: The question is deleted.

Comment: @sotiriosdelimanolis, what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207671/difference-between-two-dates-and-net-function-daysinmonth, its also helpful, but not marked

Comment: I *think* that flags are marked as "helpful" when *one user* has agreed with them, so the question may have one close vote from the review item you raised but not yet enough to close it. The close review queue is at 11k right now and I've not often seen it lower than that -- stuff takes time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What happens when giving the wrong flag?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285822/what-happens-when-giving-the-wrong-flag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question was deleted by the author.

Note that flagging a post as a duplicate only puts the question into the closing review queue. It is users with the [close vote privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) that then actually close the question.

Those users could have voted to leave a question open or could have voted to close the question for different reasons.

Now that the post has been deleted, however, no one can vote close it. There is no need to. Your flag has been marked as helpful automatically when the post was deleted; the system assumes your flag had merit if the post was removed altogether rather than closed.

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207671/difference-between-two-dates-and-net-function-daysinmonth, its also helpful, but not marked

Comment: @ImranAliKhan: One vote by a user with the close vote privilege that agrees with your flag can also mark it as helpful. There are currently 2 dupe close votes on that post; at least one of which must've been cast after your flag (there could have been more that have expired since).