# Declined unclear-flag, later post put on hold as offtopic

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29061548/1) was the initial post. Flagged it as "unclear what you are asking".

Flag was simply `declined`, and 20 minutes later [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29061548/get-and-set-text-box-value-in-an-event) was put on hold as off topic.

Is this a mistakenly declined flag, or did I do something wrong? I had the impression that "unclear", "broad", "suggest tutorial etc", "debug my code" flags are pretty much the same.

Comment: Related FAQ on Meta Stack Exchange: [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105391/238706)

Comment: @Palec Interesting. _"..it is important that flag reasons match why a post should be closed"_ I guess my "impression" might have been a .. "misconception".

Comment: Not really an answer to your question on why this happened, but IMHO "unclear what you are asking" was a perfectly appropriate flag reason. It seems at least as good as any of the other choices.

Comment: I believe it was declined by the system after three reviewers voted to leave that question open: https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7351337 . As to why they voted this way, you'd have to ask them.

Comment: Those 3 leave open voters must have mis-clicked...

Answer (score 6):

The flag was declined because 3 people voted to leave the question open from the close vote queue, even though it ended up being closed by others outside of the queue later.  The fact that it was closed later doesn't affect the state of the flag.

Since the problem you brought up is indeed a problem with the question, don't worry about it; the mistake was in how others reviewed the content, not with your flag.

Answer (score -10):

> I had the impression that "unclear", "broad", "suggest tutorial etc", "debug my code" flags are pretty much the same.

I can't see the original post, so I can't speak to this specific situation.  But "unclear what you're asking" and "off-topic" are *not necessarily* synonymous.  If the post was off-topic as "questions must include the code," then yes, the flags are more or less equivalent.  But if it was off-topic for some other reason (e.g. "this belongs on Super User"), then you should flag with that reason.

For the record, "debug my code" is [not actually a valid close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x/253096#253096) by itself.  It's a perfectly good reason to *downvote*, but you don't need to involve the extremely-backlogged close review queue to do that, so please don't.

Comment: The close reason given, "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior [...]" is effectively a subset of "Unclear", it's just a specific reason for the question being unclear.

Comment: @Servy: That's the "questions must include the code" reason I was discussing.

Comment: If you think that that close reason isn't a valid reason for closing a question, then you should bring that up separately.  For the moment, since it's in the system as a close reason, it is considered to be a valid reason for closing a question.  As I said before, it's basically just a special case of "unclear' in which it specifies why the information is unclear (it's missing one of the specified pieces of information).

Comment: @Servy: I'm very confused.  What are you even talking about?

Comment: @Kevin it is one of the _off-topic close reasons_ listed.  It's under "It should be closed for another reason" --> "Off-topic" -->

Comment: @ryanyuyu: I'm looking at the off-topic VTC subpage right now, and I see nothing about "debug my code" *in general*.  I see a lot of more specific problems that might *happen* to apply to *some* "debug my code" questions.  There is no catch-all "questioner put in no effort" close reason.

Comment: @Kevin I think that the reference to "Debug my code" is just short-hand for the otherwise really long specific description.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: I see.  I've clarified with a link.

Comment: @Kevin So now you've made it clear that you're talking about something completely different from the OP.  He's talking about the reason the question was closed with; the one that I quoted the first sentence of in my first comment.

Comment: @Servy: OP's post displayed what I interpreted as a common misconception.  I thought of this as a teachable moment.  I fail to see why everyone is making such a fuss about it.

Comment: @Kevin Because you interpreted the OP's post incorrectly, and as a result, are giving advice that is completely incorrect in context.  Just like I could have posted and answer that would go into detail about how it's bad to create new accounts to upvote your own posts, and I would be correct that doing that is wrong, and yet such an answer would completely fail to answer the question, and thus merit downvotes.  You provided correct information that *fails to answer the question* due to your misunderstanding of the question itself.

Comment: @Servy: I'm not convinced your interpretation of OP's question is any more accurate than mine.  In any event, *someone* will interpret it the way I did, and I'd like to ensure they don't misunderstand how the closing system works.  Is that really such a heinous crime?

Comment: Posting an answer that doesn't answer the question, and instead assumes the context is radically different from what it is, and as a result advocates an action that is the complete opposite of the appropriate action in this case?  Yes, I'd say that's a problem.

Comment: @Servy: Tell me where I advocated that **OP** take any action whatsoever, and I'll happily remove it.

Comment: @Kevin Tell me where I claimed that you advocated that the OP take any action whatsoever.  And again, you have *failed to answer the question*.  You have provided information that is correct, but off topic, and as a result have not answered the question.  When you post an answer that doesn't answer the question, you'll get downvotes.  That's what they're there for.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73106/discussion-between-kevin-and-servy).