# What is the difference between too broad and primarily opinion based?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, needs-more-focus, opinion-based

Recently I've seen two questions in a very similar fashion being flagged differently. I'm only starting to actually get acquainted with reviewing posts so I might be totally off here, but it seems to me there's quite some overlap and I'm unsure which one would be better to be used in the future.

The questions I'm referring to are https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35615566/what-is-the-difference-between-angularjs-jquery-reactjs-and-underscore (too broad) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619605/which-of-the-following-is-better-when-to-use-each-of-the-javascript-framework (primarily opinion based).

The Help Center [says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions):

> **too broad** - if your question could be answered by an entire book, or
> has many valid answers, it's probably too broad for our format There
> are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too
> long for this format. Please add details to narrow down the answer set
> or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.
>
> **primarily opinion-based** - discussions focused on diverse opinions are
> great, but they just don't fit our format well. Many good questions
> generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but
> answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on
> opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise.

I wouldn't mind some guidance on which one is better to use when I'm reviewing these posts.

Comment: You know what? There's probably a reasonable amount of overlap between the two.

Comment: Yea I figured. Any idea which one would be better to use in posts like above, or doesn't it really matter? I'm unsure what the consequences are of me flagging a post incorrectly, although it probably doesn't matter too much (which then raises the question why is there a difference).

Comment: As @BoltClock said, they overlap. But e.g. Too broad: What is a framework for node.js || Primarily opinion-based: What is the best framework for node.js

Comment: Thanks for the example of the differences, that makes sense. Also looked up another post on what happens if one flags (wrong), http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285822/what-happens-when-giving-the-wrong-flag

Comment: related: [Breaking down “too broad” and trying to understand it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258589/breaking-down-too-broad-and-trying-to-understand-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is primarily focused on questions that invite opinionated answers, while the other lacks a clear, focused problem statement.

There is some overlap, but in those cases, just chose whatever you think is the best close reason.

Comment: I totally agree, the only thing that can be added is that we close also to help out OP, he gets a text when its closed on what he should address to try and reopen. You like to put some extra effort in to this, consider the help OP will get from this text.... better--> feels like opinion (OP please try to address this issue), explain a lot of stuff (OP please address this issue). Some case however are hopelessly both...