# Display the ratio between new questions to close and closed questions

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, vote-to-close

We had times where the sheer amount of questions in the close review queue was rising, then shrinking due to a phase of motivation, then keeping the balance and now seem to rise a bit again.

To motivate reviewing and bringing this big number down I propose to implement a meter that will display the ratio between new questions in the close queue and questions pulled out of the review queue in a period of time, for instance today.

It could be green if more questions were handled that got put into the queue and red if less. Because nobody seems to care anymore.

Comment: *"... the sheer amount of questions in the close review queue was rising, then shrinking due to a phase of motivation..."* - I don't this this is correct. The review queue was at about 100K, so the site made it more difficult for a question to enter the question and started [quickly] expiring questions in the queue. It appears the site is tending to deficient questions, but they are not being properly disposed. See, for example, [Fuzzy the number of questions in the close review queue, a dopamine for the shutterers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252573/608639).

Answer (score 1):

Questions age out of the queue if they aren't handled, so as a direct result of that behavior the queue will pretty much always have a net zero change in size, at least over any significant period of time.  If there were way more items being added than the reveiwers could handle, there'd just be that many more items leaving the queue due to expirations.  If the reviewers started handling a lot more reviews than normal, they'd just be that many less items expiring.

Comment: They only age out if they have 100 views which many don't have. With your argument we could just stop reviewing because it would age out anyway

Comment: @juergend The close votes (if actual close votes were cast) only age out after 100 views of the question.  There is no such restriction on removing items from the close vote review queue.

Comment: @juergend I'm not arguing that we should stop reviewing, I'm saying that the rate of change of the size of the review queue is going to pretty much always be zero, regardless of the health of the queue.  It's simply not a meaningful metric to look at.  The fact that the stat you propose showing isn't a meaningful stat doesn't mean that the whole queue is pointless.  It simply means you need to come up with metrics that more meaningfully reflect what's going on, if you want to add in more metrics.