# Why are so many resources dispatched to close an off-topic question?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

This showed up in the close queue: [What's the main difference between Quickboot and normal boot in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6975930). An image is below.

[image]

With a policy of [dropping questions from the queue in an effort to keep the queue sizes small due to lack of reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252572/608639), this seems like a bad idea. Its seems like reviewing resources could be better allocated.

Why were nine people dispatched to close this question?

Is there a better way to utilize the limited resource of reviewers?

Comment: Highly related: [How many “Recommend Close” votes is too many?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204705/how-many-recommend-close-votes-is-too-many)

Comment: @animuson any clue when "Recommed Close" votes started getting listed as "Close".  That would eliminate some of the confusion here.

Comment: @psubsee2003 [Low Quality review queue erroneously showing “Close” instead of “Recommended Close”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208221/low-quality-review-queue-erroneously-showing-close-instead-of-recommended-clo)

Comment: The real question behind this question is: why can't I see if someone else already recommended to close a question. Why do I have to do it additionally in order to be sure that it is on the LQ list? This is clearly work that is done multiple times without need and the software that powers SO could handle that better.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Did you check the rep of everyone?  That is why there are 9 close "votes".

Only 4 of the close votes on the review in question had sufficient rep to actually close the post.  The remaining 5 had <3K rep so they couldn't close the question.  This is the nature of the Low Quality Posts review queue.  Unless someone has sufficient rep to actually perform the action they are recommending, their votes only serve to keep the post active in the review queue long enough for someone of sufficient rep to handle the post.  Now that 5 3K users have voted to close, it is no longer in the LQP queue.

Comment: *"Did you check the rep of everyone?"* - no, its irrelevant. 8:1 is overwhelming consensus for Stack Overflow, which can't seem to agree on anything.

Comment: @jww but users <3K can't vote to close questions, so how would you suggest their votes be handled?

Comment: Good point. That begs the question, why are they voting in the first place? Or maybe the question, why are their votes irrelevant given the problem of review queue depth and current policies.

Comment: @jww but they aren't irrelevant.  They are recommending closure (which is basically flagging).  As I mention in my answer, their votes keep the post in the queue long enough for users of sufficient rep to come along and handle the post

Comment: @Jww I will say that the fact that they are allowed in the queue at all is confusing to me.  If they can't perform the action and only prolong the stay in the queue, why allow them to review at all except to make it easier to remove the post from the queue.

Comment: @jww Your question prompted me to ask it on MSE since it is a network wide issue - [Why do users who can't perform specific actions allowed in to the Low Quality Review Queue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248296/why-do-users-who-cant-perform-specific-actions-allowed-in-to-the-low-quality-re)

Comment: Maybe they aren't in the queue but see the question while browsing and VTC?

Comment: @MikeBrown If <3K, outside of the queue, there is no close link.