# Add numbers back to the review queue drop-down menu

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, top-bar

As of the [new update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355233/when-i-look-at-the-review-icon-i-see-red) for the review queue, the number of items in the review queue has been removed. Can they be added back?

[image: numbers]

Comment: Conversely, what use is it to you to see that there are 8,500 things in the queue?

Comment: @Makoto then you would go in and review...

Comment: @Makoto See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252572/fuzzy-the-number-of-questions-in-the-close-review-queue-a-dopamine-for-the-shut

Comment: ... While realising that you only have 20-30 reviews available to you per day, and that number in the queue ***keeps rising***.  I really want you to sell why the numbers should be back.

Comment: Looks like they are still A/B testing because I see numbers now instead of the red dot I saw a couple of days ago. I like connecting the dots better.

Comment: The numbers are not important, one can feel depressed when they see 10K question for closure (So why bother...), or if there are less than 10 reviews for NATO/Late answers (So why bother, let someone else do it), but red dots - I feel like a kitten running after a red laser dot on the wall, and I just have to click on it

Comment: @Makoto I’m curious what you mean in saying a reviewer only has only 20-30 reviews available per day. I realize there are limits on how many you can approve, but there are no limits on how many you can *skip* through. I hope I don’t like a bad citizen for saying this, but I skip far more reviews than any I take any kind of action at all on. So if a count for a review queue shows, say 45, I know that’s even if I look at all 45 of those, that’s not 45 reviews I’m gonna end up acting on—because on most I’m just gonna end up pressing Skip. (Now hoping I don’t get review-banned for abusing Skip…)

Comment: Well @Makoto it's back now https://imgur.com/a/sBY2W