# Empty review queues?

Tags: support, review-queues

Recently I noticed the "Review queues" button (on SO) for the first time, as it had a red button on top of it (I don't know if I gained the ability to review recently or not). I clicked on it to see a menu pop up, then clicked on "All queues" to see a screen with number of queues, with top 3 ones which I could access and review. They all had 0 posts.

I've noticed it again (it being red circle), and again clicked on it - to see same as earlier - 0 posts. When I refreshed (after a second) the queue was populated with 11 / 5 / 3 posts. After another refresh (again after a second), all of them dropped to 0 and stayed there.

I've started refreshing now and then - and now I'm seeing 14 / 11 / 3 that are not dropping to 0 suddenly - they are decreasing indeed (which is, I guess correct behaviour) but by slight amount after each refresh  (or staying on the same number), and not turning to 0 (so I can actually go and see what's in the queue).

I also don't have the number of posts in each of queues, which I see in similar questions posted for this.

So, I guess my question is composite:

- what's the deal with the red dot?
- if queue is cached, why would it occasionally display "real time" results (like - decrease by 1 for queues) before plummeting to 0 and staying there?
- should I be seeing number of posts in queues?

[image]

Comment: Click "all queues" and it should make way more sense.

Comment: I think this a cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302226/how-does-the-review-needed-indicator-work-exactly

Comment: @Servy I did - I saw 0 posts in each of the queues. Let me add that in description of the issue, as I've omitted this step

Comment: @eithed And you didn't notice all of the other queues that weren't empty on the page, besides just those three?

Comment: Also relevant (I don't think it's been linked yet): https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358151/

Comment: @Servy - queues that I don't have access to were not empty (but I guessed they might have fewer people editing them, so the cache doesn't need to update for them so often, idk)

Comment: @Ajean - cheers for that! This coincides with what I've observed. I guess this can be marked as duplicate then

Answer (score 12):

I can answer at least two of your questions:

> what's the deal with the red dot?

See [When I look at the review icon, I see red](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355233/when-i-look-at-the-review-icon-i-see-red) ...essentially, the red dot is now the indicator that there are review queues that you have access to which need attention from you, a potential reviewer.

> should I be seeing number of posts in queues?

Well, that's been a hot topic and a lot of people want it, but it's currently not designed that way. There's a chance it's being A/B tested and I'm in the B group that doesn't see numbers, currently. See [Add numbers back to the review queue drop-down menu](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356077/add-numbers-back-to-the-review-queue-drop-down-menu) for an example of one of the requests (more have been made as answers and in posts on Meta.SE rather than here on Meta.SO.

As for your caching question... I can't answer that.

Comment: Thank you very much - shouldn't the red dot display only if there're indeed any questions for me to review, as it popped up for me only twice, and in both times after I clicked on it, it displayed 0.

Comment: @eithed Yes, the red dot should display only when the respective queue hits a certain threshold. Because each queue tends to sit around a different size, each queue has a different threshold. For your queues, that's: **First Posts & Late Answers: 90 tasks**; and **Triage: 100 tasks**. If you are seeing a red dot, and clicking on it, and the queues are zero, then that's probably a caching issue. They used to have the issue where it would show red even if you had used up all your reviews, but I believe they fixed that a few weeks ago.

Comment: I'm sorry to say then that the issue persists as a red dot appears and there's no issues for me to review. I've just came home and opened SO - red dot was waiting for me, and after clicking it there was again nothing there.

Comment: Same here. I "see red" practically all the time, but whenever I check all the queues I can access are either empty or very close to it. It is starting to get on my nerves.

Comment: I've actually seen the red dot before when every review queue I could access was completely empty and up-to-date. They should definitely make sure *that* doesn't happen.

Comment: @TylerH, Unfortunately, [there's no check with respect to the individual user being able to review *anything*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302226/271271), let alone being able to review items in the queue(s) which are "in danger". The only check that's done with respect to the individual user is if they've clicked on the review icon in the last hour.

Comment: @Makyen Hmm, I thought I had read a while ago they had implemented some fixes for that; maybe they just mentioned it was planned, instead of a completed effort.

Comment: I'm also seeing this red dot for empty queues