# Has the recent issues related to Code of Conduct changes and gender pronouns affected SO activity?

Tags: discussion, code-of-conduct

The new [Code of Conduct and the endless discussions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/334900/official-faq-on-gender-pronouns-and-code-of-conduct-changes?cb=1) also had a unpleasant (and unprecedented?) side-effect of several moderators and other users resigning.

I am wondering if this had any measurable impact on SO activity (number of questions / time interval) and/or moderation activity (more non-tackled flags).

Taking a look [at the review queues](https://stackoverflow.com/review) shows no problems (the Close vote queue which typically stayed at 10K back in the days now has less than 9K).

**Question:** Has the recent issues related to Code of Conduct changes and gender pronouns affected SO activity?

Comment: There does seem to be an increase in votes posts and traffic, but i have no way of correlating that to meta events.

Comment: Note that the CVQ is artificially kept at a certain level that does not necessarily correspond to the actual number of questions with pending close votes.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I did not know that. I thought all questions with close go there after a while.

Comment: Here's the FR that made it possible: [Fuzzy the number of questions in the close review queue, a dopamine for the shutterers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252572/215552)

Comment: Custom flags are not handled as quickly. That's really the only change I've noticed that can be attributed to the Meta SE issues. (Not just fewer mods, but the volume of Q, A and comments on Meta SE and in chats.) As for SO generally, in the tags I'm active in if anything, there are more questions. The atmosphere here on Meta SO is generally *quieter* than it was earlier this year. (I guess everyone's over on SE who feels the need to express their opinion.)

Comment: The stats I can get at with regards to flag handling by moderators on SO are not sufficiently granular to allow me to extract out certain periods of time. I only get an average of the time it took to handle each flag over a certain period of time (e.g., day, week, month). The average handling time for month would include the handling time for the week, so this doesn’t tell us much. You’d have to remember what it was before. I kinda do...but it varies a lot over time. Currently, we’re at between 1-2 hours per flag, which isn’t bad at all. Actually pretty good, compared to the early days.

Comment: @CodyGray I had a couple that took around *ten days* to be handled. Granted, they weren't time-critical and it didn't bother me. But the delay was very noticeable. I raised them just about the time things hit the fan FWIW

Comment: Yes, indeed, @Cindy. I’m citing averages for *all* flags. Some flags take longer to handle. This mostly depends on the type—custom flags take much longer to review and act upon. Then certain flags are just *hard*, and require either a certain person who is experienced investigating that issue, or just someone in the right mood to deal with it. Sometimes one mod is unsure, so we leave it for someone else to review also. The bigger cost isn’t going to be whether helpful/decline is picked, but the quality of investigation behind each. We all had our niches, and the departure leaves some gaps.

Comment: Regarding Q&A, I have a bit better analytics, but a prohibition on sharing the particulars of that in public, so I’ll defer answering to a CM. But I do feel comfortable noting that there has been a decline in questions and answers over the past 3 months (interestingly, not really in votes, and definitely not in downvotes), but just the existence of a decline doesn’t prove any significance, much less correlation. You’d have to go back and look at natural “waves” over time. I’m sure the number of posts waxes and wanes, so I don’t know if this observed decrease is even significant.

Comment: @CodyGray Is there some possible reason why the number of questions should have declined? Answers could be understood as some kind of strike-like behavior but questions are mostly from people less acquainted with the situation, so I would expect them to stay roughly constant.

Comment: @Trilarion Lies, damn lies, and statistics.

Comment: @CodyGray Then the working hypothesis is simply that people lose interest in SO or in Q&A or in both.

Comment: @CodyGray are flag that are insta-handled (comments flag, spam, etc.) counted in that stat? That could skew the number significantly lower.

Comment: There is no way to even tell which way the traffic "should" go based on it.  If one group of offended people boycott SE, and another ramp up posting in outrage, then the effect could be both huge, and statistically insignificant.