# Speed close flags

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close, declined-flags

Is there a policy on flagging questions for speed closing?

Example use case: duplicates that haven't been closed for years.

I've [submitted such flags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/1269037), and some were accepted, while others were declined.

[image]

Comment: @Shog9: does this question apply only to SO? Aren't there duplicate questions on all SE sites?

Comment: @DanDascalescu Other SE sites don't have a massive backlog of questions in the close votes queue that would require "speed closing," as you put it.

Comment: See [Is closing old questions a gigantic waste of time and effort?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254402)

Comment: Remember, when you VTC it, it goes into the close queue

Comment: did you consider joining [SO close reviewers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251955/so-close-vote-reviewers)?

Comment: @gnat: Not really. I'm generally against closing questions, aside from spam or duplicates. SO is plagued with [trigger-happy closers who understand nothing about the questions they close](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278460/speed-close-flags?noredirect=1#comment124730_278466). If you don't know what it is, let others deal with it. The community loves to answer questions, but the culture on SO has become one of [closing and deletions getting out of hand](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50967/question-deletions-are-getting-out-of-hand).

Comment: And why is my question downvoted -4? I asked if there is a policy; I didn't suggest we create a policy.

Answer (score 9):

Solutions:

- Get a gold badge and Mjolnir away
- Get into a chatroom and organize a duplicate closing effort
- Vote to close and let the close queue handle the rest.

It's not a moderator's job to do those things. It's not an exceptional situation and it's not something that requires moderator attention. It takes 5 votes to close for a reason.

The only reason some of the flags were approved is that some mods are more patient than others and they had some free time on their hands to help you out with closing a duplicate. Please do not take this courtesy for granted.

Comment: Also, in the case of these most recent flags (which I declined), it was not immediately apparent that these were duplicates. In cases like this involving older and highly upvoted posts, I prefer to let multiple subject matter experts review this instead of unilaterally closing. There wasn't really a pressing need to close these right now.

Comment: This isn't the case on other SE sites - other sites don't have the moderator swamping problem that SO has.

Comment: 1. I don't remember mentioning any other SE sites, and second, could you define this "moderator swamping problem" you mention? I'm not familiar with what that is.

Comment: @BradLarson: I really wish that "subject matter experts" voted to close on questions. Unfortunately, those who vote to close often have never even worked with the technology, and just happen to have time to review close votes. That explains the [herd mentality - if someone votes to close, others will quickly follow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/150034). Just one example: [this Meteor question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20918293/revisions) was closed by people who've never answered any [tag:meteor] questions.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "Mjolnir away" term. Can you link/explain it please?

Comment: @BradLarson: and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10356573/revisions) was closed by a mod who again has no [tag:Meteor] expertise. The community fortunately reopened it.

Comment: @DanDascalescu Users with a gold badge in a tag (1000 net score or more in that tag) can single handedly close questions as duplicates. This has been dubbed the dupe hammer, and later, Mjolnir (which is the hammer Thor, the nordic god of Lightning and Thunder wields).

Answer (score 6):

If you think that the questions should be closed, then vote to close them.  If there is some particularly important and urgent reason why a particular question *really* needs moderator attention, and that regular community closure is insufficient, then you would need to explain why that question is so special when flagging it.  That the question has gone several years without being closed is *not* a reason to require moderator attention.

The correct course of action for the moderator is to decline your flag.

Of note; if you have demonstrated that you are an expert in the field of that question (as demonstrated by having a score above 1k in a tag used on that question) then you could close it as a duplicate all on your own.

Comment: Interesting; didn't know about the solo-closing power that comes with a 1k tag score. I wish that was the *only* kind of situation in which someone could close a question on their own, because I've repeatedly seen questions single-handedly closed by some mods, only to be reopened by the community who actually understood the question ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10356573/revisions)).