# Clean up "looking for [something]" questions

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, clean-up

As of right now, there are [6246 open questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+closed%3Ano) that contain the phrase "looking for" in their title.

Some of them include:

- [Looking for OCaml IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582388/looking-for-ocaml-ide)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406/looking-for-a-mvc-sample-for-winforms
- [Looking for lock-free container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500362/looking-for-lock-free-container?s=4|5.7746)
- [Looking for a graphDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209875/looking-for-a-graphdb)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19216577/looking-for-ext-net-tutorial?s=16|5.7002

Out of 6000+ questions, some of these are bound to be valid questions, but it seems like a large number of these are just "Find a product for me" questions, some as recent as 2013 and 2014.

If you have some spare close votes, it couldn't hurt to go through these and clean up the site a little (or a lot).

Comment: 408 of them need one downvote to be thrown off the cliff (Only do those which should be deleted please): http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+answers%3A0..0+score%3A0..0+closed%3A0

Comment: Ugh.  What a pile.

Comment: dumpster diving! let me get my shovel :)

Comment: Perhaps a warning could be given at the time of writing these questions based on the keywords

Comment: is there a chatroom for this undertaking?

Comment: @CarrieKendall - there is now:  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69389/clean-up-looking-for-something-questions

Comment: Looking for an open-source plug-in. Must be a non-smoker, thin, introspective - likes emo.  UNIX sysadmins, c++ developers, and haters need not apply.  Need by mid-terms.  Thx.

Comment: We are down to 4,909 open questions in the initial search. That means we've closed/re-titled 1337

Answer (score 45):

Here are a few targeted searches (low hanging fruit):

- <strike>[open questions containing "looking for" and **"ide"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22ide%22+closed%3Ano) (30)</strike>
- <del>[open questions containing  "looking for" and **"software"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22software%22+closed%3Ano)  (156)</del>
- <del>[open questions containing  "looking for" and **"free"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22free%22+closed%3Ano) (223)</del>
- <del>[open questions containing  "looking for" and **"open source"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&tab=newest&q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22open+source%22+closed%3Ano) (181 -> 22)</del>
- [open questions containing "looking for" and **"plugin"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22plugin%22+closed%3Ano) (219 -> 53)
- <del>[open questions containing "looking for" and **"plug-in"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22plug-in%22+closed%3Ano) (33)</del>
- [open questions containing "looking for" and **"library"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22library%22+closed%3Ano) (462 -> 299)
- <strike>[open questions containing "looking for" and **"tutorial"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22tutorial%22+closed%3Ano)(104 -> 39)</strike>
- [open questions containing "looking for" and **"tool"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22tool%22+closed%3Ano) (226 -> 87)
- [open questions containing "looking for" and **"resource"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22resource%22+closed%3Ano) (111 -> 77)
- [open questions containing "looking for" and **"documentation"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22documentation%22+closed%3Ano) (176 -> 132)
- <del>[open questions containing "looking for" and **[frameworks]**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+closed%3Ano+%5Bframeworks%5D) (25)</del>
- <del>[open questions containing "looking for" and **[content-management-system]**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3A"looking+for"+closed%3Ano+%5Bcontent-management-system%5D) (33)</del>
- <del>[open questions containing "looking for" and **[database]**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3A"looking+for"+closed%3Ano+%5Bdatabase%5D) (94)</del>
- [open questions containing "looking for" and **"links"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22links%22+closed%3Ano) (109 -> 82)
- [open questions containing "looking for" and **"link"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22link%22+closed%3Ano) (209 -> 145)
- [open questions containing "looking for" and **"framework"**](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22framework%22+closed%3Ano) (177)

---

The counts represent the total amount pulled in the searches before the [meta effect](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/269350/839601) and (where applicable) remaining amount a month after this was posted.

Comment: Just a reminder for everyone: Don't waste close-votes on posts which will be cleaned up soon anyway (like negative score, no answers).

Comment: And more importantly: Don't waste delete-votes on posts that will be cleaned up soon anyway…

Comment: There is also questions containing "alternative" and ["open source"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22alternative%22+%22open+source%22+closed%3Ano) / ["free"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22alternative%22+%22free%22+closed%3Ano) / ["plugin"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22alternative%22+%22plugin%22+closed%3Ano) / ["software"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22alternative%22+%22software%22+closed%3Ano) / ...

Comment: Feel free to edit the answer :)

Comment: questions in _"looking for" and "free"_ bucket are something special. And the answers... oh the answers. No wonder that Google recently [downgraded SO "credit ranking"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280370/839601)

Comment: Awesome job, looks like we've made a pretty solid dent so far

Comment: Please note that if you hit one of those queries in combination with a specific tag the [close vote room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/21004549#21004549) can help closing questions. But we need a tag to filter on to be effective from the CVQ.

Comment: @rene combination with tag - do you mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22library%22+closed%3Ano+[java]) for example? `title:"looking for" "library" closed:no [java]`

Comment: @gnat yes, but java has the downside that it is a major tag with a lot of questions in the queue and we can only subfilter on off-topic but it will work. The more precise the tag is the more effective 3 or 4 close voters in a close vote event  can be.

Comment: @gnat also remember to drop a message in the chatroom with the tags you handled so we know what to filter on...

Comment: Whew, it took me some time to burn my close votes for the day on "tools". Wait -- it ended up at **239**, that's *more*!

Comment: @Jongware that's likely because they're currently in process of tweaking search algo (to calibrate it using live results maybe), see [Search Results Vary Radically Within Minutes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/283768/839601). Also, don't forget about incoming fresh garbage (new questions) - granted, this cleans up pretty fast without our efforts, via The Queue, but still can blur the search

Comment: ["free" bunch](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22free%22+closed%3Ano) currently shows 47 questions (of original 223) but as far as can tell, only a handful of these qualify as recommendations

Comment: just noticed, [looking for "tools"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=newest&q=title%3a%22looking%20for%22%20%22tools%22%20closed%3ano) gives different results than looking for "tool"

Comment: @gnat Yes, that happens with all of the singular/plural searches.

Comment: [database] bunch seems to be over now. I pointed yesterday two remaining questions in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69389/clean-up-looking-for-something-questions), and less than an hour ago [last one was closed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9742744/839601)

Comment: I think the "open source" ones are pretty much cleaned up; may be a few stragglers left, but moving on to "plugins" and "libraries" next

Comment: one question I recently voted close made me feel that [open questions containing "looking for" and "framework"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22framework%22+closed%3Ano) may be worth adding to the list