# Are "advice" questions on topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, questions

When helping with [the "looking for" questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/282932/359284), I noticed that more than a few of them [were "looking for advice"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22looking+for%22+%22advice%22+closed%3Ano). There are currently only 158 of them, but there were plenty more before.

I decided to just do a search for [questions with "advice" in their title](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=title%3A%22advice%22+closed%3Ano) and found *only* 3,500 of them. It looks like the large majority of them should be closed as being primarily opinion based, but I wasn't able to find much on the meta sites to support that.

Just a few examples from that list include

- [Looking for advice on Web Presentation Layer components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173657/looking-for-advice-on-web-presentation-layer-components)
- [Interface advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5731497/interface-advice)
- [Table design advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12816967/table-design-advice)
- [Advice on hyperfile.db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11209457/advice-on-hyperfile-db)
- [WCF - Advice required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688530/wcf-advice-required)

I understand that questions can have bad titles (like this one, perhaps), but I am asking about questions which are "looking for advice" or "asking for advice" on how to get something done.

Which brings me to the core question: **Are "advice" questions on-topic for Stack Overflow?**

Comment: Hmm, we close questions based on what they ask, not how they ask or what *verboten* word they contain.

Comment: "Advice" is too broad and ambiguous: many answers given here on Stack Overflow are advice. Just because the title contains that word doesn't make it off-topic, it's about the content.

Comment: Some questions asking for advice may might be closed because they are seeking discussion and any answers would be "primarily opinion based".

Comment: Most likely many of them do need _editing_, especially to make the titles more specific.

Comment: ...see also: [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)