# Openstack 'General' questions migration to Serverfault

Tags: discussion

Lately I am finding a lot of questions regarding [openstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openstack) (around a thousand with that tag). Most of them are very general questions regarding installation 'how to' or instalation errors.

For example:
[Openstack Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13948518/openstack-installation)
[Openstack and devstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21729860/openstack-and-devstack)

I started flaging with the `Off topic` flag under the subsection

*Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/about).*

Is there any 'policy' for matters like this or I should just do random walks and 'spam' the moderators with off-topic flags.

*Off course there other `in topic` questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961597/openstack-api-authorisation-in-codeigniter (even if is not a good question, is still a programming related question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not spamming moderators by flagging posts as off-topic. You send them to the Close Vote Queue where users with 3,000 reputation or more will close them with 5 close votes. So no moderators are harmed in flagging posts as off-topic.

This is the correct way to use flags so please keep doing that.

If you find tags that are riddled with off-topic and low quality stuff bringing it up here on meta as a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) or clean-up request is also an option. More users will help out in [getting things cleaned-up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/282932/clean-up-looking-for-something-questions).

If you cast a reasonable number of flags in a single tag you could leave a message in the [SO Close Vote Reviewers room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) where the regulars will handle that tag during a close vote event.