# Are questions about available hardware considered to be on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I flagged [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29233274/4200092) question as off-topic because it asks about **available hardware** supporting a particular API, rather than a specific programming problem. However, my flag was declined by a moderator.

Are questions about hardware considered to be on-topic if (like this) they are somehow related to programming, but don't involve a *specific* coding problem? Common examples might include questions about the level of DirectX/OpenGL support offered by various graphics cards or similar.

Comment: To clarify your flag wasn't declined by a moderator it was declined by the [community](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/7452164) when it was reviewed and they voted to keep the question open. No moderators were involved with this flag.

Comment: I know I've personally flagged at least one of those reviewers before as having consistently poor reviews.

Comment: see also: [Clean up “looking for \[something\]” questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/282932/839601)