# How can I best help with Close Votes?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, community-moderation

At the time of this posting, I am 5 reputation away from being able to view and participate in the Close Votes queue. (Please don't go and upvote one of my questions/answers just in response to this post.)

I've heard/read a bit about close votes being a growing problem.  I am not trying to rehash any old questions/answers about a general solution to this problem though. My question is simple: **What can I, as an individual, do to help with the problem?** Also: **What should I know in advance to be helpful/effective regarding close votes?**

Stack Overflow has helped me many times; I'd like to know how I can focus any spare time I have to participate in this matter most effectively.

Comment: Short answer: Use them. Especially in the enormous review queue.

Comment: You're welcome in the [SO Close voters room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) where we focus on some tags and help out in the burnination requests for specifc tags to keep that close vote queue as low as possible. Feel free to drop in at any time to ask for help or advice. Or join one of our weekly events.

Comment: I'll take the minority view to which I'm becoming accustomed and say be very, very cautious. It's very disappointing to have a question closed after you've spent time devising a solution - regardless of how poor the question is according to the "rules." In one recent case, OP revised the question but it was closed in the few minutes it took to prove an answer. Five closers, three contributing answers but not in the tags in question, one having contributed two answers since September 2013 and the other none. Low-traffic area, insufficient regulars to re-open. OP wouldn't be encouraged either.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just to add some more to what has already been said: **Use your close votes efficiently.**

Burning down the close vote queue works best when you are working with others, so you can target your close votes and ensure that they actually contribute to helping close questions.

Here are some useful links to start from when looking to target your close votes

- [Lets burn down the close queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251489/359284)
- [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251955/359284)
- [What the automated Roomba looks for when deleting questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/159034)
- [Active burnination requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request+-status-*)

Shog [started a movement to burn down the close queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251489/359284) back in February of 2014, and since then the number of questions in the close queue have dropped quite a bit. This worked really well because there were a lot of users working together on a smaller set of questions, so their close votes would be put to use right away.

Since then, the [SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251955/359284) have continued on the trend, and we regularly get together to target specific tags to burn. This is even more effective, as everyone is working on the same set of questions, so you don't need to worry about [your close votes expiring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97581/159034). There is [a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) where tags are coordinated and events are set up which I encourage you to join.

You should also avoid casting close votes on questions [which will be automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/159034) soon. There are automated processes (usually referred to as [the "Roomba"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roomba)). Quite often the ones you will see are questions with a score of zero with no answers, which can just be downvoted instead of casting a close vote.

And every so often a tag comes in through [the burnination requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request+-status-*) that we feel needs to be cleaned up while the tag is burninated. When used in combination with the SO Close Vote Reviewers, this is an efficient way of ensuring that the new close votes do not sit in the queue long.

Of course, if you want to work independently, then I would recommend tackling close votes for tags you are familiar with. The [close vote queue has advanced filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149380/159034) which you can use to target your votes.

Answer (score 13):

Use your close votes!

Working in the review queue and voting to close bad questions that you see.  As of the time of writing, there are 13.8k questions in the close queue.  With only 40 close votes per person per day, those run out long before the queue will.  The more people that get in there and review, the faster the problem will die.

As far as what you should know, search meta for the myriad of questions about closing questions and choosing appropriate reasons.  Also, don't be shy about asking here about what to do if you get stuck (after you've done everything you can, i.e. search meta).

Comment: Or join the [SO Close voters room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)  ...

Answer (score 11):

Thing you better focus on first is **"patrolling" your tags** - ones you're most active in asking, answering, editing. There are two ways to do this, first by browsing questions as usual and voting when you stumble upon a close-worthy one, and second - by [filtering review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231856/165773) by your tags.

If you think of it, this makes perfect sense.

Closing in "your" tags is where you are in most demand, because your skills and expertise in these make a solid foundation to evaluate troublesome questions.

Also, this is very efficient approach effort-wise. It's so much easier to evaluate questions related to area where you are proficient. To find out how it could be different, try review [filtered by duplicates in an unfamiliar tag](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=mumps&filter-closereason=duplicate)... just be careful and drop it when your brain will start boiling. :)

The last but not the least, this effort brings almost immediate benefit to you personally, not only to "whole system". This way, you help to keep an area around you, tags you usually visit, clean, so that you can enjoy it more.

---

Now that we're done with top-priority part, what else you can do if you have spare close votes and want to help. This primarily depends on how much time and effort you're ready to "invest" and the options are really wide.

I will share observations on a few approaches I tried myself.

- First option can be called *picking a low hanging fruit*. At first, try filtering review queue by different close reasons and pick one that feels easier to evaluate to you. FWIW my personal favorite is too broad, with unclear being close next (opinion-based is worth checking too but to me it worked worse).
   
  After you pick the favorite reason, use it in filter and roll through queue voting only on questions that *immediately and strongly* feel low quality and worthy of closure and just [skip anything else](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/232140/165773)... skip anything where you can't decide on closing in a few seconds.
   
  This way is probably least effort consuming; after you get used to it, it will take you maybe 5-10 minutes a day, no more. Important part of what makes it so easy is that this way seems to be supported by the system: [queue prioritisation heuristics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199912/165773) currently appear to be tuned to bring low quality questions closer to the top, so that these get closed faster (so you end up skipping less than one might think given above advice).
- Another option is *[clean-up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/clean-up/info) events*, when someone finds a bunch of questions worth closing and brings it to meta asking for help. To regularly participate in these, one usually needs to somehow track cleanup requests and visit meta to find it out and decide whether it's worth participating.
   
  This is probably most effort consuming sort of activity; in my experience it could easily take one or two hours a day (every day, sometimes for a few weeks, go figure). But it's completely up to you to decide whether it's worth it so there's really no one else to blame that it takes so much.
- Last option I tried is participation in *[SO Close Vote Reviewers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251955/839601) activity*. Details of this approach are quite thoroughly covered in a [prior answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285461/839601), I will only add that effort wise it seems to be somewhere in between two other ways. In my experience, it can take 20-30 minutes a day after you learn the ropes.

Answer (score 10):

Many users are just overwhelmed when seeing the massive close vote queue of SO, and complain (may be to you in particular) that close voting will just increase that questions being pushed into the queue (I've received a number of comments on my behavior here for disclosed close votings of mine).

Don't give a shit. Use your close voting powers, and maybe downvote if you think that close vote needs extra attention, because the question asked was really bad, or obviously off topic.

All these actions would just speed up identifying crap questions, and close (or even delete) them quickly.

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to give a dissenting answer:

Don't be afraid to use your close votes when you see things that definitely are garbage (either questions from end users when they have zero interest in modifying the software, or shopping questions) or duplicates.  You've earned them.

But don't be pressured into "It's my responsibility to keep SO cleaned up, so I have to use every close vote I'm allowed, every day".  If something is borderline, or you aren't an expert in that area so what's not clear enough for you doesn't really mean that no one can understand it, then feel free to skip (and in the close vote queue, that means actually hitting the Skip button).  Downvotes, comments, or just leaving the page pretending you never saw it are perfectly valid options in cases when you wouldn't be comfortable having to defend your decision to hit that "close" link.  Definitely don't feel pressured to cast a close vote because somebody else said the question needed to be burned.

For one thing, a close vote not cast is a close vote you'll still have near the end of the day when you come across a piece true crap, and might have run out of votes if you were rushing to use them.

Comment: This isn't really dissenting so much as cautioning restraint.