# Encourage user to review close votes

Tags: discussion

As you can see in [reputation](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) page there are more than 34k users having 3000+ reputation, who can cast close vote and [review the close votes queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close).

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╗
║ Total Rep* ║   Users   ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╣
║ 100,000+   ║ 354       ║
║ 50,000+    ║ 1,057     ║
║ 25,000+    ║ 2,979     ║
║ 10,000+    ║ 9,121     ║
║ 5,000+     ║ 20,013    ║
║ 3,000+     ║ 34,447    ║
║ 2,000+     ║ 51,328    ║
║ 1,000+     ║ 95,387    ║
║ 500+       ║ 167,653   ║
║ 200+       ║ 284,001   ║
║ 1+         ║ 4,688,065 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╝
```

But as i notice today from last 9 hours there are only 1.6k+ [reviews today](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats). If you count as percentage depend on users it is only 5% of total users(rep having 3k+).

At the end of the day, I don't think it will go more than 10-12% of total users who do reviews:

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ need review ║ reviews today ║ reviews all-time ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 6,650       ║ 1,621         ║ 3,186,688        ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

So, how can we encourage users to participate in review tasks and make the review queue smaller?

Currently we are getting a gold badge on completion of 1,000 review tasks. Thereafter we get no badge, so many users stop reviewing then after. Can we give a badge to users after completion of 5,000 or 10,000 review tasks? Or on every 1000 or 2000 review task?

To earn such a badge, users will review more tasks and decrease the queue.

Comment: That would encourage the people that already do reviews to do more, I don't see why it would encourage those that don't do any but can to start.

Comment: People who review just to get badges, probably aren't the people we want reviewing.

Comment: The lack of hands on deck is indeed worrying. As it is a chore the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room tries to relieve some of the burden and give the feeling you're not struggling on your own.

Comment: The main problem is that most people with high rep come here for personal enjoyment and refining of their skills. Sieving through hundreds of just awful questions does neither.

Comment: @Magisch i think people should give something to community from where they refine their skills.

Comment: @ketan Sure, and thats why many people review and clean up the site. But this site is based on voluntary participation, we don't force engagement here.

Comment: People, or at least I, don't review that much because it's both boring and demotivating. You have more chance of opening a salvageable question by refreshing the front page now and again than by sifting through the review queues.

Comment: Platin Badge, Titanium Bade, ...

Comment: I run out of votes almost every day.  Why I should waste them on review queue that is filled with crap with [tags] I don't care about that should have been closed *days* ago has never been clear to me.  SE can very easily make the CVQ useful again by only including questions up to an hour old.  After that the effectiveness of a CV very rapidly trails down, modulo the tag popularity.  They are well aware of this, this queue serves some kind of sinister other purpose and it is not encouraging close votes.

Comment: One thing that frustrates me when reviewing close votes, is the 3 seconds delay. It is clearly needed to avoid robo-reviewing, however, if you have a two-liner  low-quality question in front of you, it can be pretty frustrating.  There are also too many mouse click+movements involved to close a question.

Comment: @Jaco There is a [userscript](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts/blob/master/CloseVoteShortcuts.user.js) to add shortcuts to the CVQ. It cuts down on the time to click and select reasons per mouse tremendously.

Comment: Give me the rep to be able to review, that'll encourage me to review. ;) (Jk, of course- I want to earn that privilege fair, after all!)

Comment: Of those users with 3000+ rep, how many of them are actually active on the site?  Maybe 5% of them is much higher proportion of those that are actually currently active.

Comment: I'm in the "things ain't like they used to be" camp of people who think that the quality of questions is generally lower these days. My strategy, in order to not get totally discouraged, is to avoid most questions that even look like they may be low quality. It's also not particularly clear to me what use there is in closing a question that has a couple downvotes and then no activity for days or weeks. Why not just let it quietly fade?

Comment: What is really scare is that 15 members in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29513306#29513306) counts for about 25% of all the reviews on week ends it's up to 30%

Comment: @PetterFriberg The SOCVR really is a closing squad, may it be for the better or the worse.

Comment: New idea for badge! Only for close voters (10k close votes)! "The Gold pressed Latinum Badge" which has its special color and can only be obtained by close voting.

Comment: @Trilarion just to be precise the link is only related to review que count, "Leave open" reviews are included. Maybe "really is a reviewing squad" would have been more appropriate, may it be for the better or the worse.

Comment: Fix the review audit system. It is buggy, it is broken. Particularly the audits for the low-quality review queue. This is the main reason I stopped doing reviews myself. I find it offensive that users who are trying to help improving the site get incorrectly review-banned, over and over. Since SO can't be bothered to fix this, their hired personnel can do all the reviews, for all I care.

Comment: it would help to have just one new [bronze badge for using filtering](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/220922/165773) in the close queue and one bronze badge for Skip (the latter could be even just [an additional requirement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/232052/165773) to already existing badges). Stats suggest that [many  (way too many) reviewers burn out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252600/839601) at really small amounts of review - because they are kept oblivious of elementary productivity enhancements

Comment: @gnat Sound like good ideas. Additionally, for those who are not actively close voting currently, why not asking them (with a notification or so) to review just two questions (every day) and to specify their favorite tags before. Just make a nice wizard for them and do not ask for too much. Ask them if it is okay to continue reminding them of only two reviews per day. Some people may just need that little extra push - of course totally voluntarily.

Comment: @Lundin If you really want to and know you are not robo-ing, have a look at [this](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/myuserscripts/blob/master/ThingChecker.user.js)

Comment: @Magisch It is easy enough to spot the audits (just open the post in a separate window). That's not the point. The site should not be actively punishing people who have done nothing wrong and only try to help.

Comment: I don't find revewing this queue to be that useful/enjoyable. I'd much rather spend my close votes organically while trying to find interesting questions to answer/share. Adding rep, badges, or anything like that isn't going to make it any more enjoyable, so i doubt it would entice me to begin using the queue.

Comment: Two words: broken audits

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Personally, I think this is because of the general decay of Stack Overflow. Those with high rep have likely been around long enough to witness how the quality of the site has slowly but steadily declined. There is far more crap per user on the site now, than there was 5 years ago.

When you see that quality decay pattern, you lose all motivation to do reviews, since it evidently does not lead to a better site. This is the main reason why I have mostly stopped doing reviews myself. In the end you will lose motivation to even visit the site. How many of those high rep users are still active?

Lower rep users have likely not been around as long and therefore haven't noticed this trend. Since they don't have as much of historic reference of what SO used to be like, they still think that SO is a site of steady improvements and are therefore more eager to do reviews.

And of course there's the novelty of getting review privileges, as well as badge hunting, both which will make lower rep users more frequent reviewers.

Notable problems with SO in the year 2016:

- No longer a site for programmers, but a site about (learning) programming. Tiresome "give me interactive beginner tutorial" questions are no longer considered off-topic. The only way to close them is to find a duplicate, but:
- Finding duplicates is far too hard and too much work. The "frequent" FAQ system is not working well and need an overhaul.
- SO relies far too heavily on shovelling crap through numerous review queues. To counter one crap question/edit, which can be written and posted in less than a minute by anyone, we need manual review by up to 5 high rep users. Instead of preventing the crap from appearing on the site in the first place, *before* it gets posted.
- General system design: if your system is not fast enough to process all incoming data, then no amount of queues and buffers will save it. Queues are used to handle peaks of incoming traffic, that your system cannot process straight away. But if a queue is never exhausted, the system design is fundamentally broken. The whole of Stack Exchange relies heavily on the assumption that the crap per active reviewer quota remains low.

  The close vote review queue was the first to fall because of this, it has been a lost cause for years. It is just a matter of time before the low quality queue becomes the next victim of the site design, it has been close to death for quite some time now.

The solution is to recognize these fundamental design problems and deal with them, not to invent some new reward system. Rather, badge & rep hunting is part of the problem(s).

Comment: Define "general decay of Stack Overflow" - you sure this isn't just survivorship/newness bias and you not remembering old crappy questions but daily seeing new crappy questions?

Comment: One problem which I think you could add to the list here in the future is: When the newer users which are rep hunting and then gain more privileges, they will have a different quality standard in mind. So "give me teh codez" will start to get reviewed as "Looks Good" by many users, which aren't as long on SO.

Comment: Of course, that's effectively *always* been true, @Rizier123. SO was getting 500-100 questions per day the day after it went public, hundreds of new users per day... And plenty of folks earned rep writing code for simple requirements right from the start. Heck, one of the first questions asked on the site, posted by user #1 the day the site entered *private* beta, [probably falls into this category](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c). Old folks always love to complain about "kids these days"...

Comment: @Shog9 Well maybe I'm not long enough on SO to see the entire *evolution* of SO from the start to now. But SO also changes overtime, which is good and maybe sometimes bad. As in the early days recommendations were on-topic now they aren't. But just from going through old questions compared to new ones coming in, I find way more good questions from a few years back than I see good questions nowadays. I don't have facts to proof this, but from my own experience I feel like just from the traffic on SO the overall quality is dropping.

Comment: Given we [delete hundreds of thousands of questions per year](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296608/what-posts-get-deleted-and-why), you'd kinda *expect* to see a different mix looking back than you would looking at the present, eh @Rizier123? Kinda how really old houses are usually solidly built - the ones that weren't fell down ages ago.

Comment: @Rizier123 [Survivorship bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias)

Comment: "How many of those high rep users are still active?" That's an easy one. 29k of 34k users >3k rep have visited the site in the last 30 days.

Comment: You had me at *'Finding duplicates is far too hard and too much work.'*

Comment: @Trilarion yeah. Visited the site, cast ten closevotes across the front page and left in disgust.

Comment: @JanDvorak I wouldn't know. It's far above me to understand what high rep users are feeling when using the site.

Comment: This might be unpopular, obvious or simply useless since it won't change a thing, but I think the gamification is incentivizing a lot of the crud and *"general decay"*. I've enjoyed this site for years and I still do, don't get me wrong, but since I signed up less than a month ago I've seen numerous tactless, no-effort questions; they practically litter the python department at times. What's worse is that if I try to shun them into oblivion, there's always a point-crazed user who breaks radio silence and encourages this conduct by answering what should have been deleted. Stay picky, people! :)

Answer (score 12):

Have you considered that just going through the close review queue is mind-numbingly awful? As a reviewer, I am expected to read what are already, by definition, the worst questions recently posted on the site and determine what to make of them. This takes a while... I don't want to just robo-close-vote everything.

So if I have a choice between browsing through new questions, of which there's always interesting ones, and actually engaging with an active community, trying to enlighten those people who ask good questions and learning for myself... and removing my brain from my skull for an hour a day to go through a few dozen questions in the close review queue... why would I ever do the latter?

That said, if you want to fix the code review queue process, I doubt a new badge would help. I haven't even gotten the Steward badge yet and I just can't bring myself to do it.

Comment: So you say that by design doing the close vote reviews is awful work. This would mean probably that we should find some automatic ways of closing (for example score < X) or be done with closing at all (you seem to be done already), except for the few who for some reason are OK with doing it.

Comment: For the specific case of close votes, I think lots of it could be solved by adding a "do not close" vote. Instead of waiting for any 5 close votes, the system would wait for a majority vote, where you need 3 out of 5 votes. This would mean that you would only need 3 close votes to close, and that incorrect close votes could be overwritten by 3 "do not close" votes. In theory "do not close" votes exists already, but only through the close vote review queue. There is no convenient and fast way for someone reading a question to cast a "do not close" vote.

Comment: @Lundin "This would mean that you would only need 3 close votes to close" Programmers did [this experiment](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7797/3-votes-for-closing-reopening-experiment-the-results). They declared it a fail. Also: "There is no convenient and fast way for someone reading a question to cast a "do not close" vote." You want me to cast a "do not close" vote for every question I see and think is okay? Now that is a lot of work. For me, every question I do not close vote should automatically get the "do not close" vote.

Comment: Maybe its just the tags that I frequent ([tag:c]), but I find that most questions I come across in the queue merit instant-closure.

Comment: @Magisch Most of the C++ questions do too, they're already preselected for that. It still takes some amount of time to confirm that though. 30s isn't a lot but it adds up.

Answer (score 4):

The general topic (encouragement to close vote) is surely a big field, but about the specific proposal:

> Currently we are getting a gold badge on completion of 1,000 review
>   tasks. Thereafter we get no badge, so many users stop reviewing then
>   after. Can we give a badge to users after completion of 5,000 or
>   10,000 review tasks?
>
> To earn such a badge, users will review more tasks and decrease the
>   queue.

My opinion is that you could give such a badge (preferably a gold badge because they have the highest value and are only appropriate for the immense workload to review thousands of bad quality quesitons) and I would just repeatedly give it for every X reviews above 1000 (say X = 4000 or so).

But, the effect on users reviewing more tasks will be small. The length of the queue will only marginally be affected (my estimation).

Reason: The work in the close vote review is not very rewarding by itself and no amount of rep/badges can change much about it. Life time is just too valuable. There it will always be difficult to encourage people to do this work.

It's not true for all people though. Looking at the [stats](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats) there are six users with >30k close votes (if they took only half a  minute on average per close vote that would still mean 250 hours each). So obviously some find pleasure in doing this for free and they may find even more when being rewarded with nice badges or additional rep. On the other side, they tend to have already lots of golden badges, but still I guess there would be an effect.

So overall: One can do it but don't expect a breakthrough.

Comment: Worse yet, adding more badges will just draw in the robo-reviewers. Who are likely to vote "Leave Open" on everything because that is the easiest option.

Comment: (being one of those 30K reviewers) I wouldn't do CV reviews if it would take more than 5 minutes a day. As of now it takes less than that, it takes me 5-10 seconds to vote (15-20 sec when I spot a "known good" audit, because I open it in separate tab to make sure to pass)

Comment: @gnat The average person cannot read more than 5-10 lines of text in 10 seconds and probably even less when trying to understand the text fully. Therefore I guess you aren't reading the whole text of the questions before voting. That would put you into kind of a robo reviewer category, although I'm sure that one can be somewhat accurate estimate the quality without reading the full text and you might be a very fast reader and a quick but accurate decision maker. I would advice people to take a bit longer usually. But then who wants to stare at crap for a longer time.

Comment: @Trilarion anyone can easily check [my review history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat?tab=activity&sort=reviews), it's public by design. Questions I pick are typically less than 5-10 lines and after a bit of training I think anyone can make them quickly. If I stumble upon questions in familiar tags, I can quickly evaluate even longer questions - 15-20 lines in Java are easy to me to make a decision (especially since I immediately pick Skip when I have even a shade of doubt that question deserves closure)

Comment: @gnat Ah, so your strategy is to pick short questions and skip often. Well, that is of course a cool way of getting lots of good reviews done and close lots of bad, small questions. I never did it that smartly. I just reviewed what comes along and used skip more only lately but also took me much longer to finish a single review.

Comment: Badges? We don't need no stinking badges! (Couldn't resist-- seriously, badges are not a motivation)

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm with you. Nobody needs them. Some may like them a bit but if the work you need to do for it isn't rewarding by itself, a badge will never make a big difference.

Comment: @Trilarion yeah, "low hanging fruit" - I described this tactics [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285534/839601). Least useful but also least effort consuming

Answer (score 0):

Artificial intelligence beats best human Go player. That would indicate that with proper machine learning model it would beat easily human as close vote reviewer or even better; **predicting** which questions would be closed before they are even posted.

Indeed this is already [researched](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.7291.pdf).

> *We observe an increasing trend in the percentage of closed questions*
> *over time and find that this increase is positively correlated to the*
> *number of newly registered users. In addition, we also see a decrease*
> *in community participation to mark a ‘closed’ question which has led*
> *to an increase in moderation job time.*
>
> *Feature analysis reveals stack overflow urls and code snippet length*
> *as top differentiating features to predict a ‘closed’ question. -Correa, Sureka*

Human power could be used to clean training dataset from noise. Which means that most likely training data included questions which should have been closed.

Comment: Ok, then how do you encourage human power to clean the dataset from noise?

Comment: @rene Well, that has to be done only once. With good training dataset you can develop model which has high accuracy. I think being part of community effort which leads less work in future would be motivating. In the research to which I cited their accuracy was already 73%. Which means that they predicted 3/4 questions correctly.

Comment: @rene: 1. Figure out which users have the highest percentage of closed questions per close vote. 2. Going forward, when those users vote to close a question, make their close vote count for four close votes instead of one.