# How can I get a "not even a partial answer to the actual question" deleted?

Tags: support, answers

According to the ["Why and how are some answers deleted?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) article in the help center, how can I signal other users of an answer that is:

> not even a partial answer to the actual question

I cannot flag and a downvote doesn't alert anyone but the user that receives it. How can I get this kind of answers deleted?

Comment: @CodeCaster but... **they can't delete** it either.

Comment: Just downvote it. If it's negatively scored, it can be delete voted. It doesn't need to notify anyone.

Comment: @KevinB why? The help center specifically states that such answer are liable of deletion.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean? like i said, once it has been downvoted more than it has been upvoted, it can be deleted by the community. It doesn't need any kind of moderator intervention or notifications.

Comment: @KevinB yeah, but if the community doesn't happen to pass through there... it can live for months.

Comment: @Braiam - The help center states reasons that things *may* be deleted. It doesn't state that things *need* to be deleted for these reasons. That help center entry is more for visitors wondering why an answer was deleted, which can come from moderators, community votes, etc.

Comment: well then maybe it isn't as bad as you think?

Comment: @BradLarson then, why are we so hard on NAA's and closed questions? Anyways, there are channels for each of the other reasons that an answer can get deleted, why this one doesn't have one?

Comment: If it's really that crap, some 20K rep users will click `delete` below the answer when they stumble upon it. Eventually. If ever.

Comment: there is isn't there? it sounds like you're describing a "low quality answer".

Comment: @KevinB if I ever flag a "not even a partial answer to the actual question" as low quality that flag has very high probabilities that will get declined.

Comment: @Braiam just to be clear: do you mean answers which are more of an answer as "I like turtles!", but fail to actually solve the problem at all? As in "I think your indentation is off, do it like this:" on a C++ question?

Comment: @AndrasDeak stuff like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36182706/792066) or for a fun twist [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286270/792066)

Comment: I'm a little confused why you aren't downvoting these answers? If they don't fit in a flag category and it's not a helpful answer, then that's exactly what you should be using your downvotes for.

Comment: So in other words, this is the weekly incarnation of _"Why can't I flag Not An Answer on answers that don't answer the question"_?

Comment: I find it kinda funny that there are more complaints here about declined flags than about deleted answers these days. There are, after all, a lot more deleted answers than declined flags... And even the laziest ones generally take more time to create.

Comment: @bluefeet downvotes on answers, unlike on questions, don't make them go *puff*, I want them go *PUFF*.

Comment: @Shog9 exactly, if you give a path were they can funnel those answers that bothers them so much, you will get better helpful/declined ratios.

Comment: @Braiam If you aren't willing to DV answers you want deleted then you can't expect others to do the same.  A negative score on an answer is the signal something is wrong - add your vote, then maybe others will and _puff_ maybe it will be deleted.

Comment: @CodeCaster no, is a serious [support] question after [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36182706/792066) answer went through undeleted for 5 hours.

Comment: @Braiam you didn't even downvote it.

Comment: But did you vote on that post @Braiam that lingered for 5 hours?

Comment: An answer "bothering" you does not constitute a responsibility on anyone else's part, @Braiam. Is it creating a problem for the site? Do you find it incorrect? Do you merely dislike the cut of the author's jib? Each of these is a separate problem, and the means by which you handle them should vary as well.

Comment: @KevinB because the downvote doesn't do the task I want: that the answer goes *poof*.

Comment: The only people who have that power are moderators, so you have to instead use the tools available to you. Even at my rep level it takes 2 other people to also delete vote to remove it.

Comment: If i were going through the low quality review queue and found that answer with a downvote or two, i would investigate it further and see that it's a javascript answer to a java question and act upon it. If it has no downvotes, i'm less likely to look.

Comment: Unless you get diamond powers @Braiam nothing you do will unilaterally make the answer go _poof_ but you need to do something within your power - which would be to DV. If you aren't willing to do that, then you shouldn't expect anyone else to.

Comment: @bluefeet well, I believe that moderators wasting time declining flags on these answers are a bigger problem than me not willing to use the tool that doesn't do what I want.

Comment: I'm sympathetic to this Meta question, because I think the handling of posts that _look like_ answers but are in fact [not even wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_even_wrong) is something to consider. But you're not making much of a case in the comments here.

Comment: @JoshCaswell well, they aren't either. I only am asking about how to do an action which feels unaddressed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From your comment:

> downvotes on answers, unlike on questions, don't make them go *puff*, I want them go *PUFF*.

Then earn [the privilege to delete them](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user), @Braiam. Otherwise, you're stuck asking someone else to do that, and they can always say "no".

As to your primary question here... When you ask someone to do something and they say "no", it is rude to immediately look for ways to continue badgering them.

Comment: Ok, but, can you delete this answer pretty please? http://stackoverflow.com/a/36182706/792066 Is obvious that the answerer is drunk.

Comment: No, I can't. Three people who earned that privilege I mentioned already did.

Comment: See, this is what I want. BTW, this answer was made of [public knowledge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/29529122#29529122) of at least two users with the privilege, but they didn't use it. What you gather of this?

Comment: Earning a privilege doesn't compel you to use it, @Braiam. You're expected to exercise your own judgement and make choices that you can live with, regardless of what someone else might want you to do.

Comment: @Braiam that they aren't your sock puppets.

Comment: @RobertLongson that they aren't bothered enough to get motivated and use their delete votes is worrying. As worrying that people isn't using the [close queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319497/792066), that SE felt that they need [to experiment with it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319131/1-2-3-test-let-s-increase-the-number-of-reviews-close-votes-for-science?s=1|0.0000). These answers, aren't easily measurable, but if I say that "flag rejected" is a proxy of this value, is a significant portion.