# Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, comments, not-an-answer

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13213978/why-does-stackconst-string-not-compile-in-g/13214025#13214025) frustrates me a lot, it's a completely unsourced opinion, it's a well up-voted comment that someone accidentally entered as an answer.

The question is:

> Is this a g++ bug? Is there a workaround so that we won't have to drop the const until the bug is fixed?

And the entire answer text is:

> The members of a standard container have to be copy assignable or movable (C++11). If the type is `const` it fails the requirements.

The definition of "Not an Answer" is:

> This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

I don't see how it could have been more clear that this should have been just a comment, but when I flagged it as "Not an Answer" my flag was declined:

> Flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I'm writing this up here cause I would like someone to explain to me either: How that answers the question, or why my flag was declined.

Comment: When you refuse to DV bad posts then you'll indeed have plenty of frustration to deal with.  Hard to see the point.  Or deal with it.

Comment: Well, the flag declination message seems rather self-explanatory in this case. There is very little to misunderstand. Moderators are not expected to judge the technical merits of an answer. That's the job of the community, through voting.

Comment: _@Jonathan_ I don't get what bothers you about that answer. It perfectly clarifies what's going on.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mean I understand the answer, but I'm frustrated that the time wasn't taken to explain how it applied. The time wasn't taken to source the answer. The time wasn't taken to explain the ramifications of this change. The time wasn't taken to address the difference between gcc and Visual Studio. I suppose that you guys are right, my only recourse is to resort to down-voting. Perhaps I'm just frustrated that that's made meaningless here by the same community that would have downvoted a question with this amount of effort to -22.

Comment: @JonathanMee Well, Bo closed the question as dupe and you can't add your own better answer. Is that your concern actually? If you follow the dupe link any future researcher's questions will be well answered. Good duplicates will be achieved well by these, and are likely to receive upvotes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I mean honestly my concern is that I don't think it really makes any effort to answer the question, beyond providing an unsourced opinion for an answer. It's akin to someone giving a detailed question about why their installation of a new carburetor has failed. And the answer given is: "The carburetor must provide gas to the cylinder" It does point out where the problem lies, it makes a couple potentially unfounded assumptions, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Then downvote it.  That's exactly what downvotes are for.

Comment: I think you can make stronger argument by asking mods to delete answers so anyone with the same question is redirected to the best answer instead.

Comment: @JonathanMee but.... if what frustrates you is that there isn't ENOUGH..... that doesn't mean it's "not an answer", no? If it's bad, you downvote. You say this community would've DOWNVOTED a question with that level of effort... not DELETED the question, DOWNVOTED it. So why do you want to DELETE that answer?

Comment: @Patrice Oh no, this community downvotes *and* closes answers with this level of effort (which is not necessarily a bad thing). I was making the point that there's hardly a point to down voting an answer with such an extremely positive rating... Though as we talk about it, I have to say that is a pretty lame argument.

Comment: @jonathan so because questions that aren't appropriate get closed answers that are wrong should be deleted? How does that follow?

Comment: @Servy Welp, Tunaki has kinda convinced me that I've misunderstood what constitutes not an answer. So in my newly enlightened state it doesn't seem right to continue arguing this.

Answer (score 12):

Answers can be terse.  Don't expect the moderator handling your flag to be a subject matter expert in the language.  If you don't agree with the answer, you should downvote it instead.

Comment: Heh, I see what you did there.

Answer (score 3):

> I mean I understand the answer, but I'm frustrated that the time wasn't taken to explain how it applied. The time wasn't taken to source the answer. The time wasn't taken to explain the ramifications of this change. The time wasn't taken to address the difference between gcc and Visual Studio.

So you think it's a *bad* answer.  You don't flag bad answers as NAA.  That's *exactly* what the flag decline message is telling you.  If you think it's a bad answer then downvote it.

Comment: I think it was *not* an answer. It was an opinion that might be used in the formulation of an answer, but it didn't take time to answer the question.

Comment: You're arguing that it *failed* to answer the question.  That doesn't make it NAA.  It just makes it an answer that fails to answer the question.  Downvote it.

Comment: So I think the point that we're quibbling over here is what delineates a bad answer and a non-answer: "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question." I mean if I go through and answer every "Why Isn't This Working" Question with: "Because C++" that is clearly a non-answer. This answer lies somewhere between a "Because C++" answer and a bad answer. I'm saying it still lies on a non-answer side of the line.

Comment: @JonathanMee Obviously bad or obviously wrong answers are not NAA. It is actually that simple. You flag as NAA answers that 1. Are seeking for more information from the asker or an answerer (not the case). 2. Ask a new question (not the case) 3. Say "Thank you"! (not the case). Point 1. is always prone to debate but not here. See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319617/how-can-i-get-a-not-even-a-partial-answer-to-the-actual-question-deleted

Comment: @Tunaki And link only answers? The way you define it is very simple I like that. Your definition certainly puts me on the wrong side of the fence.

Comment: @JonathanMee You're right, I forgot about them. 4. See my blog here [link] (although some would flag that as VLQ, meh). You have the reference in the linked question http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1743880

Comment: @Tunaki Using that standard I must accept that this is an answer. It's really a little ironic, if the answer had provided a link to the standard I would be less frustrated by it, but it would be a link only answer. As it is, it's just what the author thinks the standard says, so there's no link... heh.

Comment: @jonathan Including a link in an answer doesn't make it not an answer.  A post being nothing but a link makes it not an answer.

Comment: @Servy Right, I think we're on the same page there. Even if we weren't I've been enough wrong for one day, so why argue?