# What exactly makes this answer an answer?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

[What is the purpose of character_set_connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16082480/what-is-the-purpose-of-character-set-connection/19811325#19811325)
https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/4429472

> not an answer – ZzZombo May 17 at 5:13   declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

Ugh. So, what exactly did THAT answer?? Just a piece of badly formatted code, no attempts to actually answer anything remotely related to the question. How come I am wrong?

Comment: Did you read the answer carefully? Because it does indeed provide an explanation (however wrong) which was incorrectly formatted as code. But even if it *didn't* have that, it is still showing an example of the usage of `character_set_results`. It's a bad answer, but it's still an answer.

Comment: The question was "What is the purpose of character_set_connection?" Tell me where did that answer attempt to go about it.

Comment: Read it. According to them, it allows you to INSERT and SELECT without using encoding functions. That is a purpose.

Comment: This is always the same debate, let me quote myself: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323788/flags-should-not-be-used-to-indicate-technical-inaccuracies-or-an-altogether-wr/323798#comment348386_323798 *Obviously bad or obviously wrong answers are not NAA. It is actually that simple. You flag as NAA answers that 1. Are seeking for more information from the asker or an answerer (not the case). 2. Ask a new question (not the case) 3. Say "Thank you"! (not the case). Point 1. is always prone to debate but not here.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you think that it is a poor answer, or that it *fails* to answer the question, then downvote it.  That's what that's for.  The NAA flag isn't for answers that you don't like, or that you don't think are good enough, it's for things that aren't even *attempts* at an answer.