# Audits are ultimately entirely inconsistent

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I've been thinking about this for a long time, and I realize that some answers "get lucky" with being extremely relevant, but ultimately breaking the rules of Stack Overflow.

Take this audit for example:

[image: Audit with a short answer]

I thought that this clearly would trigger a "Not an answer", because it is more suitable content for a comment. The post was asking how to implement something like this so more explanation would be required for it to properly be an answer.

I am sorry if I am misunderstanding the rules as they currently are and this is ultimately why I wanted to take this to meta to get clarification on this topic.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323789/1079354)

Comment: What action you took? Flagging or voting?

Comment: The review in question https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19869838 it was in the first post review queue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You thinking that a more detailed description would make a *better* answer is a perfectly fine opinion to have.  You can reflect that opinion in your vote.  But it's still *an answer to the question*, even if you think it's not as detailed as it should be.

Comments are not for short answers, they're for clarifications of the question.  *An answer to the question* being short doesn't mean it's Not An Answer.

Comment: Lets assume I had downvoted it though, wouldn't I still have tripped the audit system? Because I do agree with the fact that it is an answer. In the past I had been using this flag to point out answers that didn't follow this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer. If this is the case, I can't agree that this is a high quality post that should be used for auditing purposes.

Comment: @RyanSchaefer It is a solid answer, the question is "How to get a label's caption without the '&' character (Used for accelerator keys)?". The person has given the answer, simple and to the point. And even if it had been a bad answer, the issue is that you flagged it as not an answer. If something is an answer, even if it's not following the how-to-answer guidelines, you should not flag it saying it is not an answer.  That's what makes it a great audit, by messing up on this post, you're learning that this is not the correct use of the not-an-answer flag.

Comment: @Davy but then wouldn't downvoting be a problem? I can say' this needs to be expanded. Downvote!' and still be wrong.... I definitely agree an NAA flag here isn't correct. But I can see legitimate justifications for downvotes