# Downvoting low-rep users answers shouldn't cost rep

Tags: feature-request, downvotes

How many times do low-rep users get their bad questions downvoted, sometimes with a -10 score? A lot.

How many times do low-rep users get their bad answers downvoted?

Not that much:

- Because it costs a downvote, and you only have 50 by day
- Because it costs 1 point rep, and even if it's small, people know that chances of getting them back are higher when downvoting a medium/high rep user, because he/she'll very probably improve or delete the answer. A low-rep user could leave this bad answer downvoted forever (and create another account)

So I see that weird thing a lot: Wrong answers (not only low quality ones) by low-rep users often get flagged, not downvoted.

If low-rep users (limit to be adjusted) could have their answers downvoted without rep loss, there would be more downvotes and less flagging: less work for the reviewers, better "value" estimation of the answers.

I'm sure that this won't increase the unfair downvotes. If a low-rep user posts an average answer he's often encouraged by an upvote, even more than a high-rep user.

Any chance that something is done in that direction?

(That's not a vital issue since there's always the "low quality queue" to process those ones, but still...)

Comment: So.... we need some proof that people don't DV low rep answers because of what you say for this to make sense. God knows I have NO qualms with DVing, no matter the rep. And... maybe I don't hang in the right tags, but I rarely ever see a bad answer not downvoted..

Comment: @Patrice The best evidence I see is that you constantly see answers with comments explaining why they're completely wrong, and no downvotes on the answer, or a comment explaining why the answer is completely wrong with a ton of upvotes, and only like one downvote on the answer.  People clearly know that the answer is entirely wrong, and yet still don't downvote it.

Comment: people downvoted my "top" questions out of spite because they didn't like my comments on their answers. Doesn't cost rep, and it's petty... and too small for the serial downvoting... but low-rep users can't comment, can't be a "nuisance" to angry users. They're not as "valuable" a target as a highrep user.

Comment: @Servy good to know I'm not alone here :) That said, I'm opposed to downvoting right away if the answer (or the question) is salvageable. In that case, better explain how to improve, and if there's no reaction, then downvote.

Comment: We don't know why people aren't downvoting these posts. It could be because of the rep cost, it could be because they pitty the low rep user, it could be because they don't have the rep to downvote, or maybe they simiply don't like downvoting. who knows. My gut tells me it's more likely pitty.

Comment: it may be possible to check the site for 0-score answers by low rep and negative (possibly deleted) score answers by high rep users (for the same question), and see if there's a lot of those cases.

Comment: @KevinB And yet when the 1 rep cost was removed for questions the number of downvotes went up *dramatically*, so we already have some pretty good observational evidence that the rep cost is a significant inhibitor to people providing feedback.

Comment: this rep cost is necessary and well balanced, so it probably avoids downvoting nonsense or vendettas, but IMHO that applies less to new/low rep users who are not a valuable "target"

Comment: Just my two cents: I think hard about spending a precious unicorn point when I'm not confident that I'll get it back. Users with <10 points who post terrible answers may not feel any pressure to delete their bad answers, or may not understand how the site works well enough to consider doing that. And given the strict guidelines that I've read for NAA/VLQ, there's no clear path for the community to delete answers that are vague, simplistic, irrelevant to the question, or otherwise "merely" terrible.

Comment: @Servy again, maybe because of the tags I hang out in, but I do not see those. I am not saying it is wrong necessarily, more the fact that I haven't been exposed to it. Hard for me to get behind a proposal fixing a problem I haven't seen :P.

Comment: funny how negative and positive votes seem to balance each other on that question :)

Comment: @Kenster supposedly [there is](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319617/792066)

Comment: Like Kenster, I'm loathe to downvote primarily because of the reputation cost/loss. However it wouldn't surprise me at all if downvotes were free then there would be some who would downvote for various reasons. Perhaps a limit of free downvotes before losing reputation could be a way to go.

Comment: This suggestion is, in my opinion, absurd.

Answer (score 15):

Downvoting costs reputation on purpose.  It forces you to *really* consider whether or not the cost of reputation is worth pushing those answers further down the list.

I think it's a fair trade.  It's quite easy to *gain* reputation; an answer will give you 10 and even accepting an answer will give you 2.  In the grand scheme of things, a user with the ability to downvote can outgain the cost of downvoting.

But more to the point of why I'm opposing this, it really doesn't matter if an answer is worthy of a downvote from someone with 10 reputation or someone with Jon Skeet's reputation.  The fact is, you're impacting the order of how someone views these answers.  You're directly impacting whether or not these answers are seen as *good*.  Regardless of whether or not there's no apparent cost to the person you're downvoting, it's still important to reinforce that downvoting should be well-considered and not something done to punish the lower reputation users.

(Also, at *your* current reputation, it'd take you *quite a while* to notice significant rep loss *just* from downvoting.)

Comment: Humans are loss averter by nature: it bothers us much more to lose something we have, no matter how insignificant, than losing something we never had or can gain. For us "losses loom larger than gains".

Comment: Funny, but I have never cared about the rep loss from downvoting answers, and I downvote lots of answers.

Comment: Actually for a poor question or answer, it does'nt matter that my reps are going down.

Comment: @TinyGiant And yet [lots of other people](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340084/downvoting-low-rep-users-answers-shouldnt-cost-rep#comment424041_340084) care about it a great deal, to the point of not downvoting answers that they know are bad, because they care more about the point.

Comment: you are right, but lots of people don't want to lose rep. That's a mere observation from non-downvoted answers. Okay, now I'm officially entitled to _not_ delete 0-voted questions in the "low quality posts" queue, since they're flagged but not considered bad.

Comment: I don't *really* care about rep, but I do care about the privileges that come with them. If I had 20k+ rep I'd downvote answers all day, but as it is I pick my battles very carefully and will indeed choose to only comment more often than I actually hit the downvote button.

Comment: "at your current reputation, it'd take you quite a while to notice significant rep loss": thanks for considering me as the main downvoter here, but there's other people out there with lesser rep who don't think like me.

Comment: @Servy I did not imply that *no one* cares about rep loss from downvotes, nor that they *shouldn't* care about it. I was merely pointing out that I found it funny that *I* have at no point cared about such rep loss, especially considering the amount of rep I have "lost" by downvoting answers. I think this comes from a sense of duty towards voting, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 13):

I tend to avoid downvoting on answers *especially* from new users, for no other reason than that it conveys the message *you suck!*.

The *intent* of most people providing the answers is to constructively contribute to the site. Stack Overflow has some strict guidelines regarding quality, and sometimes new people have to get used to that.

I don't think that a downvote is the best way to convey that message of "hey,  thanks, but I'm afraid this doesn't really fit with Stack Overflow's quality guidelines". A downvote is a rather abrasive way of saying that.

That doesn't mean I don't downvote complete crap from new users by the way, but there is a large grey area between complete crap and brilliant answers.

Do *some* people avoid downvoting answers just because of the reputation? Probably. But I suspect that not wanting to discourage new users is also a factor for many people.

Comment: went through the low quality post queue again today. There's a lot of nicely not downvoted lowrep user answers flagged here. Now I leave them as-is instead of deleting them. Too bad if the quality of the site suffers... what would be ok by me is "you cannot flag an answer if you didn't downvote it first, that if you've got DV privileges of course".

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre A lot of stuff gets pushed to that queue automatically. That it's in the low quality posts queue doesn't mean it's manually flagged.

Comment: Refusing to downvote a post that you know is bad is inconsiderate to everyone other than the author, and often enough even the author.  Anyone looking for an answer is getting a false impression that the answer is actually worth their time, and the system tools that are in place to deal with problematic answers, or users with a pattern of problematic behavior, aren't able to function properly because you're refusing to provide feedback on the quality of these posts.  Their intentions when posting the answer is irrelevant; the point of voting is to rate the quality of the post.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I didn't know that. Can you enlighten me on the criteria? is there a post somewhere talking about that?

Comment: @Servy I didn't say that I "refuse to downvote a post I know is bad". In fact, I explicitly stated that I do. But a lot of posts aren't "bad" as such, but merely "meh", or in other cases, in response to bad questions (in which case I have trouble blaming new users answering them).

Comment: @Servy another thing I would be okay with, would be to be able to downvote (or upvote!) a flagged post from the low quality posts queue. If you want to do it, you have to open a new window. Stupid. That may well be my next (heavily downvoted :)) question here on Meta

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Indeed, you didn't say you refuse to, you just said you tend to avoid downvoting posts.  The comment applies to all of the situations that you don't downvote a bad answer, even if that doesn't end up being every bad answer you come across.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Makoto's answer, there is also the fact that answer vote totals aren't nearly as *important* as question vote totals.

Unless you are fascinated by bad questions, if you see a question in negative territory, that's a sign to stay away. It changes your browsing habits.

By contrast, votes on answers are invisible until you're already looking at the question. Furthermore, answers are typically in competition with one another; you rarely see a bad answer on a question by itself. So even if it never gets downvoted, more often than not, the good answer(s) will eclipse it, pushing junk down to the bottom. You can effectively make bad answers go away without bothering to downvote them.

There's just less of a need for downvoting answers. That's not to say that you shouldn't do it. But being stingier with answer downvotes than question downvotes isn't harming the site.

Comment: People not realizing an answer is harmful, or otherwise problematic, is *much* more problematic than someone seeing a question because it doesn't have a bad score.  Bad answers not being indicated as much have a *very* significant negative impact on the site.

Comment: And we have a FP queue... why it isn't useful in these cases? Beats me...

Answer (score -8):

Here's a suggestion:

Whenever you encounter a question that has been unfairly or aggressively downvoted, you, in turn, should have an option to "downvote the downvoters" .

By clicking on a button, Stack Overflow will flag all the downvoters as "*persona non grata*" to yourself. When you view other questions, these people's downvotes will be subtracted or eliminated from your view of the question.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The proposed mechanism is also too problematic and uninformed to be well regarded anyway.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand the proposal: this only affects *your* view of the question/answer, right? Not for anyone else. So it is a kind of *remove bias so I can form my own opinion* kind of approach?

Comment: remember that votes are on posts not people. And yes, it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @rene Yes, it only affects my view, not others'.  "-5"?  Sheesh, SO is going to orthodoxify itself into irrelevance.

Comment: @Pierre Okay, I have to give you that this is a fresh idea as opposed to most others that are only about *punishing* the curators and your answer reads a bit like that. That probably explains the votes. We see a lot of those *punishment* posts here on Meta.

Comment: @rene I don't mean it as punishment. I simply propose they be eradicated from one's life. They don't lose points or anything.