# Encourage users to review posts

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

This question is related to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319497/encourage-user-to-review-close-votes), not a duplicate of it.

For clarification why this isn't a dupe, that question is asking for badges, and I'm asking for a system. You'll get to know when you read my post, what system I'm talking about.

---

I had recently come across [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319497/encourage-user-to-review-close-votes) question, which showed that there have been very few users performing reviews recently. That question was only about close votes, but I am talking about the reviews. Mainly about close votes, as they are always above 7k.

The linked question told that we should introduce some new badges, but I totally disagree with it. There was a comment explaining why there should be no more badges:

> People who review just to get badges, probably aren't the people we want reviewing.

This is the exact reason why I didn't want a badge to be introduced. Another post (which I can't find right now) said that we should increase the number of review limit for queues above 1000 to 60, and less than 1000 to 30. This is currently being experimented, and the current limit right now is as said above.

All this is to reduce the number of reviews left in the review queues each day. But I've seen many people saying that the review system is buggy and broken (even I agree to an extent). I haven't seen many people reviewing, and those who are also, are reviewing for badges and stop when they reach 1000 reviews.

Very few people take the job of reviews seriously. But those who take it seriously, hit the cap very often. We can't always keep increasing the cap for all users.

I know that the more helpful flags we have, the more number of posts we can flag in a day. I'm proposing the same thing. Like if a user reviews 800 reviews, in a queue, their cap is increased to 35 reviews. Once they reach 1000, it is 40.

All the figures given above are just for explanation. I'm not telling to implement those figures. All I want is that the more number of posts you review, the more the cap becomes.

Also, many users get frequently suspended from reviewing because of failing audits. So you can also introduce that the cap is depending on the reviews performed, and the number of audits passed successfully.

The final formula of the cap is up to you.

So in brief words, my feature-request is:

> Increase the cap of reviews a user can perform per day, depending on the number of reviews performed, and number of successful audits.

We can also add a system to reduce the cap for users, but I'll keep that for next time.

Post your opinions, and if very detailed, please post in answers.

---

**EDIT:** Many people are saying that we need to introduce reputation for users to review posts. But I'm not saying for more users to review posts. I know that users do not like to review posts, and let it be that way. I'm asking for a system which lets the users who review frequently and properly, review more posts by increasing their review cap per day. Reputation isn't the solution for everything.

Flags don't give us reputation, comments don't give us reputation. Community wiki's don't give us reputation, edits for user > 2k don't give us reputation. Many other things also don't give us reputation, but people do them happily to contribute to the community. Introducing reputation in everything will spoil the community badly, as users will do things only to gain reputation.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain? I know that in meta, if someone doesn't agree with your proposal, they downvote. But can someone explain why this proposal is wrong?

Comment: Why is this not a dupe of the one you linked?

Comment: @DavidG, because that one is asking for new badges to be awarded, I'm asking for a system, increasing the review cap of users reviewing question properly, and successfully passing audits (meaning that they're doing their job properly).

Answer (score 14):

Give reputation for good reviews and take away reputation for bad reviews.

When you ask a question or provide an answer that people find useful you get more reputation; this is Stack Overflow's way of saying "folk think you did something good, we trust you a little bit more now".

When you ask a question or provide an answer that people *don't* find useful or downright *wrong* you get some reputation taken away; this is Stack Overflow's way of saying "folk think you did something not-so-great, we trust you a little bit less now".

Why should reviews be different? Reviews fall in two categories:

- cleaning out the trash;
- helping new folk out.

why shouldn't we trust people more who do a good job at this? And reputation is Stack Overflow's measure for "trust".

We can already establish what are "good" and "bad" reviews by looking at the eventual outcome. This isn't perfect, but neither are up/downvotes − crap gets upvoted and good stuff gets downvoted − but in the long runs this should be a relatively minor effect.

The amount given for a a single good review doesn't have to be very large − maybe one or two points. The amount taken away should probably be a bit larger − maybe five or ten points.

#### Problems

Some people might argue that people will now start doing useless reviews for points only, smashing the first button they see.

The rep penalty should fix some of that, as do the existing review audits. In addition, doing stuff for points/badges is not necessarily incompatible with actually doing a good job. *I* do stuff for badges, and I don't "cut corners" just to get at the badge. I don't think I'm such an exceptional individual and many people probably do this.

Another − larger − problem is that new reviewers will be discouraged by the rep penalty. Basically the system is telling them that they did something that sucked (but then again, sometimes people need to be told that they did something that sucked, even if it was with the best of intentions).

This could perhaps be fixed by making the penalty a variable amount; i.e. no penalty for the first *n* mistakes and increase it slowly after that. This gives some leeway for new reviewers. There could also be some sort of notification for this the first *n* times...

Comment: This is a really good option, but I'm not sure whether this would work. Introducing reputation awards for everything isn't such a good idea. People would just then do stuff for reputation, not for the community. I know you've mentioned it also. I ain't yay / nay for this.

Comment: *Some people might argue that people will now start doing useless reviews for points only, smashing the first button they see* - that's quite an important point. It means that the "eventual outcome" has a real possibility of being incorrect so it'll end up rewarding robo-reviewers and penalising the people that carefully review that happened to have gone against the robo-reviewer consensus. So while it may get more reviewers it runs the risk of them being people that won't be doing it judiciously and discouraging those that do if they keep losing rep because of it.

Comment: @JonClements There could be a review queue for reviews! :p More seriously, yeah, this is a potential problem, but this problem exists with *anything* that gives either rep or badges, and this is no different (how many people posted a wrong answer on purpose just to get the peer pressure badge I wonder?) The audits should, hopefully, catch the worst of it (although the system could be expended/improved on...)

Comment: A meta review queue, hey? But Quis custodiet ipsos custodes?

Comment: But what with the review reviewers get? Why would they review reviews? You'd just end up with another layer of the same problem...

Comment: @isUserAGoat I'm not sure if that was a serious reply or a joke. My review review queue was a joke, at any rate; which is why I ended it with ":p" and started the next sentence with "more seriously" ;-)

Comment: Neither. Hmmmmm... I was speculating on a possible solutions to this problem, and while my answer made sense in context to my other thoughts, I see here that it may be out of context. Sorry @Carpetsmoker, no harm intended.

Comment: To be honest, I think that your solution is the best, the only problem being what [Jon Clements said](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/319633/encourage-users-to-review-posts/319648?noredirect=1#comment326096_319648).

Answer (score 4):

You have to realize that this problem has no solution.

The review queues are a very special thing even for Stack Overflow. Although you can get some professional to answer a question, there is not a single reason for a knowledgeable programmer to waste their life reviewing tons of garbage questions. They just have other things to do.

So, reputation points is the only bait you can offer. Now you can imagine an average user who participate in review.

Besides, nobody cares. You can talk your throat out discussing things on Meta. The result will be *all the same*. So vent your frustration and move on. This is what this Meta site is for.

Comment: Well, I do review a lot of questions. In the middle I stopped for about two weeks, but I've started again. I used to do it before also. There is one reason why I review posts. I think that when I was a new users, and all the good posts I see, have been reviewed by some user. They have taken their time for helping me out, and identifying questions. I should repay them in the same way. I agree most people don't care, but those who do, should be allowed to review more, like I've mentioned in my question. If others aren't doing, why should the one who is doing it, have to have the low review cap?

Comment: Because people will do it for the vanity points, and make a rep fortune on shitty reviews.

Answer (score -28):

I think folks at **Stack Exchange are already on it**, as if you observe these days sometimes **there are hidden Easter egg questions** that are embedded just to see if the user is doing it right.

Comment: You mean audits? I know that. I've even mentioned that in the question. I mean to say a system which increases the cap of review s a user can perform per day, by the number of reviews performed, and the number of successful audits.

Comment: Even considering the season, I would hardly call them Easter eggs...